# The fastest square root calculator

Tags: number, arithmetic, fastest-code, integer

Write a program which outputs the square root of a given number in the shortest time possible.

### Rules

It may not use any builtins or powering with non-integers.

## Input format

- as a function argument
- as a command line argument
- as a direct input on stdin or a window

Your entry hasn't to be a complete program, it may be a function or a snippet.

It doesn't need to be exact; a one percent margin of error is allowed. 
The test cases will only be positive integers, but your program should output/return floats.

It may return the square root as function return value, print it to stdout or write in a consistent file, which is readable by the user..
Each program should specify the compiler/interpreter it should be run on and compiler flags. If they aren't specified, I'll use the following implementations: (just talking about mainstream langs):

- C/C++: gcc/g++ on Linux, no flags
- Java: OpenJDK on Linux, no flags
- Python: CPython
- Ruby: MRI
- Assembler: x86 Linux
- JS: Node.js

### Examples

```
Input    Output
4        2 (or something between 1.98 and 2.02)
64       8 (between 7.92 and 8.08)
10000    100 (between 99 and 101)
2        bewteen 1.40001 and 1.428
```

### Scoring

Your programs on the same computer with same conditions (Terminal and Iceweasel with this tab open). 
This question has the tag "Fastest code", so the program, which calculates the square root of a (not yet given) random integer between 1 and 10^10 as fast as possible will win!

Comment: *powering between 0 and 1* should probably be changed to non-integer powers only. Otherwise you'll get 'pow(x,1.5)/x' style answers

Comment: The bottleneck is going to be I/O, so for practical purposes this question doesn't have a winning criterion.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: It's enough if the sqrt algorithm is a function which has a return value. Only the time of the function will be counted then.

Comment: You need to run it multiple times with multiple random integers otherwise the scoring is totally arbitrary. You should also have challengers specify a compiler. And for languages like C or C++ you need to specify which optimization flag to enable.

Comment: @AgentCrazyPython Yeah, I'm doing this, are 10000 different random numbers between 0 and 10^10 enough? And, about compiler flags, the answerers should decide themselves, I'm no C programmer (sorry if that sounded rude)

Comment: @MegaMan enough. Put it in the question and ask for compiler. The compiler will make a large difference.

Comment: can you put up a leaderboard, by the way?

Comment: Not today, don't have time

Comment: I don't think you've thought this out fully - 10**10 is a 34-bit integer, and the ARMv7 processor that the Raspberry Pi 2B uses only supports 32-bit integers natively.

Comment: I would vote to reopen if I could. We aren't used to [tag:fastest-code], but we have to take risks.

Comment: I'm modifying the question to make it less subjective. I added "Each program should specify the compiler/interpreter it should be run on and compiler flags." I hope you agree with my changes.

Comment: @MegaMan my edit was rejected. I think you could manually edit it in yourself; the compiler is quite ambiguous.

Comment: And in order to be able to compare (>0ns) you should make it accept multiple inputs just so we can compare two programs.

Comment: @Mego: Huh, dind't think about it, I cqan try on another computer or just use smaller numbers

Comment: Can't you just use pow(X,0.5)?

Comment: @MatthewRoh It may not use any builtins or powering with numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: What's stopping people from just using a big lookup table?

Comment: I don't know much about this: I have a solution in [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/) that runs on [TIO](https://tio.run/#taxi) with a [C++ interpreter](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/taxi.cpp). Is that a valid submission? How do I specify it?

Comment: `which calculates the square root of a (not yet given) random integer between 1 and 10^10 as fast as possible will win` Maybe just run all numbers, the timing seem acceptable

Comment: @EngineerToast Sorry for answering so late, just put the interpreter including link in the title. I was not here for quite a time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## C

Since input is limited to positive integers between 1 and 10<sup>10</sup>, I can use a well-known fast inverse square root [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) to find the inverse square root of the reciprocal of the input.

I'm not sure what you mean by *"only Xfce and the program and a terminal running"* but since you stated that functions are acceptable, I provide a function in C that will take an integer argument (that will be casted to float automatically) and outputs a float as the result.

```
float f(float n) {
    n = 1.0f / n;
    long i;
    float x, y;

    x = n * 0.5f;
    y = n;
    i = *(long *)&y;
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i >> 1);
    y = *(float *)&i;
    y = y * (1.5f - (x * y * y));

    return y;
}
```

The following is a program that makes uses of the function above to calculate the square roots of the given test cases and compares them to the values given by the `sqrtf` function in `math.h`.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/xhpvud)

Comment: See [this blog](http://h14s.p5r.org/2012/09/0x5f3759df.html) and/or [this paper](http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2003/InvSqrt.pdf) for an explanation of where this magic number comes from

Comment: 'only Xfce and the program and a terminal running' means there are no other processes started by me.

Comment: Knew this algorithm and hoped that someone will post it! ;)

Comment: You need to specify the compiler.

Comment: Using Linux, I'll be using gcc every time.

Comment: Using a union for type-punning would be safe.  Pointer-casting this way violates strict-aliasing.

Comment: Ran across this algorithm myself not too long ago. I needed a way to square-root (and cube-root) *excessively* large numbers. Didn't need to do it every frame, but I didn't want any delay to be noticeable when it was recalculated. Ended up not using this formula as I was going to be rounding and truncating the hell out of it anyway, so log10 was easy ("how many characters does the number have when converted to a base-10 string?" which had already been written) and taking 1/2 or 1/3rd of that value was also easy and the result was good enough.

Comment: Compared to sqrt() it is ~100x slower in my test.

Comment: @lahjaton_j Are you compiling with optimization flags and accessing the sqrt intrinsic, since that would definitely be faster

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3

Why am I using Python? Never mind.

```python
def sqrt(n):
    # 3 iterations of newton's method, hard-coded
    # normalize

    # find highest bit
    highest = 1
    sqrt_highest = 1
    while highest < n:
        highest <<= 2
        sqrt_highest <<= 1

    n /= highest+0.0

    result = (n/4) + 1
    result = (result/2) + (n/(result*2))
    result = (result/2) + (n/(result*2))

    return result*sqrt_highest
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/fq8Do0)

Comment: did you just use python for a fastest-code challenge? are you out of your mind?

Comment: @AgentCrazyPython I've used Java, so, he's good.

Answer (score 3):

## C

Uses unsigned integers when possible for speed.

`root.c`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ns(t) (1000000000 * t.tv_sec + t.tv_nsec)

struct timespec then, now;

int output(uint64_t result)
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
  printf("sqrt(x) = %10lu.%2d    real time:%9ld ns\n", result / 100, ((int) (result % 100)), ns(now) - ns(then));
  return 0;
}

//real time:    60597 ns

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &then);
    uint64_t num = atol(argv[1]), root = 100, old_root = 0;
    num *= 10000; //multiply by 10k because int is faster
    //and you only need 2 d.p. precision max. (for small numbers)
    while (old_root != root) {
        old_root = root;
        root = (root + num / root) / 2;
    }
    return output(root);
}
```

`timein`:

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc -Wall $1 -lm -o $2 $2.c

./$2 $4

r=$(seq 1 $3)

for i in $r; do ./$2 $4; done > times

awk -v it=$3 '{ sum += $7 } END { print "\n" sum / (it) " ns" }' times

rm times
```

Usage: `./timein '-march=native -O3' root <iterations> <number>`

Inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74372/39244), uses [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).

Comment: Running on a Raspi, -march=native -03 doesn't work. Is this needed?

Comment: @MegaMan I think you typed 'zero three' instead of 'oh three'.

Comment: @AgentCrazyPython Yep, I did.

Comment: @MegaMan did that fix the problem or what?

Comment: @AgentCrazyPython Yep, works fine now

Comment: Can't use awk, even at really big numbers real time = 0 ns

Comment: @MegaMan Really? On my laptop it works fine. Can you give an example number where the real time is 0ns?

Comment: Don't remember, but something around 10^9

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/)

demonstrates one Newton step after a linear approximation on mantissa
speed of C is fast but not really relevant unless you have to apply it several million times
then it is sensitive to overall context of SIMD vectorisation, memory access patterns & other branching causing pipeline stalls etc

```c
float f(float x){int i=*(int*)&x;i=0x1fb90000+(i>>1);float y=*(float*)&i;return(y+x/y)/2;}
void main() {float y[4]={4,64,10000,2};
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)printf("f(%f)\t=\t%f\n",y[j],f(y[j]));}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##LY1BboMwEEX3nMJKlcoGim1qWlHHXCRkkQITjAgg41QgxNmpaTqbNxq9/6d4uxXF9qK7on2UFTqNttR9VGce9dFYVai2dviitOZijIbERL250ZjxmLKUsimB988kLSGq7b1FPt2g7a8WAX5yIovuLNLKx44@eZ2kVmzi8J0yNwHWWcaJfMqzs/4252lpKvswHZ6Dic6ExnL1fnpdovtVd5ig5T9yFhe1iPBDhHwvDONVetCb/RtqFJPNScgmCMhg3AXwAfARSG5Vbo@Qd4dwPjeXEPAOQuS6bb8)

Answer (score 1):

> Adaptation of [my own answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/fast-inverse-square-root/145914#145914) on [Fast inverse square root](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/fast-inverse-square-root)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 114 bytes

```
rename binary B
proc R n {B s [B f f $n] i i
B s [B f i [expr 0x5f3759df-($i>>1)]] f y
expr 1/($y*1.5-$n/2*$y**3)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYm7CoMwAEV3v@IOGaJgNT5aOtTBT7CjZLA2QkDTNFpIEL89DR167nK4Zxtn741QwyLwkGowDm2kzWtEB4W9xYq@xRRGFIeEjP6XRC@sNshtPZWX@vqcUkpk07CY85Bd9Ksso8Ql7FSnRGVFEjwp48PPy6BhsVc4V2B5AMWBXX@2Ffe3ocTGt74DsfzwXw)

Comment: You don't need bytecount since this isn't code-golf