# Fastest square root of an arbitrary size

Tags: math, number, fastest-code

We do seem to have a [fastest square root](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85555/66833) challenge, but it's very restrictive. In this challenge, your program (or function) will be given an arbitrarily sized nonnegative integer, which is the square of an integer.

**Input**

You may take input in any normally allowed way, including (but not limited to) an arbitrary sized integer type, string in any base, or list of numbers representing digits.

**Output**

The allowed output methods are similar to the input ones, they just need to be in a way which can also represent a number of arbitrary size.

**Requirements**

- Your program should theoretically work correctly given any number (which is the square of an integer), assuming the language is capable of this
- All submissions should be in either:

  - A language with an online interpreter that can give (or be trivially modified to give) accurate times, and doesn't time out with your solution
  - A language with an interpreter/compiler available from the `apt` package manager, and is less than 1 GiB, in which case it will be run on my Chromebook's Linux VM
- If it doesn't take under 20 minutes, I'll just give a good estimate based on the first test cases and time complexity
- Built in square root functions are allowed (but boring :p)

**Scoring**

Your program's score will be the amount of time it takes to find the square root of:

- All 4096 perfect squares up to (not including) \$2^{24}\$
- A random (but same for all programs) 2048 perfect squares up to \$2^{48}\$
- A random (but same for all programs) 1024 perfect squares up to \$2^{144}\$
- A random (but same for all programs) 512 perfect squares up to \$2^{1440}\$
- A random (but same for all programs) 256 perfect squares up to \$2^{5760}\$
- A random (but same for all programs) 128 perfect squares up to \$2^{14400}\$
- A random (but same for all programs) 64 perfect squares up to \$2^{86400}\$

**UPDATE:** The numbers have been made bigger. This is a total of 8128 numbers as inputs, specifically [these](https://gist.github.com/Radvylf/ec631517d21f0b9b590a19e0cb34fbed/raw/74960169b733def38213213133f51a852c551976/numbers-updated.txt). Remember that fitting the test cases specifically is a standard loophole. The only part that counts toward the time is the math. I/O and setup can be ignored.

Comment: Just to note, Dennis has said in the past that [TIO is not a good timing method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12708/66833) for fastest-code challenges, which presumably would be applicable to other online interpreters. It might be best for you to test all submissions on your machine, requiring people to include testing instructions.

Comment: BTW here's a Gist that has all the data in JSON array format: https://gist.github.com/Samathingamajig/c15fd1f15a7bca6181a2e792c469503d

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I still will test any C/NodeJS/Java ones on my machine, I think.

Comment: I think you need more or bigger test cases. With Python 3.8's `math.isqrt`, the actual computation seems to take little time relative to that for input/output.

Comment: @xnor The problem with that is that, while it's very fast for practical languages, it would make it too hard for a lot of esolangs. TBH though I overestimated how long it would take by a factor of several thousand.

Comment: This is a very important question: What parts are required to be in the time: the actual maths, the outputting (print/console.log/System.out.println/prinf/etc.), the setup (reading from a file/initializing an array? I would assume only the maths AND the outputting should be included in the timing, but we need to know for sure to stay consistent for everyone.

Comment: I also think this needs larger testcases. Currently I/O takes more time than the actual square root. Test cases on the order of \$2^{10^4}\$ to \$2^{10^5}\$ should do.

Comment: @Samathingamajig Although there are already 4 answers, I guess I'll make I/O not count toward the time (in languages where separating the two for timing purposes is possible). All that counts is the math that actually calculates it. I think it's too late for larger test cases, though.

Comment: Please use larger test cases anyway. These cases are too small to be meaningful for a fastest-code challenge, and existing answers can be edited. And it’s not helpful to just tack on a handful of large numbers at the end of thousands of tiny numbers—with a distribution like this, the running time is heavily dominated by the tiny numbers, which is not interesting. Use the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/39242) next time!

Comment: What CPU does your Chromebook have?  x86-64 with AVX2, BMI2 and ADX extensions (i.e. Broadwell or Zen), in case any of them are useful?  Or is it based on a Silvermont-family microarchitecture, so only .  A machine-code answer would obviously want to take advantage of whatever features your CPU has, and tune for it.

Comment: @PeterCordes x86-64, with whatever a Celeron N3150 has

Comment: @AndersKaseorg In a few hours I'll add some more 2**312, some 2**3120, and some 2**31200.

Comment: Here's the new data in JSON format https://gist.github.com/Samathingamajig/c15fd1f15a7bca6181a2e792c469503d

Comment: The problem with adding test cases is now we can't use TIO to get a time approximation.

Comment: @Samathingamajig For an approximation, you could probably just use 1/128th of the list, then multiply

Comment: That CPU is https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/87258/intel-celeron-processor-n3150-2m-cache-up-to-2-08-ghz.html, [Braswell](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/cores/braswell) family, thus [Airmont](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/airmont) microarchitecture.  So yes, unfortunately low-power Silvermont family, not mainstream x86, so fewer fun ISA extensions to play with.  Just SSE4.2.  http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel00406C3_Braswell_InstLatX64.txt has a full list of Braswell's CPUID feature bits, and instruction latency/throughput.

Comment: Unfortunately double-precision (2-register) shifts like `shrd reg, reg, 1` are very slow, like 10 cycle latency and throughput, and stall the decoders because they're multi-uop.  So that's unfortunate for some extended precision code. `div 64` is not a *lot* worse clock-for-clock than Haswell, but IIRC extended-precision division (with a divisor wider than 64 bits) doesn't usually use hardware division instructions.

Comment: Your new test cases are invalid. None of the numbers except the first 4096 are actually square. And instead of 128 lines of 14400 bits, you have 33 lines of 14400 bits and 1 line of 7132 bits. Furthermore, they’re still too small: my GMP answer runs through them in 6 milliseconds.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Ohhh I forgot to square them. This whole challenge has been a mess, I'll try to fix that ASAP, as well as any other issues. I apologize for all of this :/

Comment: Can I suggest a more scalable benchmarking strategy? Describe an infinite sequence of squares of exponentially increasing length, using some simple deterministic algorithm with a seed provided as input. Your score is the number of these square roots you can take in 10 seconds.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg That's actually really smart, as soon as I get home I'll change the spec (hopefully for the last time).

Comment: Your file doesn't have 8128 numbers, but 8034. The missing ones are likely in the 2^14400 numbers. Also, line 7970 only has a weird 7132 bits instead of ~14400. So I guess there must have been a copy/paste issue at some point.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire There definitely was, sometime soon I'm going to switch to a better scoring system. I've just been busy lately :/

Answer (score 11):

## C++, 140 µs

This is a trivial answer that uses GMP, but I’m submitting it anyway to drive home the point that **the test cases are way too small**.  Scores in the range of literally nanoseconds per input cannot meaningfully be compared.  We need larger test cases for this to be an interesting challenge.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<mpz_class> numbers;
  mpz_class number;
  while (std::cin >> number)
    numbers.push_back(number);
  auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (auto &number : numbers)
    number = sqrt(number);
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (const auto &number : numbers)
    std::cout << number << '\n';
  std::cout
      << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count()
      << "ns\n";
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nb3drjRLdl13f56iIQMWdSEhM@OfovkKfgEBQqtFkYTJbprdtAQbfnXTa4wZ@1CGAV@4cfrLql1ZUZmREet3rrl@9w//8G//@ne/@@d//h/@9ve/@7t/@s9/9Zu/@N3f/OMffv@Hv/zlX/7y13//D//tv/27v/nv//S3f/jjn/7xr3779//93/63v/rdn/7wj3/5yy9/@/s//ebvf/u3v/@zf/Ob/@OX3/zmj3/6z3/@5/nwL/7@H/73//i7v/vtH//4l7/5/T/9/X/6q3/847@vM3796/0jf/uvf/O3f/dXv/kzv/y7v/39b/7y5xv/pj78zc@3/90//NMf/@Y//qff/u5/@bP7Kd/97T/96Q@/@dPzm/8pv507@vM//5u//eu/@Y//@Fd//MPf/dOf/vYPv6@f/MPv/pc///Pf/@G//plf@y9/@Mff/Jnf/R8z2G/@/Od3/vsfZdj/9R//9P/@wff/1w/@7g@//@OffvP/9bMZ8w//9Kff/MVf/FxDvfrX/@H3//rf//LffezJv@Gj/8dV/Od/@sff5ud/@8c//cX/46Pf//b3f/jjX9UV/Oc//uWf1fX/25q1f/Pvaqzf/@nP/s2/DPevfv/H//D7f/Xvf/k///mfn1/eX/ov55d3/vKNX9r8pZ9fZv9lv7@8T3321bH3@rTOOHVKnfONOu7zS/t6nV/frvN6r@Puv4zv/DLW/GXWebOOq96v@vuuz0@ddybj1hffp0Z43xrqZcz3q8Hfxq90fm7wu5MLmFzJqit6d@ca6gq/h6t4ueLvOb987em/fP1568rqG9/k1eJvm09Pndf4Rqvxuei68lbjtV4jN36jrfq1tut326kr6E9dS@eqeqvr672utM@65r64W25jPHU/4@WGG3dcn/wyuOexeHXqb/OpT@tbb81mfWOO@u5cNcrcNd56BpNT31j1m7@sUb@7Vl3BOnUtm6nfX13f7jyLWde8d1394T7qjHpVV1mzWXd59uOzYrKez9f9YYJnnVHTXCe/L99736/xujOP72RK383sfnnSjTn/BtP/LZ7Ed3woPp/Whw@Ip9YOD7C/07XBd@sqeb03j66@V/@2mojXOXnH5vX077NxzvT8yVS@y3FWZ8zl@OvwW9vfrYfOa6/nPFzb8TqPi@Nw/XXPdS/fw319z2KBvFkhjSXyMg8fX67lwvx8WSYf8/a1l7@37jpanN/9bm@M05n5WjGMP3getfb57uApffV06@@TZ/fVhdf5PtFvDXbI4jl/dRcsRJ5@7Rm@e1gT3xk1DzXBNSe1OBdLlLlqz@H1y6qqq69z2sdaq2XLQv1Yga297LzGumythq6lzO/WIzq8Zg230VjOw5U9eb615F3vm6W/3AVrsiG2e6M2KK/ZMfV4H7fC495mdz/d17v@3l/2HA@fTcJ368khNj72Z29fjV/v67dKJigZ2Mv1bOp6@mCH97HYYNMdNidbbCEN@hpuMmREyRK@u5Eb/dTQ9S@yZDwvG8y5Gu/D61eZU0sB6YMcqvds0YZsGm3XmKMjr2qX1m@Nwe/WEzpsWeTaqNVY5yxkXckuvrtr29S/o@5l1MKpc05deu1p7nc@o@6dSa1d/pYoqG3@1PxM19Vsvm7@vXtO9/zhd4fjTMbk1uucxW9Nf7dmra6BR1R/P1xbXSXi4VFSPFx/XSby4@W@1sc9Lu93Ne69pEnNw@rMyRrMz3IP1rrh9VQeL@ZzLeZ2Oc9rM@e17WrM/fAs9sNz2crm/fK89sez2x/PcTee6fb5loRCTg2e@x6sgbr8use9uN/auHXve7Nm9mb97MNaOq6r87DGzst6Oy9rj81Rwk15XaIekddZq6ezbs9gDR/X85ms7cNt17@s@bNZ/7Wl@O5hX9R5bJL3eV9Vzruu@lFWNjZWHdhlJQXYcnVg/71PBFctM9/N42dreOb@/J67@X0OWxsByy/UX1VrLxKgfvSL2EU2vG9DUJT4RWrUARGCAmSUdyJc6nCUymsqondTXp8I74N0YqoQ66X9kPHfq/CPREOC@64dP@sqgG80vzcd5ZvIx5LvKoH6UX7v21EDkantUcAiGDsHRS9qE/l/lUFTQrcedTCU3bUUmYkWqV7ChVlqW3nfjsK/Fifz2d2@pUDUEf3zs9qinFlLR1Vy9cqIkhnRONPf60td1KMg6gFzZTw31M6j/hqv9zCi2Upyc3@187jbOoF7LznQ1FDOy5jqSbY/n201aP3qEzNEQ@Rxrusu@axk/6M6QxnXLDpKiVjGZF8flRy/V@uUX58q9Tr43OdB2b@YASi8FyPgXVkvq2Ec1MG1tPpSMw7X2dKYeGsLM0trY2TUwfW5DsZHrQhnd7/dd5/rejeMlZf7elWqjLKH@2FPjJvSse6VsjPUvm6jWnsYQ3U4KuB3q4G/pQpu0cGdTfkiIPlsfpppC2OrhLLzcjZG2FubEjX7PBpnpbVRwE@08dM04Gob@tnQsHumRt6jKKlDjL@9VfQHo7AeMOIHY5BRarWjmGtloplZTKj@gXFZz0nlXJONdq5p2jEL0M91aSjoGlTL4EU01sPAcv3KLKgZrO2NPVtDMLtfaX3freFnu3vmQQRjjjIK5ibvPuzkr3YOv1eaml9vKiGkN1eG3cFnG0v7Y6@82rOM0rHg6lBzgZHbHg2S/midjJgqNY@8Wyibr5cA58zzXINYe@XNu8/PRvPM0f3eyCi1ERhzLH@hNKA2z/HXZ66lnkbMHq9zNq@6tiv3MHNHtZS4P9a8RpH3Po8zsTIv63WWagUzZ6s5g7Wlmc8oqxK6zvVazvzaPod1fCo7z2i/PrHdfH61rjW2hs9250nv5XPHcOaz45o4jyvkZL2cz9VzmmuplAz3fobr7GTVne0aLLWCafSgNerwslpb1m4JzOm7vvxsaEQ9M45HzKvn6HygezDsXh2QEtGYZG@ckNqvGGsIHz6bmnEoRb7nbizxzt4skaPp92GA1qFpFPrE6zBjLq5X23FrSNadYVVeE7NEuu8@jc/ad5xZj4HvNeVLa2toaO6lpXmQRK2jFrU1NTZb09rsSLAyPZFnpRCQbnhWjILhVu/KEuJuS5Rz7yWMmYmhxGwlhZmlEpjMGeKXMzeStkXu1tL5fPchkzEJOBNjtr43ld5tYghh2yLZ62lPbdwHqY9vp4vX0Ait1hnXuQbaoiYO3dGWmqStg14pexgtU5sRnVP6Cw2Ec8goWIS8m@iqks9orrZZPmUvZ3YPzkodmp@djv5DXfK9o26s6XTMg2mDhc3v1XpCp9bG1izGmeGd19kRmJy5uQfcU2zj1/srcxwd3hF5mOUd/V42lIZ56RCs9JLwmuwHuwB1izEfm6GX1PHdeP3M59Br52nda3mUzMEO6c3nh5mkhd95tjjIjNJ87h1jm88Oa6KzJ3GfXS@9TtWZ7qyljvVfZ3bXGR42o5QgwtwfbIFfMGE/nIWODdaHkoHF5jvXNf4OZ5Y9yPemdl2f7oc@BzZfmQxx3xf2IMuTUUrtcmXr1d2vpcFVL/cfPj6jlDPO/ZUTx91u9y1rjpnYmqclLLBV@3a/99oqzGCd/yRIwChHOcE@4LN63pyJxUiYRfnSS6oZdDnInnJvsKNrIpBLRBkMNrBLcHqwvcejPBsPRm/5PZroda/Y6@NVDg6MmzoTGZIwBaO8ys8a6dNT@nSnasLxoaLVRolo321dqu/oUzXlNXEOvaoet2roVzXlfDlZelZdN2X0V9@qqx9qu@ld1UPiHnr8q65eKc2jh1VqiXuvQRv@mfqonjde06jJffjs4E@NqR4b8bQQGr4b@Uz9V4ac31u6auXUOeZSbw4Mx66Px6@vXMtS36rw6rP9edXM8cQD9I729P7KjeFu9/Hej/qdWA@joF14N5yzo10wasMtvUbDYc/3@k57opxInsOszU@I6PEZ1TbliZWe5fnNMsU3Lmbn2c7YL@XH8dwn1tfB8WRN8AmO4@d6QQXjUtYTxr/8tJfKLWWdlb2qG4pzzDvtrFrUrE9CM0/CVYzStc/Kl/v0ZPvWleXPdVCrlTxgP7jT6rO6IX5vaA9On1UdFrtqlkrlOqd2JEYC9zANW5QbzN4slc9OnaU2P73idQNmjLK0W3kKzNla7P7a0siCGXt3lgz3XTP4tgcyZG7tZCJujFK6nzFLBvALR/t6noFcKrHitaDp8Le1y3G7Cck9DemGrY6v/GjPE7Gou11lf3bc8Q8ZWaYN81KLDvm5ynZ/@OwgW0s8IGlX5O7CouMd4YU66HfUukBer2b4qm4SWY6Dyy/wwOrMUlZbN99r6fo5C7MQr7@jLRZBq/pe/KNVkoWowcDzqEND55QzgQYi6sgotb4JBdTKJC4w9cdWrQYjBjd8sJrv9OMWqpUIwuf3lrpxLf2/stnQmyxSfq9MWn59q9XKjEPfrtpOXOfew4Cn/iZxT0bhqRiKQIevo5@6yvgiovA4L7X00P21Ypkzti1RhfLKnwROiUm8@sUby4pQ9uA57PKv@F786TodO6TmyODq1w20fvrhRF4NwB6DsWUvGfPQfy/vCLtnN9dLrTZsIsxPgiYdq7YOnXVG6Nb4iPGCXU@dOHiJ4ZrBXZKz5nNHq5Uf1n13WNe7tj9nTuMTxH4ZBYuYdxubby/jGrW6sQfLcfsSasFW3MtgyMZcrjO9a4PHjLINoOy9sD/rktm35Zthm@4EXcpMxm6txc1@L1GHTVtXYKAm9i5hWN9xhXUwuHMIskxjOYRfyqEldvMaEDoYnER4DnKJ8DWjfAaRDgHn@oy1TvjnYLNjPBkAatjzpyzIutuysrD1a4EgI4l/MwphR951fITTDXARLKr5PAkTntJuvjMohiXGmVjZrwF0Y0kG0g7Crj4r@cTvlUjh1xN8K/mAn1MLEv1Qguc17mTAjgg8o7CmeNfxnc42yFcCBb@qNIHzQkSBdwYGD5u4E6t6fkL4hpSe777vj4H8mnxD@QgQwlGvY9XxY@gXZ6Qb5Zr8cB0NX5oMSFLgM42DdYX7XsaF6ZxHJ8pAmL6@pqfvDZcSGWuGzcoInjet4HjdMCvxoZ7Q2RyJnRFQIHiWCERpuJn3ffl5qWjPH4Z1TVA43vySFiJEauLCcDBhN/NDz0qK6EHs@94wch2XuaKHwOWbVIfjbcPPdRzmjR78R1Mh5zhf58v8nf46nwc1ynGzoF8nPjE9w2rcYN7P9dwg32OU7zGsUdsnETrCTr43vF7HY0jkxV97k35xvM@wfB2X4RTzLJxfmjaBwp64Yc2/YcQSy0YViZsZOjQNYCLH8fA7fX8M8hj9MrnWDAG9kTJ1XCvvTTsQdDR8VHrFaBIBqwQjd2KaqDrDkV@immsYmCL65HglrL3eErAz8UqDWu8eiW3uhLwQuN7/@QyIvacnvlk7LAHORDhruX4JcbbEOFG4hCeflSjnTXLVak6ck@STQdCZSCc/aD4x6a6P2Evyi4l2Elfg/O8k3tl@El89qa82k/xqSTcR4eP@vp6o51e@iPnKnjRVPWTDkthe86bOHG8kvfXVOmd@jZtwflldy1BsnkftDsOhZXXn8xLnnr@STiMJ53hloTr@fg204kD7@zXPXs/eN4X6GKQtGXrTd8MQ7ndW7u/8BHiT9kO/MB8Ny5fo7LMNDrebLmxvM3SMEGZ@Sw8aWMaEZP7bDTs3Yk6@X28@NznJtw1ZE2JI1Hga0G7NhObLU/b3a369np5geK1a109DHPA57knizAbSyWo5Xt1@kpKv67NhTxqINtlqsjKh6Nf13VYzgF/ev@sfv5/5bzdiWt7ryXuTui/LIMHrx/1F2tPxjongOi7TCjjyxqVrXg1MP9m/tV2HoWlMRT5nZ/fEvU2rv5rIddzKh7IIMaDraJL6JVTYDJAnitp9YBxNbNcRx4njUj71GO51NBlODH37eYlfz6/V4fdH5B@hEMfHqj6Jsvv7M0l3VmGSu1P5SrTf6183UV82ofe3Zu63DLsE5pPc76SJOJ@8zE0PO16ZDMb4y9wx5H@G@qFc4dekcfylOrYn74f6ZTzYNAT3H/UPiWbD@/h4vl84Zi@3x@/j43I9tXy8vsG24H1tAHMF5Co5vw31Iylrx6urNF/AAzBhMNSv5A9NGYzo37qqYdKAP5hRWMO0AYGrN8lvxyu9lvf383IvPH/d76@R8dYdnwiuWYj7@2U7ej37Xt95cr3nXv8ZuZ@T@yNLaTbiyf3rapKPeDI/E83@JiFvSoKUiO8zv5PwO@d/mf@Z6IA5Kt/Xn5PKz/ObbKs3qX3HY1/zvuf5l9PoeijDy/WBv@h4I@tnssz5fGR9zXnhH3f9zfqfGZSZ9TlXoCDlFbp@yx9M9mVlfeMKmpvZWf/lBbof5rmJnCNEpI7ZP@X7uZ/Wk/21nuhzHL7m@@1@LOnm/qzl735dd//W5bif15f9XWLc/V7u0Uha59y8TuQDHp2ZnRb5Uc7c@oFAOF4XXkLmR/lTy0N5REyB@V9Xn5ffpvzC7vfzGfm25kx26Mq/RcaD9yvysYyAZJZW5CfhT8fbka9rr2SlTuTvwip/A8twvCM05SUyIy6nlhPzU2JU@U6EPhmoyH/SGszvfqMf9hvIyr76Y5OX8H30S1lh6pvyuNQ/@C6O16Kfdg@ExfibSa2pPgMqkrRWoCx7RP9tIj2cP6Mfy7MKtGRGf@JUmfla0a97Bdqyr/4tV0p9XGpW/VxelPq63Cj19z4343ai3/FP/PxE/x/wKW/gKybMnkBezhP7oXwmf/@8sS/Ohb6QcTD5RoSfz7/YJ/U4AoG59sup5WgGrsW@OUaPOcb@KXMrWbge@whxwfyeEfsJ8ftcSI3jTaExdYz9RZD1SU5P@6x8oIy3Yr8RiPT3duy7s4XKCM5xvLpRr/fEPjxHyEwdtR8/xJX5vUf7kvyg0JnyXrA/69iEzzCNpgrfQGjqa9ivH7FZ8kTPp31b5qPPo47av59@DJ837ePa80JqBAw5Xid2QdJR@7qOQmswP5vXM06ub2qfk4ljf9dR@530JPtf6JHjLaE2yVfyORggzt/6ByQwk888@g91bMmLnpnE6BF6813/48OBynv9k68cC7Oj76v/8mGoBxCnf4N5bB4LP8MU6beTI203Sdr6zZKumyZ9kic1ts/xZkr7Saq0tqe50jGSLB1CdARWOR6C3/f6dwRQzdshAJn/92b1SrCY5MNf8POt//ix4fz@SYKwFrL5wlp47SZnzSbywIeYv@Qa8baFJL6vmci6YBOTpHi/N2Av07mlx7bv9Y/rKKQH98CU59eSATUVwvsutIfYn@lSM6sXNuZ4o933M5@Pk/Pnl@/PO97cGR@xx@er5/fXyvXse3275Xr3zPXvk/s5X@7v3Ps9O8nj500u@elJLbPwLpTtJp6Th34NddTxON9IPea/3Rx2aW@fD3a6nzeDKHUUGiQozvF683nXxz7/NoQI1dHwDDGoZLOHwZuSOUKF4k5xfvmT3B9pbsdbQobqaFiIaXe9tm3QCPfL@Su72/Vdfw3M8xhw@rC3nzdAPVPk@Im@N1hVj08oEdEO91fZ18mTfwa66iikqP41DGZS3Rx7y/7tTWhRHQ2h1TL43O@9G2CrY@RB7SLlQx9DedGHwbkSguKMBA86HtF13i8De3UUa/SRY2L@e/yPOhoUrKN4IxO6nl/37/dP5J8RXXP7hhvrOJSX4zEY@Y3gjj7s4uP7LUSxHgLyt45ijwQ0Cg5ob6CNzSDohx3cgw/YQgJ6IJGEcS5gQLgkUDbhBOU/PBca6XhTHJJusJ@XVer5y8AtizDjLcO6H6mkYA4M@uo2ez0JCX9g77zeY8AY422JPHgMJ9dxB3vwGmz@pp4KR0PR4BXQt8I1hTF8YpPKHTeMXceOvq6jQW5yoD6Psl933q98PgyQ17Hl@wmffxP8Be@nwfVPe5Xzp6F3IFe5vmVgvo4n178N29dxen9ASB3viFf6yN5N4RPH@aldIbh1PZm/9ZguKPHyOb/rNZlQR3FL30011HHsvDcRUYOIXQJ6IeC17M@M101ifGbJxGSY4gDj4vrA7nS8IYbpw@3j@tccri/NSmEbWX/lzgQIW@p8i@Mw8VJHsUwCZB3vfK5vzNEL9HD9167Fvq1j5BWIHd@/Ypo@wk6cT0RfZMin/VxHcU11NJUEBsL9We7oFh7Ssn93Nw1Vx@H@LiGE/U720/2/k8IizKJ8qN2N/f@Jl@L8afrrK6v0Cd7E5NhH6J353dvUWR2n8mnH/6hjsE7G2IWkPMq385iUq@NFnrym7OrYgkt5TeiVWgjm6STdR7gnmJZmMrCOwT2VuYV/9Z2uvwU6Cf8LmIvy@wzTjHXsyndi4o43g3860xRlHbf6gRD4EhiT51F23@N7DHg@3yY/6xgc1ElqlLCT@qnsPfxPMDSWD5Sbj3/aSOuIkXlNutZRPFRNqilZED7oR2HSgduIiaqj6dw6bvQr0RH85zqOYG66qeAGmExEzjBRXEexUVqJjlePJ@9PPl8t5685LoQn4@2W8ffK750nv1/qyOs5uT7hpiB5HlPfXq1YHvGdHNXndTRtTq7D@XiVhBzFSwkCd7wSN933JuSbgZ8jYOgRLJ54ex1N5jcCCYGPm@qPGfAGTu54S@xUw5H09@o5@vtbEEEdZ65vCzFo2mN8fgQgNAx17u8LPKFh8HL/JWZZn8KTmB8MPCsuPuNNZhde3wdLhQHyCGCaoqm@xK8aCjjvhVSUufKIqEIR@f0RTBVpDMefQ1RVCVDB7ULL3oDlA5o/Iqtq4wuKd@OKihIGQrgy6KojSKSB7hJa/4wA7Z/9K@xecNQbjFXTMwJI1URZ1QUI3v8VZ9WErtRxXaSVwJaG@e33A3tpxjd5PwTF1DF4K8L/Xs803tmaOWeOwVwRv@R@hCq9KQVwvB3cFZnwKXxriryqi0e@N9I4IrgeYT51Wa/oq25kjWPwVxciVMf55b0AoqadxPlNeBHGZsbrgo@IbojDwsuwzqbEOteDmHW8GSxWn8KamsuY85egJ6zQIMy2kKg6DhFZNV3o19ZPMFn9wqmIF/bgzARbES1jvscbKNZIGUodA9Qqsy2ff4FxjXa/3wLyGi34rNpOQsDwyvn9EpMCxMru@YJdC3ysZt3rL2EguGxMcVoWXzjeyv3jNgmE22K16hjY2jiZP9WM73cwbs@FvD2Z//n@AOJa8HFv4HLgMT3/C5huBreF1yvUbrY8f6wxfr@kietjXpjeHFk/pcYF8RkW4fwZiN@862@uAAABajAfpC8sAdtZv9QtON4Rx1XHQAtrV7j@1xPg4Yo@r2NgievN/llvQItMW39TpJLqrOy/slsEPGK18/vlTgmHXD37d/WAJdcQ11XHQCnXyP6n3MXxptiu0o6BYa4V@VHaUpDmCr6rjoFwIh6Z33UC8FxHjJeFM4ICn8iv/QYcSprmEUEodLTtK/9qmo4FN59Yr3J3hJ3WMfKTEhzH6@K9UPr4T6QjlL97CGht5SZ6v3sKd61j5Ld2COcvcV8W8zjejvzfWyAt4mEFtyjMlvRGkIuPINw6iv8Ch9wFL77RP5QFCV/8xIDVUXgv7pn66zTBv@0EB9awAo7vo//I0vaAIdWPJ7DihluzfS/ouJ0lHoyoKP5zO1f/klh/fS8mrJFMt1DpqL/7zZ938@a@FwrdyZM/IiwFSnfS62IsP2HUddR@AHrJ7/NHrseipxQ/aX90vERhmEOMGG7nK0hzPsFsTsHddRQnVuJV6HcdZ8okt/PHprBc8vHBgOfUfiJqzvyjVMU6Yj/kvfZXT8KYo5gxC7EEgn7abzgxPP/@NnFjpJlYH@UGu146iZ/je7FjWEusr04CgvuztIHxpvgxgA5LaOnS/uwEjAWX7pR9vVt4fie/G3yp4P3@@qBSHCbE9NH@Lfdb4H/HPhBl@loW0InPWEb2WTTQEc/8HgEGfv9zBaXMzPG6mDIwq@zvOmq/l5p6UrkZXFnHweL@tQdEtVroQDpNhOiXMgjADuJHQV8xv@ZLQbo@llD0FnnVMfB8/4ox64CzOR8Dh@@TThIM28SZdeIp/F5r@j@9ORLHdYtLLfsAGCtetgT/Ej47W9C0KRnpQI3E2i4LSroCh/O35SZ1vDjdYzFKHcWddRc8INtH/89yvJTqij3r3XIQAbrig5kwvt@DPwOxi36qo/5nJ9vC74O1sbwv5TWgncQl92nxDUEEUct44QKA4/924h2ppxWL1skLCgI@@s@WCDreEY@GFb8FAj/63730eRP8@14s8Gs5kdaUn38WG3Xzem@KDYUVd/1/svcCrnF3@P3S40KuS018wRZb5FRH8WklDC2BqqPxB8sWHW@LUetodeaDu@hBIwu@nsGpMR3Cr4kaMb/ztTCrjmLVjLIKWP6Mn5RZZFFXHcWr1dGSL5yIjNctCANt4/Mn/jCFOBu/sZTS8aa4tRIelpoF@8z520K0jjvneMcytToaPyLKKSi7Nqnrd6XEjXSv63u9FsARBXL9LyMp4Kcjr1azeK6O4tgIcwnPRi/7/RGAdjk97r81Lcuro/EzFo0g7RU8Wx13YNr7C057rwC1zxukdgoBLXjh/utXLlj7XLR2C1w78T/wkAFsfzOI7fYGst2MH1py6nhdfFsdLVjswAE8f1jMWD8S@VduvdDtcgeVj@XNWfxKvsjrSYFkHY1/dqIaXH@5VcrfWvYWwpI@Egn@WnRJ1F35fV4LMvv5jL9aBiuovH0pi20rhbHd@G0dLfLsF/dWRwtA62j8F7Du8fwp9s2CWsdbxo9Jv29/b4t/66CXvZ7En@toMeowTQoC/bFQdZTfLoKasJxwdSPzgtiFW@Ovi21vFr8SPRSbXZtLqPbTjZ@P2i4CuRFXz5siX8ebK@/Xm8/XzPn7yfd3EOM1aRn/9PzeSQEvZhnX8z65PrxzrlfAE59/5g/G@6Uo@A0ebgBEEVTfzD@Mt6eYGGCDuPpbaPwO8xdAagV/v3OmJHndAuXESwaYVN9v8XCDGjvPP@ZPBOgzXq0ucfvlVwvjp2CD3yfBwvUA5xOt/1lIXULa/E0dLbKuo3g4i6Edr5v/KS/T4mzgkNYaYE0zX9803jS@ZVE3MAnW@yDgxnx/2/yTd@t4RzzcsCaKIoDH/FUdLSIvoac@H5SOMr76kc8/i8/LmhUPZ4F2SgrMn9XRovX6RzzcwPHi/lryb/VsLXYfSBWrDpaF8MM8wi31drwtHm5guFrAcGZIGh6L60ePPh@4rb5/zR/i7iHfhvmBN0XjFis084@Dx28xeRcPN6hesexhfKl7GJIAUOowrHyYEgSMEqQntQ8jxQ8imDlKLCCqifmpp4d8Hz14uNq9EhLU0fzrGNbkchQPZyE74xGu9H2T5IBNNj2/S4BQx5nxhuQIdRQPRzT3tfximj@2JN7xlni4Okq4UOrR/DNePPpxAFN2vCNRAxW06FPcYPSr1j3zNUPwUJNt/ruOkj8M9BzzDVxB3ozE23Gfm@/Hk8@HhBIDFIXfn9oHgxIBx18SUYAqze9vSSrqqD4fZFEs8j/m/wer3EL/RzycBf8WgLziB3DXp@Uhn3i4wfJK8Ujmb3XJNKwiYX5B8zDfhNGeSx3geFM8HKVb08@X@IcBMt7v757xtpwewzQxnx/ZPkr6iYeThEAyglf8RR1lCNFasUblkzuEWqhUqehZ/wIYx/W5u3wjw6rIS2fgeFM83CAszfzuJX6kjmEv2clHDdDivj/iT@oYxhPEgLUuT7hQziN@ZZxXlpQ6iofDLML@Jivo9R0BfxzFww1r4zi/i5@RYsHxhni4eurytFDkpfwotYl/MIDrON6W26WO4ndAteJf1FE8nGQNFtU84n/qbzLFkD6y6gVcNMUsz7dC69Bkl5kyAvB5l3emjuKPpH1wvCEebj5Trpo6il@amql8P3g4nEj8rzqKf6o1I/NNHUeqfB79twkgulv18@DfUf1jhdALwoBSn@RrKQeSWudt4uEmQEPP7@K3pKJwvCEeDm@uWUY0xX9NYQJ8f41UEtUqtZRoix@bAFW4HwAiVhM9T8qJHvFnk91iQdErHq5u8sF/1oxlvI@0OO@beDjL8STH6ONXeoyUJ933834@7/nrfn/d8fYdf9/fO/f3T66n3eszTsv7N9ff3twPWchjyVPut7XcPwFX5qP1zA96Z17KDscbmU@ym8wvgTHmm@3F/Lfo84kf5vud51XWvc@vnTzPfp9vf/K8@5vnT5iH3ycfzfUQX7WaqmX94ABy/Thq3dKrrLd@1x8OCvevucfnM@uVekbmqwcPV1Io69vSRD4/Wf/9ZD@Muz80qF7LuNg/U/1iPZf7i9UT6pLm/psqWj7v7k/EdCq@sn/ruFPzNd3fU7XI@cv9P8n7Ot5WPgj7Yz5KECA/phv4DUkK47FRmM9a2Mif0qrKI6rIkE@1@1IBVg9u@b4rz6a4Q84fyjvpVhxvKg9J08rHBJ7QyrOl/JwzeLg6Kl@BHQ6r1o7yF2sJeSxxi8Vpr/JaWKKELp/ynBp45HupKeW96or5BHXD/K6ufphrqC/m1R91VJ9wOd3Pl/pmwvbg9/fMeEf9BOwRfYUTif4iioY@k0wmpDLqO24L/VdH9SFRavRjHdWXtYjUn1hX6NNZfs@Rr2qob6WlcbypPgZWuS2y2@rrOqq/58XD1VH9PoFx8DkFQ1tiG@0BCW4sy/u0F@qo/TBP056oo/bFPMHfT8vzeT@0R@qofTIt23lDleN4S3tmgjJkPoQNcP7R/iFob33d82gf1VF7aT2v9tNSP7wh3bHg79PeWk/T/lqgADy/a5@RDMx4bohfLC6mak2cGOevJxWD6xYQ7if1hHumvPC8qTY82o/rDR4O72FI@PNqb4Iewf6k1pD1KxEQ41EvQh3eq@ChCFF7Fm8J@3bd@g/QN8f3U3uYcPv0/KW9LKWQ423taaTJ6@8d7e2aFO1vhInX973a50v2jGNlI/b7ApDE/X2x7ynBRD4sgDDMB@KY@SFNz3wBxHC8qf@wyqzZVkMu/Quc3PlcmiPHO/ojZGnxTww/cH579V/quG79pP4NdZTbCsqm/7OoP7CGMv4RYQvk6zLBw@dTf6qO@lfCdB1v6X/V1emPLaqemR/zbJd6yaLMR38OaSfREkX5zDdRN@a/R58v4my@b/qLOJEhb@r6k5I4Od7Q31x96n8uqtj5fSrWh4WeoYciT2bh59GfRbzg36JN0Y8rjjOloPrDS1wQn3/6y8CL8Z/XCB5u4Sgxn/gPzG85HvjfddQfXxffTlFu3q@Wz9fJ@bvn@6l9W5RrMD7xMX5vPsYHFoYO1zMTPyjryXjCEm7B5814Qx1DhjW7@nyhuMYtUWU@5gwp1pzGMyS7crxlvAO0qvOLYLLC9YQgayXeXseQZK33DU3We4myPuMt0mZZ6NqMx9TR@AxRTddDTbDrYwUPxyZy/VA8K73fMv6ziGtxfyvxoQX7FvdPGRvzAQMX80OYl/naqalcoO@ZTyh9mN/9GZ9apBOfS@UlmVc3nrWAKfv5MN61EDd@f@6Mt4yP1dF42SId4e8f42mSglmS@xhvA@3h/qYGmPs5r/E5vu39ns/4XbkzxvMW5XXMD1WZP/RijjeMBy5gIczvmcYLKfZVPp34H6TZlF/nGG@so/FHrEIrap/EJ0s2p972@YxfcnNW45Y9j/zcz63VfbrxT8KEVvI@w/hoHVPn@yR@urHjqZIlqztTWmyN8LONv27iS453jM9u8bnUF7/Gb0n6pfo4@qOOtza5Gf/dRP09vxsf3qTdpVkbxo833FL8HlU4MnEu483SsDneNh69rSvn82O8eguEnlY2e7/fa3x7gyJlPlD/zM@noAyhm2XO3Xj5BoDI/NZp6GvSlejvfevVNukZ36@Vz7fxef7N9xO/37oB1E0/xvc3P8fvU0fN9TSRqBzND2xh2nzezR9sAALWXSe/UEfzDTuJbI7mI8rdNT@xSbw63jZ/AbzL@VUeU479mO/YN/@xgWH4/jM/QtW2z6838yd1TIU49VOMX9vb5w/aiN8ncB9qzpSJdw07juZvaheZz6k9bH5n93ALbOqZuP@SFq7P8ZofKmFgvkgKPcYjYGbFuMDYOvaWmvF@btH4rRqfb8rGp/mqTcDC85f5LMn4HO@Y72KzWjwOroDfn4/5MVDHXh8OH9crOwOfN/NrdTTfJq2fpejdfNzW4Ofzab6OEnULyWfwcBuCBubTOhw@P@b/MB@RT6J8GY/wue@tcKOq3XxiHc0vlpj6QiXYzD@W2Wk@cisuOH@Yr5Rq0PGm@cyyYsxvbtOWnL/Nf24EmOMd86MUaEt5aN2KJfPmUyUttGhew4QaevOvmzoU5rsmB/@vzF7lVR3N324m0M@n@d0NvN3vJ/9bR/PBlN83f@@YL0bs4p/uEzwck4f/urWP@fwz/wx8EP0okSLjEY7l/ilnYj6Ur5w/zW/vEy6UbViE99t8@DaPzvnHfPm5@XOL/X3/ml8/j5U@VP@bfz81XdayPxpK0AGYr0drWPiOONxvyB1D8mi@/2AVUjRfXrI19ISLKaln2h3viB/w9reMAuILypoRbyBNJOOBMqN238JTPm/iFU4NbqH/xcNhVUsD8E7xDkSDJQkoMSRnwBt8RB3FS5SWET9xKFjh92tbSj/whWPnUNDA9X5fC1fBd0JdIItVqCslNugrPAcCqTmK96B8R1IEwrWOt8SHYCTKoAAAlPkGtcX8X3qxOoo3OQL@IED4xKPgJh3JMtuly2ziV474Mj4f4lvqKN5FOk3Hm@Jhyr0SH3PAj3E/Akb4fvBwrArkwwHYwHzUqkN@1FE8jsScUjA08ToHd0gShi6eByGNfDqXu8n0lO@neKD6UHzQkV3pDcWn4x3xRHUUXwQoE3l5xiv@qI7K01ru4pMw5pC3ZbyKXzritt6QhTLeGOKdqF7rkohO8VCUPcmpjLx0vC1@6hDIZH6pp2S@4UV5Lu1oKKzFYx3Qen7@idcqc0b8Fs6x480uvuvMId7rEMee0kuIB5PANESm4sVIy6H/QLWhDzF2j5QT4QQ74KUkpHjFo8lIwfwIq79UqIxnmQnvu/i2sprEu9VR/Nu5nC6lTMTH1XHn8y1@Dlhvvh983cGQmrJciL87@/4@hgXXgyHAeMLapvwXXv/u4vsO@CVZMoL/K7Mu90@USKKMJV6wxJH4wbODhzvkSSXLeMQbUkZ2pMu4839iX1Ed5PNhwft5z/OrBbb8frjmcPubVBz3@ZP/5PeBp3E9J/jJo73J@yO@kqcu4BLuKRGYvEgJeglCMZq8ELT5ErK0yvJRmr@Xgza8HmOEOrYcjVDJPtkKLyHqUM0@txid5GqoaJ/TQk1LXZjfgjnDcd73Utm@2ZJQgoxLddveS33bVqhw38Dk6sUQ98oLgbAQh4iM5YWiIUy5GXkLpuWF6Nr3MSt9Qi9ifezzheSwXrwidF8zwFJqQDMmhwky8/kh3w0rSVfM8azFAfPihIgDizPjrEvVgebNb@0eMo9PPeCLFbqPFjzyS745hCAwkHlfLSKbF2KaX1bCJT3pop55cUI7Ah4nvCfzDTFJC3K6XkR1QIkitpoXK@Qm7Yi@tgYrTxDavvzlbZcg5RXBDYPKvBQqwXjz4lySlS4KvF6MLzQsfYgTD89KRl4iyXmxQ@XSt1hzHOs3ZC89aHTYWHroYMYrXp0XK4QxQ4gVL9qllBlNzDsuTQvpzOii4uvFmKGl@alrf6x/8S9r3HNiWkjxcsc5KW7HGMhvwaPrr5O48HrILHiF87vXPGPiQK715L6m9yxJTMu9z3lpa4jjOj/YwSGOWSdzOGNqhcE5I5@TmSdM57NY75ens96T57Vuwbt5wvwlJl@96CPPnehJxhl3bVjd41/Wm/Wz1s6KqsWbNXZNT16srMP99KzM/T5Zq/tdl87mu@uZgugQ2rSVNb9jAkNx82Rf7JEi@Mc79i/ryW6CxsKns3fLjruVKEqz7EpSfJ5TQjY7F9Rn2HECz@PFyX4H6Omvw77k9Zy4BGHDDi32DEkwhG@RLeifGZqdL/LnXJLhEmxW5sC884XqplbRG0LtNyTFEmyHjec7obvBOpG/5ukhOWYbKDNdrFLUAK3JX2ZIkg2q5lvigS5nd0Y@IVn2x/z1N67aK6O3V0ixRsh@vh1a71cgOC/6F2pvJK8EOO@49N5vXMZXT1gOHEAhIQnaX2i@332JvinIllcIh16ioe@xcoudresaZvFwCX0hqSYofHJO1/3lhfVh8A3N2/9hWkHGi5MuENRIhKNohyRbsvKMfHTDYTeyTo0XIdl@pQKVmSiuPC@sdXshebGYHVYXq@mhcbHcXf5zR8YQdeabsXRfGFJ45Qv3eV06VV5YlUeNQs85Mp/Kg/SGZFxK9TAhJbTBC2v/4EgKSTlU4lbXvz1wvxd@E@vrITTJfZU4HSFnT4glLO0Z@YQkHeWZ1hkoWucQ@LyzOi7JOswiabsxEuqpF91aSFZESNrfWy3Ji5lnKtDAc3ZI3l8TaWFsSsk9DkY4k@ZzSeJJQns98PaFRP67vEuzXZL5mqUwM82EvurFGOFumvOu5yk9Ii/WyJonUeQcEjCdP/T0jrwSgoPg4QmHFNLZp7O@FpapCwvkxQoPFXwdOWe8YapaCQWG8T4jr5D014sdtiueSeinzhc@rBWOf8p853MZqL5QaMEtEQ6qb4Zka7fLurUFcPtihZdrjx6iLoDMzuoNjWJO9XB77f2G7Av0vE@HyfB5nR9@sPOcEIadd4ZB7CRECwOYNcy8WJfGX03Pi2GY1@2@wos1LYwO1X9GTqj4fc1hec6xuJoXVlvjo8eSgSch/XQAuEsQJbJBBq2ErNM9QE4pTAdJpmBnk3WK6Lc0VGhNeamedYmqHksqfWHoHIFkbTkZRovN05Ag7Fyv4XdAdtanvxAPqJc/KJa8wjchfOSZNe68sOhdMi9Z6j74UqStelMnzwsL5@uFPukv8oA9ofZ6rLWH@2tc8q/PavzXcn/pwaRf81vdAv73p6KfF@v@ZfZ7znrvt9a@4@yfkc93f@uc/DqEJV5PS2olnRhuS4aVu6D8K@xi/c2dWuDEOG3c2dAm9S9J8bwwf2QOqRaZP80dMvJZmXkKFHwW/X3zdPobJr7vppp8EnmmoMNzTg8b39dHy0rol48Ppvuslr7CyFdK@cuKqp2YNdbPXXWS0/AXcJbe13jDy0eh@UhPoTBP8MLUG1Rp4eb7xpCsghdh5/tG4IiwV4Sf7wMBlVYWOwx9lIS74xS4jizI2r@8YekrXWcaEdq18PQBP7tNMHqY@mSt99cNzfitKXlHGmVk5G06kxfh60N5Km0@LawwuEUiAaFURsHlptT6FIOyujXTqum9EV63IREJL8LcR4VCCxXcCncfqy9PcO2w933rmN59QWUoez8Bz@9t5@HIOyliqOLC4VcvJFXBawmLH2XOuWZ4R72LPUPMQkWz@gLHWg1ih5CMfELuYq2JM0bczjkkwNbCPxdtRUFFGP1OUub1ol9OP4Z5fpqOODLxkPxlXV4/eNLzrX2Z/W7q/rWGWC45BEDI696w3xDDu/R2lx@nXoQwp@FBySj3BELwyjQkp9wzYxXUfIWFp5H22aHFC08P5k9anLyXyceSXqnh1A@2S/lC/gN5nnZL@2l3Qvhu5y9j3HNmGIVk@884l3OI0Pv9rRNWonoRmqIGIY1X@P305vq@MBu1L9AO7LJwH5XwCBmSDVzC1jdCl2SVhDNmSwa/tS4D4LfvPH/ncgBSrR1Sv@eyALY3tE3tVx7AOjtEgHXnYQJsgbrUi/HDBTjODxngDxvgCn1UY7t6PW2HYMo2M2EEDOTmpQdBOAH7G5IqjMywAvbAIHlxeQEx/ZwxCj@cwx7oTzrXXK7BkGU1ygB8Fv2ETqteXH7AcdsBwRMXhsARCBIvLkeg2PX3NsNxZNI1/tYYlydwzBB/wbugv9MuFKpe7HCFNfeiZIZP2MQoRlP@2F/HkecXArIGg4UzNgPJIt4bzrJy4@O1gQXWj6OMU3nY5grvGYWbysz2w4xGZFi52iAY9hywD37LonHGWYFLQqcY/rWSFSFkqxdhaAMhp5y3C1A4GFdI3Rrpbu9r7dC@kdXRFybKmtkot1l/mUJc9U5DoDmHJdDUTTYWcuQSaDuthkb46ErHhKBOZRNGx2vJNBRI/nJCctcocr8sj6HBs1dReB6/EOU1QvVhegx0EArIcOs1whuOfEbY9@rxhY4PRWvsggJGbQDbH2XkQBhfKyHkXMRc6CGRDAug7DahkWzhCZR@VyLHp4dJsD@BUkbEyK34rOf@Zf2cs8f91rnjENFMA6bn/tYbSGcqBWc4KkOCaJOmsFT20CR2/JzwWM4QKdaL3Hu/0FIoLTM/FgdKBoktKxsk/FrSQX53njviS0LI78uz6F8grki@PK8yZG7TKKyB/GVe2kgITfKtfYklvx@mye9c6snSAeGipMbK64HmYIRN89JXWqjvX/oluLTk3G@NS4HZfjgxgX45PziazhirzTmkXM5ZpdLUkSVE9C/vDxXn98PN2X4l6/xh7@w/dJ7j8nv2eQk/Jfp1nHUpQfHn8lvnkoamLMcXl1Z0/PCMju8Sj452mUhHu9Sk5Z@Gq5RkSchB52UzHfPSm44VOcZ@W7@25QpDaCDhvIg8RNAqIUmWKzP7hWm@wpjylx4i1vrtyF5L2TLOlc9kWJXYJbAjwylbU6p36HW8QvjXQkD6RhdYYHkpSqMv5Cr13tdlmYXMUy3T5U33nBliWvjg1E39QvVfa86c@XVCbtuBifh09hv62/7DZ2h/kPylRVf2nZIB4wrq014uZ0beMzq3Qx/jr1M35vXsE6JeW5xd5tRQ@Voj5n2dL2S/9fxjA9SL2xitbC3thA6syxk7M7YE5msaq51rb3RrD/zLiU2Ca5ROnvDxhYf1p58n0fz8JaUcvIj9Q68fx7ERm2ylhHelZyX2Kj/rs0KgTOWWttZ4UlICEib22DBsyTnEKtLS7QtNs73dwvvaQuQMkCKt3d6UtgAAj31oEVZGXrEhB/3OpF@lc9lz@WJ9XuOHYRqmrJ2/fLFXyTX63C02dZwvsE/oZWP3IhZdPxTkaBuLnPYKv2s/k6s8IZt9YmMP@GBCR/vGDh8tfUTrRYutTtcG1zxWhvb8kMvop6mdI7cVGu8hPtFzdoi@R6kifYef0ieYYuJf1G4PWXi9iA8yeguduH3ywoc7QjgOEFBfZvSUYEGJG38HDHiuuZ/4RCP1gtLlxm8CP6j8sfWeI4@UgvEi/teAZCzt@UZ8tNri7dLtrvhxAzxQCHd3fL0xUpKWbn7h3H1D4o4Ya2Hl/ULzPmaLX1mK7rvN/3p8TwAcyvAyX@KfCsnyCudllx/CB/3LiZ9b1xVC@gES3HtfKdGzkEN/eawWUnuqh/SpKbpXN9lz0JEh0HLm14pvztWo47AT9d8pjbw9dZ/4@KUOQ78vjZrfAjbhOPsy9o@dkkWohBNPoOVHSJItBnacwEh5kbjEAAAYYuEnsYtxUjqZzojhIv7SbAD/2RjIcFf5rZE4iWlfRz4zsRQz6z4LIbN@66TpwfzpgjClb/Avb@I28qFI7EuyQqbfW0rKi8R/ppzxnjMTI8IW9Art33gbOdq2AecysSYbSElBTIj9pFnxJVHGmZa1GLtbGuMobXmTv0uknDYSvNg/VMqJj0GlFTLl9ySGNr/7BGHfn/nLO0OoDNVkGJhT4psuk46sl@NfRmJ6ls14PWX/uMaI@36XqDmxwfml1JiwZOKHs70t5Mrtu/21WbLOT2uJQ1IQE4LlNhKrLBMjO4UaGPfOhHwoDTB3Yp4Ts8fndXkZ8YyfEC2DGPGcntJrqKETXy2V127rzJEYrEaBv95n4rSzL9uWpL1mRk4JOC8S7wULfEIi/SYmDCnUD8104salR9IOlooV5RjEdUo2O3Y6sq2i/MtOjJryFCXkhJ7B5zWvFC1rJbHuOVMSD7I@8fCpR/beJqBhsR7CVKGzTlx9UkHi9cyV2Pu8pfkE4xOfr1PSNnauNzH8enHSQnTdOD/TlBajyKMwZIciALs8@QIM9JDQ4DaVi5zOVh8vSjiYqJTTZSY2skMBKjUJ8LcdPuqOv/QJoyf2WWq71rLQgy5LWhcLCpcj5GK0r3vM/2@dl@8dtwufpXREPbOfz4bzgMItgY9rWblTP6f1vSiggoR7fhcnKfNKT8PEml@QNuQxg/75qEcoQSp8AusI9OObSMCwBIYlbAV8zdYBLPWEKBemxOXG@pUgnBpG@uAtiRy5K8m6bakFYTRPABx5CoIWDCLnxOZEQp4HUEzY1GpB7JUGdoDQh/xrI1xydcXDQO5I03UpUMrC/AlBlCgjsDDS/PyDMT8JjTcFLwew49PTuvUhAo/WnIanaaX12arghq95TGTnvOlN6n@oUqWc7cvulCNNbmrNADuT9QlWjlBBCZKmrAwdmPQ1wZt5WnuEWn5WapLgFTiGV7cozmzhGcbTvT0U4Cx6xNVZ8jV8Vt9tfEMsqyTtsFBAAuW6S7Ikt3ENODFqNgDwpPUbGOkO/DpNZAfY4pqU4Gbqt0gPv5eXtkHUCAfZTRmhjrnl/cO@vah8egLig7sT4t2RNqkwO9U6LFMpFKu2JFsAgI17wGjTrSex0IBrIDiWegeUDMHzS@MOxvLI3fwIH8XIx9gk7R66JGTDuUXaH9EoQDn7hOv7ITIHAlV1DqBN@J3kb5rsvE47pY8AKCQPR4TJN50HaDx0C3mWJKPala0fhUoNkglhpNNI/Wo3Jtsku6UiWO5KhOwGE3F7w9C6QdzLrcnCFaa67lL2s0rAa9ZmklKMSgz4Jnu65OKT2ys1CDoQvKz2b/0EZkA/nCuzEXEH/ZZUIphSGqY86wnrIeuAoK43SUyZUGJNsBg352bSoEpZYkLg1YiNYQi1//ipNP2I7X50W54haKZCmD6oSXjUUy8/OkkZkKFrYJFfDjETJrQDVeJtOB16OgWH8gEJBx/dk4e8NWwM9JNTWk9J5GH5CvgBiOSIRIQVd5Wq4vlLMrMMP21yN3KuU2VGXH8ZqhlJOo5zffG6S4JsJFri1AANe4CmWIrEzAjfv00HH7UBmXMfEwz3JfrGJQDUam6XplfifKjWGvyQ@ip70omDX7j8OJmUERo3/ExMgO@nX/MgoAeyUsdKn/cR8/ppSSOGKAVBJUlXI86xvTdTUXMJAUjvt0sIKbWyOiCZiwdOvAMcS2txUyBxNAJ5u/MAziQhZxxFmFptciDnRzR0B9VARXtAwp9TDvNyOjWTBqVsDY4DSYspUigJqpW0AxZuOB2JRn2iXLQx00JBku7np6SHdDRXsuCgV/NQjFubBw4KJAzKO2BACbjoNCQkx7pDnhbfSAvUAb8jKj3BgSOLKdZdWh3pK3bsreS86B4Q4uLbaop2ESNNpgE2Ma3rREia3sX5aJfZVyybXUQyp7VDOzttBj5pZ@0u3Yi9bF9eUQY@9psKOPJgNY/f3doP3PGnW5ggbzQUIQ/xN@vWLKR9IihFv9DJ4VbVoqC2zI62@ywhP8T/bjHXL/KhZBVBYDlzS2/LDsQ@tlacWMUkkxRKF1pdkUc2gUfjh4fY4a9R5hoFF1dKHCNwpeahnXxC7Dztemd9qETBKM@xn59@GPiKK13QghemJM31KX3zDkNguu2U@sZ6gqzJ9ovPstFyvFfXq1izMB6Rvqp1UxMqgfO2wcJDVixgtBLKi@Y4l1gdZkp22W16TuOMja10rIurFQOzV63/LZr1k7AU0slkEWmFW0J@nLTx2fCWINLC2iBpHBN8vA1iwxTep/QQe/zc4D0KxA4hXfQuYHnqEZ6f5jCQDUIRdpcYxVGLLt0pvmfedApnSN0OsLHPOpTy44mCktadYWPX2KmHmW4T8GjWAiLoGVZ6cYY19E7HyDYlwJYToOaLNhwwa47bO0vaa1C3aZ5M8w2bZKc5Oykq19KUYX5C1sQyfmK0CnLElTUkeGDw4Q5CVAztAr2CRvp/QROTkraAlGuG2Rn9siTgJfT3h7QAlAhEKzf2@RBp9bLSeQFscb0Fg2UaqC502LdbAnIeA/5foD60PcBu3fRFsz/IayulMqDC423UcUHf1dOJm6gfVebBBwEdwWY4K13V4GmmA5cRIFigXvbAsdqQIhpo0/cMwg8ug9ofk77AaW1Ykyvh6hfKAIq8JoR6Vkr3UGezY1YaNn3Yee0GggTTaC3uNEbHdxj2EXztYDvF9u/ACggkwf1ivgZPrkMke4SiHcD08AON2yqPvS0huRXpoDZlnwhB5qbUWfIBeePN4cDFJss7EgAo@/g1ZNesbLazAbW4pSGG7XtxkD4ESD1riU5pb04c6/bBI5APufqXekGBLJgh9EmQ7@DB@e63fIdweglCIDZv2jNNGQLQzMKVHhLhMz3oJ/Cmkkq03EjrMxrizttZju7LFM9uqXEg0gfgO0LrvekeiO1xM2I1nxCx3pAupW3QlVJ0Ro1BiQC2z0ruB9MQyMabmAiFPeAcWlok0@gHLn8y9xKU9mbE@9LVAMqmRjXWd0lhOiSD47cIRg7KNn6yOmTJIRRbof6kVgSz/Lut5YfkLck/YRlhfqNJw6//mNl6qC46tnel1PnTOUs2EGGBKNOa7NIZfN2iCppO1S2SRw3pNIkH6kdCFafEAzxsf@MlYwJJrzSuAFTZtFQlTDAs9RkftL/HfLCDSCr0oDCPa3LfmCW3AEciUJH0MSXJ/uievrLHg9/uKV7e4q3q1ptZnto4@7WxUBqRa3WVTAvQl91JtAGbSQaMht1@oY0k6qAeTS8HgAi1EhbcM@H6WWCz2goOCcVZ4qClo3PvJv2NqdsQYENZ1qHdk9@Z/LAG2bC9BP0g2N1BjePRQmkuy64yb9kf7xu3efeA2I88pt2tLf6ZJnIv7KQMCoIXtraoBVJqa6fTSlpmPVvCrdvhEuDKLcSomUkH3rBcQKILROiSQtaewd7YnzW2@OCsaPkjKUdYYX21vZLl@TRBb/dH7LvxvoExTFDWJfDftIH/sJBrDvcbNo0y9Oj3hQeQFu40uaJe2BYLuFaY/isUaOczp/WEQPxVfJXSrAk@gZzX4x6mEHVyjlSR8/JswSZXhpHNTG@ZDZ0sbhMZrGyQ6ztFR1AtsMgeUR4wMUNy0i4K4BqFCf6ylBEzK6xikqG7wFJ0tonOEVlPygkSmQYaXwrtMimseLhh5EYL2q5dLlE0ufwPGoB4EMtk35dMn3WRZBQuhLokCmCp24Fa28kKTGu/eXRtOOV2UNsoTtxd9UKtMEK5HclvI5BJZSAPIQ1oJHIh6t0MZOCBYUykO9VR@LcdtNJgZaiuw2VZ6pj6uydU1pQgAp40xkL0ZU5zD@PXJ9SJ8J5X3J4jY5YGXvaBMqFq44qZhuW9f7pidMmOyecGdMcyJyiiIgDcJzkFkbnn19Yoz/NTcmqwT14rO3V8BsDZdGHmsO21ddYhPqYkykoT@9nYQIz6DAPo8H1NsJ50adRLXXRZf/dliXnQI6Ar7d3RFQV4tQmLE8qrzcDDtFcJukLxclo4WnazDnCkBJ7w0iddURi82MSTvhp2L99sLJpcmf23fxH@OUUYM3saj@5ccCSoYVK28F9RhgcO0c2kUyde5uyZjmgfEWeI3S5KWZhX@rmkyqVDfbWhMAgACmr88QNaa7pIpycxRhXXpsI0TV0oW3/eUD59loqvttJJbEkl/vwQ6BP0osxr/PS7Q3nRdj591DDiMYqHRBS3SgRvZSQlW0tkAC75KSeqO9jomnZpbaC5xIQM66pscMTKLGYihktI40uVG@Eg53KFwQvEzFlpv9JMO7MdUq1mEfoEqk3yZTj/yzoofa@y5jBglwheOSn9jUezhJMXfW0sJTczegS@N8FNxDJgnW8hfAXLXg6fqbsnRGGEnUjphS@cjg3knYIXgtaFXuWWSULvgFCVjFzWAuj6ShyhB7E7UUEwjcT/ILsJ29y/9CRlCyfQF07@2rMYTzEucRjMeq8AhgENGAhIoJCYHrmypLrU6va2HAE5kvneODwnfX42iB67xdnNiagIFJyzxUug3B0dcSsqPvs3wMVsCg@L4RNuFHMMDk4Ab5@r/oNxq4mosUFSpxcXCMQvabch5dF5k7CWkTMVfvIgr4lTTp6tSRttzMziKmoCWIwrJeMA1jd4qTS8Mbb9uQBv4z9gQ7Ud3yQkAFQR/JppPOZOcl@HqBhNRGj52xeZLyPsY7eBrLFhNUkLvxjb/hC/abEoupiphc2l5l8Wvtj9xkA7fUA68dE072TfsNvdS0aOiMGm9L5WC7vz0GBdhiQ0RxmpQzw@EOPaPftixz5xl/U7eJ72SyEEi3eQtkIgr5BBo6Wb2aAUyerWlKjQHacL5LF5IqhAjGPBXtYLTD13fcMhVxiwhut4lj1lDNmSCOKthziG/FVUAoAYoQxcOlhkFaSat1uigKu6yh0DHhLDZutTOUCV91LF25JSKLnh0psXlWuD70j1u1HqAlHV/wfm@JH2pRbh2RKgBUj9wT@yVrzaH1a2aF0qr0vnIfq0sLFBELvPcm6WcUHCcGnYQjYUpH/6WVpAWDsI/@XILwZRJiaYKTlhrjAJ9y8VRajKUn9PuhdS/kNDp4UvniLYPczmrQBqDFp@I71s5Uhpv5oLtPSsd8PQlMoQg3zPEN0SsHwTjknhNbFigLO3vxmlCkM2/nF/GcI4SQakqeCDFvBx@fhGrS5FHeKb8NrZ8xYAr/JCB25mGEprbJox/QDe6ZQIHbBQGmDMxNOwoVLEMR65yl@RdXRFYz19khwMfQ6tMp3BUpp0fTuhEiKDTY73Mrp@qlUFthEjAoys9p/GZSIKSrof1SFRezgW1nLLmNihpBT3LukUsh1GnyF/xlMgd5WWhMxhPWJaUyfBt6A1/hUcD2e3fdup4PeWMR1ZXxeLS@QEobYyJcRJu0Q/SihbCEFjEEanWqib2MCeaey3sEzraT5N9DglOML8CRzbsIj7brK3GbwC@ElVeQuSyRAgKyntDydeLDpt35riTSchrLdlc6/GwxqB/gH6SJQ2LX9eAbbAXd5bOt@lVboNbJdAzCMtIbIJKc77tAcmlnbOCh8RMXECHMANk@n@HhvcrZAoDsQHBOIXgljOhLQxzeIlJABRrHXc@wCg2P3f/Cm/tHbnldBVJh8oh7rTaUNRk7XUYtvYBc0D19vS0yNMNrmY0O1SfAzstim5UQeH0qNJefKbNpLEPahXD@0XoS98kDceKOQZG/BOYl1wxQAsI0pv9nebZNKLx0HXz6XjrQWpCzIHED/9UmpDCYRn8gTIP9NDMwb/DMEM@WH7QAJe2HTJuCW6TFVN2fuD@wGHqMqTNssqVCJPU7Yo6oHp0HWMv6R02JRxliRcbZhG57k930hFpv5CgwWSFeiZzLQaLiIUs5BdXQpE8h91fUllkilE8fUUMtIQjPq3aRm/qaSS12Arbyc8U@gvboANrgA2HNDU6euKFTDlzPuyfUgkg2FfYj/Wa8iSMmfbOqzjWvp6mh/WujwSTku2xsMyCvIESPeFAaJ2hFTOdTWrW/ElY62Ci7TEm9L1yaYCv3PrW2re68z5JW1KA86N/waaI8E6MhLCtCD9g1DXXn0iRgCDY0jYKZlWBFib6QBE3soegCEYkS6rvL/20x@EMC12gVW90Hp1ldVlZexSI7yRa2meiUVhMB93E5709/kByhK7pjPlTbJhTwNPSSc9Qz6gbuzHqHYh9wStQaCrW5RLeGFApIDG@GS1xQ8WC3JZVMjqktyePV22CNURY7@F3tqC1Nnv8A9sIiAsCBuHPQIjdnhCuhDa/VN5YXOaB2IHcy6E@7C64cK3GwP0ylANhYxh6KiKiGWvgigjjiix1iEKSyYdWPXtR/whRbQlyDrtV7vUIBhPENv7Sdc9SFBZvT9NR@uGNn1elKiJ1K79awEk6F0wBz2UrpgbD66ZPZpg7Elz4wBMSXaRC4U38ZYNkVEm96d5PCmiBK9wyURQoZCzLJOE7NkpsUdULmgqmIcCbT92g@KpprRy2qPtNRyYnl6Y4N@liqTFwUfCYEkO8RGprlV99k8jmeU6wky2ey9yzh1vdSDa0cYdkifAhpQ@XrXXmP9LFQJ7HOAyqnhkVyNSsISUXERRJzY/UhJWLnKzOHH8FOUCO9WSNnJPVtH@pzcds@1WTTWAiWCjfcBQ@hIAyPOxvcI@4fxf4uwgPt4ppAVxTT9bGd9Bhx9Ziq3ZEy9h85pLd4icpHbJrtVzm@XpI00ly97YUrfKtffYRXKZoDqunkPboictk8H9Std4Qs2KewLS8LmYFvyngXozUfvKYEmUUaU@ra8hkKTTDLoE5PobjUTksaRpCeoVbDdtp4hIX2wYsX7igOFO6lC7EZ@6req5alLEM2FisDy497jWdqz6SNye95bSGrmr3/k150uMbtld9acPR7ggtTc2MWiy4@en8FUgaJp8Lh9MCEChWSojY0ggZiaHIFDaYFjKewB9yeJqW7lJBSVNcOwyw8apJQTrWQ/7C0k/1ntQmtAad6mAQs5OU42HFWOvbHvmEG5qsi9sA@/GrOzwhW5hsOuWbnYMbob96uAptCd4Sj5JEh@YqfS9H2BRnW0imRjYNHjTaovIyYSVgfgM@n8AJycf/IWjp0lBCtuMaAXqzgjJBkn1yEMlq4esTMPGVyvNjSQgGlKBnjRhLruIDp0zvTfw@XBwRiq1as2MY71L6j/IMD39ht8/7CggPP0Sb5VBaesFvnmAWmIzPjvF1DzmR4xtirgsqd2S6jvPJBWbMF9aZeCwgtlIR0yIzSaGqf0waMfWQS1aEtWp/QP48ab7r1lNwD2P6EaKPr5kEcxVWCr9A/KnlBO652NV3JAojPjQhXeZcUbq/RQ4YEyDJPsul8FnVvzrCRkdgOuEKLTya2uQjGWXBszxkJjoQctY67BpVG@AY6Z3L0SXgUQDBDo9bVOst39gAU4gQBZwUsOymJZCwhyFUySBmIcSgs/Wj/a0r6tqIvq0xGD0gqHp/PQ6OWb64/mT4MbvfXv6UGHCQGqYdBI5pL3eVBMQYanHN1JFBr5O3@sNDJkQVF3NkJkTGxoIdFAuSmmsRgIyAj1ProrYNlT7n45yLfxNHDedOl2Aja/nEX8nGaYtIRkzjWF63sDKICDFgQpd5Ws/p@fSRdDsmHHXD20R2BpIbH56603Jwp@08jOZjBBOw3ji6Xs9l8etD@K6/xLuqTVI5mONdIUHtIojiAVp0RFW6bvTS5QQGnl7EKi3tT0gOTKrJl3g2QE4HK6MbogzQOrFmuMOUuJAyBaCddEpiuV5eY8OSREwbZKEy9@ByCEB8EXPiq/7LJWuCyKIVrL7/WmuBzzfyEMq4NHsWGzfT@p5ULBF3aSt5UFUICjSogfdbHL02GTQqkctEEDuj0EXpB3xi5CLEF8GiC2B9Gsalxh5eFpfVfb8aScOcMiMuGyDsm@BR3ztAW4uUWLuH3gGcTCSj7dXZklHAivid2mBJomuORkaB6RKIThIgo@vg8kaRDkgYI0W1xovmYAlwVqbrZIwJKic2i6uxwDxI1ciAW@SJG1e5o6HrhnNRu5qHbIercdxG8hk0CiyVj@UMGOJSm5ZV8BvAkDTN6KpczcGBSQI7UOI/NZRLApoOmVwoZHDBGAtY9Xa0BNXdIWADk3QcG6pIrOto9lBtntC2Hiy4KPTNATnGtOoS46IK4toBM9mi3pbczGxR4pd2ECg629yhNI5lErZyzN@LHG5GxBBYL@mS5kCtB8C9fAiTXsoQwVxyxo/UlaUpbYARge1dt@TrQKUcXQ9FIWK6CRyir@ysNRWGoY52AH6wni6JDqkR18wBWLh2E3U7qspmABrih/TRlpesFmIln/xaCXdeQzH@dA@W3DgPrxh/AVBVieNJD4hz4MBiprRFeY8FD91Q6K9iQOAp/sSFcOVgKttXKapBSobyk1hYrUXoNRZqfc0LE4O6E2xjEKZPMfzpEhSZCChpsyv1SiQe6XCDIbwZleRy3xsGcKjK0HTewLDv5KVl7I3I3avEpZwsG4yD0Ie8xjulwWYcB20HTa2DnWH5P4UkLzxxD9YpAkfKUzf8qTgix2p0qOc4zN1ZoeYj45vDa9FUwuaaGJbO2WsSxohkuzShWPUPzJn75SW1YkGQ9MsYRjaIxlm8I3c2kLxdanMhp4G1YiiSmgERtNHkeV23KzFhtuX0i2ssDJgcLdS/7O/pLOORJ2ffWvNO9jn7ZPpgLr3GIjE9x/QEAk5yuNaQvSyW1FSSyWitjcdAh7bul8Fit24JYdYISdp4GjovB4qzrJxjXenWPUBMfmM8LZDXeXUvSE3I94Ms/BJd@ch/mFbiGmzaagxgBHYGxsQNgkTxBHISryuOYOUJTLBkw5NOnKsbgHKhoC0qeiyCsWyHmKtBHQBvSOqN20sl3HqL0AD@zBs@fawrY9@6heOK2olETknRfd2GiibZN9ADhAHqFRGKCYbkagHBLD1FMMOnNLAagcaUvoI64U2mxKg1LexRIECvT@hKzbLufgerEt674ENkYgM0kpgXTSyJowJ3VlrQUs@mnhpkCAHWXlVWC2YO0TTDt1tUqJABUWUr@mbQ2RFwpEURgK3ICUx2ropVRnEepyyLuZtypyAFjfqEDQrTC1TrKwIa26ezPnpoW0B30tC9rWCBnKPrYy5yH5qtsmh2LzRUn/ScS/lAduA@ZlpDMGuUg0S7kllpI3qMY/mvjUZGz1@dbj8CFi0T@Q08CfiJSWNEi9Ho5Mnnz9mbNO9x4NNNIKrS102iRzG5vrcZDR/AFR0a487RRCIXwPk0DSRFT9vbrqBrsZBDb002AX3p/D6@dlXeN8uw/CEQitxero3HCsyiSOvNEu1C@tjHR/@VIdGKKIUgz9N0GNb1zJHpPe0oyS@De0GGQdjBXb1ArJ2EuIwzXUo3NO42tIvYtPbPQX1QUAb5AgQdRQNj@hNk0IKmZR/T5dEHXcDn2KnNxqVDQ@AO6cHT5hwXH3JXVgP2MwJCYPQc06hJKCgHgGupEoHcTstKtJVCFM72VphQBDQrsmy9dFAC9zKufX3hHreEWYEm9NxDz@EBBBp4euOS4Kyh0x3MZSHrXWeaY8QOlvZDHeEe/LDx5YMfyRd9sl4cgN61lSSlaVbtCGlbqDnX9hDaMRlmWsAYW6SKfm2QchamzzPGawVD88G3N@wyd4DO7IdAsqKEPz05R0ZfBDrTVJJA58p9F7LB1vfpOzuXDAo0IZDJ9s3XSDZNCSbYcsJGwxY4iHSz24FBCetiJf0syHz0rhJ7n6iT8bEUgK3CBtMGxtJ8W1QI0I2neuWMRqZ2WmIB0aZBPZnVQ9WKcV@aqJDJK9U4YhZ8F1eOjvV2HluZRqHvqhb2xSd4GRQySEgSabUsgB7JtQzgNI2dAX18zy1/b3J7p0mXBuzE6f41Q1nx1iuTLYSRU0JliQ7QugA0GtctKCXj5FeSuqUfSHfnVPQquXA7gA5ibFsA0klX2lVO@3YMMuxMVtwHa/1St/FIyOjudV@qxY@IafmbGOdLgNrG92yEm4n4dDkbbb41XYLFJDp@COXueYdvmC2S0nkV6YtC2TkygZtZOyfNYWzbUWd0cOBgZb6eauLKSS6fH/jGNS5fbmZG1ImO2Rg5IledbHWV7PUwJD1FJn/GvR702uU1lRWXuD0PGFsI6U8g4ons8o9YTsmRM9kkzS2U5194YiMXC7kacNcyWLDb2jDAvo7bvsEitNiieuxAUhRRX3pvj61ZczJhPwPQq010uyhBNMH55uQLbjvoYSjaD/MVtf3/pJU2QKEV7iFSaHhWFK7mTByg9wa0aTrQDjzM9vlc9wEvMEifNJrfPZyg96WlUsiEjPsJLYjb94jy7rWJX9g4zUApWgWBHQziV9rGgFHrwGi8IS1kVA9ADgSlASCYLSHybTbu6CRSeS7lv@yeqicAalH@hoBIDQKKDs9e8pkTAsTABM1qtxuQyg118MXbaC4CJKeTAbBEdbA7a3OI7AE8kuDJKBg3SyV0oUCBRxmvVNKepZxrpnGLvJHtLTs5so@@@Zh55dMpeIH9IENEWEzpmsmmhGM@7LVlRhM8GgEqeGaanRyoff1uJ0dId2intOqio3pfWwFvO2zQ0ITgwZ8A1BzuyBQqmpPxJM8vGBhYXfEL14bCHXKzQHXoegJ/EBt12yCilYgJr6wLKm6SDXtMhZqj0mUJ5JiL5wnfHZzqZfkvbHpITzXZaT/2dE@I6i4LUUEik/RG7kMqEtNyME94r13BCu1HFicaVsL3wW7gXgkN2iXMnAbNouaZNVhAQQhi1NG81ygcwTumsuMOtltE1JSJ3ukuRbCDEgc3LYoTElKnhNqo8WuxNc75Ft4CGQoHsFCv5ieoQcKGHhQF9by0MUEm@NsCXhEYWG/Lqsz6c1qyx5DQwBDJVK0MzrYc24F9jVgLyRIRObQJxN/2kgT7hRkG3DKg6IlrEp4dIXJhzL4/dnAiEj/toadhr96a2BQA8Rc1vsTZ@Y5WQXYxAuRzSPFSc0H0R67p5Md5iF0O1oIKKNJazrVheZuWxKEjMNOE5tEkOaWYEMuSyTQwPYwyXy7sQhLIFSC8QW0AKgAEEmTuzwlXFcS@YeMnc3gxCCXfb6FW1CMsV9ZAqkIwOklvwdwOzUA1EJNmQlCOAQZD2uQfQH2BTAT82@OnJ947JBBJhU4CKw0rLaWXnKUthG7oc2P4VFKWUbSJaQXLay1trKL9yIDj8YR13NsNsPj2ISoXuuX6RVEavhNJwv8MUu7br9HgbUTd5QZpvbSqMgXujOn4yM4jN8zZH8d53bSJlFKbv6zBWs78fP7TwQCHQx4nUCc@EGSBimfwDUzTCCRArbOTj9VfR0q8KnZJKsLKnHwMKk4eMJ8T4EljSdAThq/pb7uHeGS/OjbqtpBeYJZA5Xwpghi2ww2nbrhZ4VyhNYVUTVoFiQOCxnYLTQOBjESlIbZWfSyiDarfT5r47Gu8DrgTxHnWzoUuMJjR@/IX@AtBPZgFtyWw54RUkrJsHlcgjrcVSzznTY3C65HVpSUXsDmXrxreDHTREzbBs4ExUWta@ibgo8nhU94pZOtVbEB1OsxvYzYoOIoASx3Dz0JB@Tle6E0lW2OhfZJ80h4LERutQ629ZwW2m0/xY66VHnkClm3doilmp0I4Rv6BEKo8YdOkOodSwoL2YRJp5CbZYow5oKwsqn1sME2Pg9dhKZAM2Q8Pp1Euepcyt6arB/u9yZayl7mpBIeHCkLqzllWTZpx6TGqcLX5XywUql2ddo@b4zCsoJKtkuoQOn2MpiNiHh0hhqYL6yobfC@pa9XLXfijuhLElWsWLl0xfyRMKHk2xoCtKAkQZqpIZkhDEGl2yteUQvbWDBws0cATt0LfHXzSFK4k@eWAIjKTpKl2KdwBa9gKLB7S4@SbJVoatqAltp6E@7wi8Nh29U45OTrt9ZVOMLSyMcQZGFWl8bfPGEiIgdApv5gkG1ZN/HvE75mvb/xKMjy1TVL6PBKy7eBlGM84x43UtANc92wr1lOAtwN/xcXblglSXyQT1@DP2x4mmESs5cdbabcB2ObALXBHpQvFSh7GHldeNWvHIPkvilFmzLRy@hIdIN2QsveU42boyfGdyn0yVugZ4AgvOIBD@Zasw/CULAAHpUUF7MCEMxOUzsyP4DYh5RmgC0pFv7kfmryc9eDg4ROkGJqPuzWbOcD4laEUDo1UeyqFuinmHbAMgS9sY1eSwiJv6sDkbmGDLBZkLMD1PH73j4S9TgpISV4OlItf5JVR1wBup@YSMNqP8klQpzCXG/L6sGtQ9H3prejDO2oJv7DXSNjiplBwkCijpnpJsExgA5DoDkvx6BMaBp4lknYksAQuMkdutE13AZM7VeYBcbjiMr@vKKa7@@Rx0Oikm5EgspeoBfACTqVS4g/wt7AIAikPNQNkrHENz0wG8u6EFbbp2mmP6FkAWCJFZ5GVdhPS7@@xLSa39JJlOjWByFGSNEwAoko91HvPXk07BuivBiCm4i9hC5pzQnhIRvlA7pFfSxlgTgKhlxYI/BuwSEOrGBIXvS2hG@oKWdlYmxo@NlHbNoLAzv51ZIljAKRLW7fgzpsNqKltoJk8ifDKQYHIRARDzRRcjtPuVpBqZDn3JdqbdvlG@QI/UQw8ldcarL4WEgTghyw00SEiH0fczg3B4gAqZsotYscb2Jbz0juDZ4OJpK2Ds32D@j8FGrAgoypgM8F7JWgqgjqcaGXEzHLnFNdRO6GNNhKkhp3d9keGYjM8jGQK5sarURbeezw8p9g4WYS9ATQmAa4KDFXgAcg4ZvEo9jyJL/pg2wfFLIQmxLXIaM3zATEWyQVk/dDL8Hm78OQBpltquwJfMIvA2LLCDf76Bnma5pKESGxIB8mNAnkxfJrnHySLMgrsr3wplvUgCmHK8pQR2Umxhi0mlgJm5MD0kNcAXdl/RAkIHbZ5Gmk9MRlRyVuAAPRvDbjXFBSTbMXG8bp8ck33D5R1cfZWJYTAg4SqgjnCQknVAFsKexHyirgvJet4cT1JIsKWyf9Xlry7zTGhn/BcoJab1QNwnbXwAo0k3nUhE15QWgXT@aLNgJg5yVwkeseGDWWOIx8tSceM4KyRKMiJoz/Q1LkfsS5l49CQQX9rEFBaVaBPgR4ASWPddRoiCURDrT5kqgBB7hZG4ws9Ov3XNiST4Yc5iHtzlOkPQZ@u0vnWHYA5CC1RBKe0Axg4/s0nY7Po@CtFxsDrB70tuyYqdvyWBoExwhlUZ/bpLQwK9Omtyg6chpSKR3yZbRZoYiPdPihsegGcIRQQ9oTHhTjCGklSDmAl@JmpTFl04DatEYbJD@wTxyfAz5ZUB9RvvrqMtzk8@v@H6sfdQmCCrAn@RDsTrsb2D4UFdOYmUOKCFGzZU2HvQxA3oeC/IRcsTNbeBkSIaBPG9IjKKgPWPYmz1dilJj/skiD0JvOFZhBFDu@04Hvjn7Q0mZTsSJ06bODrxzkUByJAzDZN8VmEArBoWHXTOyAQ8EI4opU22cLKxLveJbIblokPTaJ7aDDX5HWqyXoLiRtrXSwwwoj8v7R1NeCBuq@CE1TvIExSOHsgv/uO9b8vzJG2iu9VhClaYK64KqjErh2Cj5qyVH4VSEHId8zKQF@NIQhAQNgsIy/H/FzdFuBgJlwT5Nj6dU@ImwMZx4FVoQGXsv6xNEBN6fGmKwE@eNHMkDgO0udRO0G5uEDbEhEAMEUc1fjdUXBYsbN44oAxDlggInxAMtJmwU669r188CQTpcRmDeafUixc/mWm4nYGOg/cKcGSVlQQKMAtlPujVdt4nCcy9ltjkXrGzeJqQcVr9lGVwFgxdJemfI9WOyazhAp0hgG8VEzCHLCrU5USlTgoDVes1EQzIWYJEdaEqjaXpxpacxBFlFgjbK3iDtBZzpdY2nh7nwsMywo7CyC9dQN2NEV2owtdJ6IyxRiRQIE95TEJduXJsDA@Uh3cRNDawTgKY3SMFWRPTTEsS2thRE4aRjHAx5yuk9ILIA3jZcIZA9Y3Qi5RFljhKLI1MP1R3zySSsozrYkg2zODnfP@m6uA5DVIu1G1vQRukzUEROMrWxAnCtwjIeMcwNrBWCZNS3cdd9EAu712BYGd@@EMB4SGcMIrWPDMKQvkXWsgW3WgGU3rSGn0McussC0OhhH@iK@AsW2LIn1e8ynoXTCF3AhHGwYGzxxReySplZZfGnZBPSELhDMHy5@w2TrnxUGBJ6RhRjCJV8waFmzj0U5tCDHisBj2DLuqNtk0FrSr9AQ6jPB91okRj3IZygBzAfo4mF9FuVda1ov0VOdTYyNHKSVHtiWgHcBc@LMQpkHKhKhF0f0c5phncPo2CJShr03KAmj9hhKgmmSBn1AyIyqzgZiH7GNpIHmbEmKL90ZkaTP8kPghxL@9anb3puB5WHATTGMT4XFmSwdDfZwGjBX4XiHOgD@0KSBkK6UYUPkQQHNwugjqDNAYGY7EK@yVSa59mA7iZwN7WuAZLWBYDejSZOtuHHr8W8JE2L70UgATJzsiw9kd2JZm/F2OmX2KTsdICGY3a2OMg1Nw1oLbIjAdQ0EYvmYhU0@JFkucWBgS6EB8ivdEYRVBFWk2cBPY7nwyEi6bKv8pvQGqBSN26VI3/Ft5S6xONn2UJjwmGrC@Qiv4S9Ce0Kk3IZY7JYH5Yrqt4iGWvDuNmMO6fBFnyKb0Hasc0qicaG27BUSV4GVxvOwMYqEQUOEKIbpMMshppF293DT2KyATuNEESj@eSz5oDZnsXGwn5BWnPqEvkp9WooAkAcpD6xn29pR6rObC7T/X7/7L3/327/@4z//2//5@@d/@3d//ff/8N/@W47/Nw)

Comment: I have added larger test cases. Sorry about that, I guess I shouldn't have underestimated C/C++ :p

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Words of wisdom

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (Node), Unknown time due to TIO not liking 2.6 million characters as the input.

If you want to see the previous tests, then [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tb3J0jZLcpy3x1UccdUwSFBl5WxNLnUVNC4gsEG2DDwN9SAtZLx2KJ4I9/oOzBon//rqrSErhxjcPf6vf/p//ukv//znP/7bX/@3X//0X//w7//8p1//8tdf/vjrv/3tr3/55T/98p9/eX79X39p8b8R/7u0V/y/d8b/67QGxxZ/PJzVnjz/zfYYeX7@6ubP8nfvzPbheH9HXinvkL8dI9uH4/PlnLk5f@VvV7Z3Ht95zsnzb/72rnqGvGh78g6t5e1a3bu9@SCt11ONesRZz7vq4Ve9yc63amfU8@fbvk@9QateeB/@9vaHM9/xtHy7vMq76l@7/nbqzJu/63WV3vKa0QXZEz3v10fevdez9J1P1k8@Z7/51OPJdxj1RqPn@42RbztWvvvY1aPVLfPJPpqtOrVXr47syln9Onf96@bf1pNnxrVaft28ypp5zbXzDuvk/fYz64PkVXbPJ9szn3PvfOp98x1ODY3z5vudUWNm5bufkz1xq1/i/PzXyD67K3vwnkfjqz7S8@rf46mPvfLs@Oj549bqWq29vf496ju2VZ@1nfrKr0dsrzHwzhoS764R8l4NGI2fPqYGUI2ufmuwjbY05ut68X7173NqiLXs2TZ7dnRTv7d56t9Lf1@9zl/6/apP2Lauv0fdb@v@@9bzHD1fDNf6t57/PvU@V@93NchvvX/0YvbH@1T/vM@ugd480nsN9Vb9@3LBHPrV/6@H@1vf5@2t/t6H5sau3w9db/S6/qgvH2O/7j9rXMTaUNebNWreGIP591Vj6o3Xzt9rxL171mqyazy@0Q814Wq0xipT17s1lt87s3/js2Z/x1TcNSXre/Tn1r9bzZJ4@zy/vzWHYrLWxHxrhvXeagXrNf96P/k8XbMzhsutf9fc7bPXVJ6a2avGX0x@zftTy8DWqrBXLRJHa0Ysd/XvWlFi@D1aGh6tobWKPkP/Pvn30WqtYpjW4lHXi9FUy/hb69zob94/jubzxGqsVbnWyBgl@fxj1go65q7FaGk1WquWo12r79hTC1KtzbGu1/VOrdvjvtm/49aaPp9WC5G@x2xP/btpL4iBWztD7RNxtJa4XnvI7CfvN0ftL7HK5fPMWc8Xo@XWslf70ox5lufv2rNir6nrnSfff8bnzL/HsM/z78z@irNqP3pm9iefMVfONp9aOp/s/6X5sbr@3fX3ofOHfj91vanrr7of3Znn73qepeeLr5PPy3DJv996n3i7WoIfrchPvX@8Xq3Xrfpnv9VfW/23e/VnrODZv3tUf@9Z/b@1XsWor38v7cG7vt/e9T23vu8@9b1jecr7nafGw3lqfBztx6fV@Dlvjafz1vg6vcbb0fiL/aL2jVnj88war/H62V9nV//Fspf9eU6N93Nq/J9b8@Fqftyn5sttNX9uq/nEMpGbj/bo2PZraxo1H@@o@Xlnzder@XtXzee7a37fXfP9npr/sdzU9W6tD/GrWjDa05rMlbY/80V7XK9FJxq1CsXaWstSNGqdao83kpgwOrKuztlTvzqvrqPVsD23lke2ybp7/E3mUqsVNR7r9RZaa25rvRbh2ExrVY5GLdMYWXXltmohj8bVTruXtt7TtRdfb863dgc@Qm3fYVnVfv42bfjeYdihdaRfnTO06b@z6zpLV35X7WOxj2vjj8eq53mPt37vhf3R5sjmNaqh7RPjrPb7zwDo2nH7sAkwtSfHlKpe7d61Y/munu9H@3q/2uhjotX3GlrqwoSQbTBenROLWP0qBrnMic@@mDY4pi2QpecZWzbKsFEQQ63eglFTZsgjO2c2vfu0JRQ7cfVPrETVY3Fq9WGsol3Wi/p5LtlbLJx1zpFFFs/12KyWYf3om0Y/1Tmxuz8ye8roi2@kK8eGWPdiBbwyiep5Yq7VEy4ZldHQOFy3jM6GYVoGUiujtG2P593LaI2GxvweW1bV1LzYMnpbLHDV8/uUURwNza99y2iOkaoveNrQkVfz9PQyuhu90mSg1ZXP1Hw/q4z2sNm0JoQ9LKtOy0bMmDL6o3Fl2LUjy@7dMu26bbtRi1Njs6pz1is3ZpfTEduo@vmeckpaLE1lsj2PnJawDcuoe2zlPV1OTixEOmfKCXqWnKJHS3E07DSdI@PyllMVQ62WcxypunLM4TL4Yl6VxcegL5NzltMWI0RGX3zUsvqi64/N0rL74jXK8IubyTJttTXF5y@P8Q2jNL9OLH3lT8Zl6wu@YWfqyJ465wz96tYWibtXV8aBqyNv@bFvrBL1PGH/1RN2GR7st/UWWMR1zikP@WVNaPIg68qj1Xb/hp1WPUZ/l8E8HlnQ0yZ1fKU6ssuoeEdst/Wr@3xOqezq5iOvzpldv5pD15m@ckzzutfcunvYRbLXr55w@Znj@9tk13utrjeNxavefbk3YshX/zCXZdirD9dVr273827q@ZiL9S1219eJpa6@lw2U2AT1TffWV95H331fjYTjsXGaRsvpGj8xT@VITI2x41F3tsYh7mqdczVW76PRez2e76sRfrvGfJgO1Yd3al5cz5R7NHfCTCiz/nlqfvWn1YzrnoOxWS0dGVvnTDkDz3KAwe7CcxVkwKooh6Yp0BDbZ7kczcGGWL3KKWERr3OW3BbMo7qOVqTYjGuNioVbrs/71joWs0HO0au1LpwKu0@7yZ86crCiX8rj@lyw2Hx15JWTFqtO/So@e12na33ufU85YmfLE7u1qvfRns8XkzPWu7yxUbtDuGe1X8RmXjsI8Ze6Mq5JHgmLvXosttzqw9giq1endqseO2P1fGxW9S3YEOtXp3a97n0whverI2/tlRiZ9SvcwLzO0g7b1649FxOw7h7fRD7iUzs1USKFi3rt5j3mRb3XnrXjxycpG6BvWQV937ITwrcsyyEWpLIlwlop64LAU10ZP6iOrLJJYu8sK6WfW3ZLmGX6grcdHek6546yfzCe6jpXNlJ8Lt3r3rKj4o71PDHyy9aKJU/uJWGKOqL3GmxW9atT7054rHzMpv4J57dsv8HmUm7wKPswrH05wmENlGcc@7Fc5Vt2JuZYOdO2RUes3Toym87Rdx@x7sjDlpUbK3fZvaNr/GDEy8seNcYI4tWVu8bhwJGtc26N1cHKVKE@jecRP1Pwb9SYH/jh@auheUFcsK4ci3q53LOVX4CL95YTP8p3GFOrKNNDRzRPiWPUr8Ljqess@Sljab6PNcuXCVPU4chd/g7Tq64chlm9xW4KZ8agrTfdWn@IXtaV9641auxTflfsbLWOMU@qV49ctVhey3cbR@vhiCWhvk78@nFAtK58ta4yy@ucGH31K3yjCm1rfR6xbyjYfWsNn08rPzQ6tdZ5YqwKts7aC2asxhVbeLRfzOeWtzub3N/or/KHZ9O@MzGy81esvQ7b1pWb9q@4/qsoyKuwSXzaipPYkpmxferIUejkvYqddO2nRIIVPRkOn0zFT7r25Rnraj3hUEhhjqYYytD@HkuNoigxOOrdh@MoQ3ZC2BSKpIThUX0YN@sVm5G9EaOvoiEzPuBT59yKl8wlu2U6osJCqyPT58j@CadE19kK08zddK8tO2riJA1FfOoJt595yx5LYyfPOa/elC@5Ki6k3jhL/XOOeuxc9eGVfUhUva6MvVBHpr7FlZ05Y7HZiiwp1fG8TUdkr66wMiowHwtkheYfjY1Ysmq0hBVW42eFW3sqJDVqjC3bzys22FtHbo3MFUO/4kiv7HBi/3Xld9YIXzHWKhb1yp5f0ZcVreoKJy7CcHVEfkFM0ppfBLYfpxPqykP@xRr9VVRsHIXFVs3lNWTJxMpZ8z3XmDwnOqOeZ8rfWVPrRhjxtZKsMLXqvZb8JgzPevelEO1as9aoMBxr1VphRr2Kuu0v6VFX3vLj@Or1LfauFTKWulozl/3BFTutjnQlVs6stXcd@ZXkUerKYUPWvWKlrLtf@afrzlrnY1HWM2PjVJxPfi4Bv0q3PL12EDzgisU98peJyWaP7fC/RoUD39qbwsSufo6JUvvXDq/4qXNu7XGxmNaut70PbvyTOjKvzlEcIEZs7ae7K5UQ3VR7LiGyujuDJX8VRslR@FHPPBSX2Dg@FZEcteNvUgd5Hcc3dqzLFeWcrSyHHStaxTmn4iTkpOrKMWMrVBnzqmKXS/GWHWNU0c0v3Lm7jihuszG6KuL56jpbNtLeiv@E51F2FNOsnidcvXrCI0smXJKyx3YsIPVe50wlzBSPInNWV2YkKJxatt@@imvtcBkqAvqon2PClA0Z866@BctYRUGfU9/rOI8WjsfRkV726mmzvvtpu2za43hd/Ljs3uh3Je7eoUTeq7gf@T0l@q4Sf2HPK6ar@OGJhb@ivl3jOeZH2eq4XxUoHm/Z8wdb3SlDxYIVzzwxCisHHFtjfp0T@1Z@r2NL5sRCryO35umJJbJ@tRRfJQtZV8Z3rCOnfJmzFaeN@Vr@ztlaNw4jvY4o2HtwMPNX2XdKbNaVjwLG5@zyv@I1ax07t5WPdhx0Drey/LiYrrUexpZSvl48pwLX9gdJ8OnI6jpHwe9LcHkpyl3h59bL97xNAfSLs1UR8FvrPOnXuvKrIPwlKZrnMIMrTH7LF8bAV6C8l798w1/KHguvoHzqGLy1N5HRrSuTbqojo3zzO5RQIMCe3@s6BXTDptERJSXwIepX@KlNSWLF4ZXYuGwqeU6s@PU8sRzXEzo5EqtpxSViMtX@Hgt4U/xeCRbyznVlRn8dGRUDuUdJmliMK04Se7j6mdhnHVGi57KwjcoAPD@pbIXjn/c7Nh4ltONDK6XNsluh/abrR@utWzYCBEOZhFUPFi2lrzJN7oT5K1gGfkCFDsN4FTzjyVCIkg6KOabTpWNKp5GJ6EpXhJO4vhS87jGUliOOPpyyWNM5izOdtHDENCya5WNj67ww5PTbqTRhpvd1j/Ua5kHSTMl/pRtJfgjv8WxDPh42aB1T2jJaW9iPhxRVM3RA9zhKf0ZrCgfyEEUSxOBe9f19/T3uaPpGd736bvfUhGz5WZ1vUTqDjvGxtZ8vCfMoC/MoLBuLg7MlBOt1TOnhaF2FeBtxmGbIg@7xKs0cra1wcSIa6rdhdTmxM5zrie@r9E9sjsoIkaFQukdp74RT6B5EoXTsKtidWQWBb7pC4s0rcrT29jGl4UkbKbweFoEi7gT8nVQ6zldhzCit9DpjtacC@kTrdY/YMvVusaEt55@UHGhnOm91nEJgk1P/3VeJhnaHc1exejh55exVTK3X6avu/BVGV6WZnu0M1gdaiRnoHBZAESW6lrNYPIywSoavvMSWjV9yJosYZ/32vc5l9R8gyzCUpS@DWbrhIORbql/e4YzWG/6/MFLDsJIYXkor4Q@sDxqje0zDU96YofXdMv5bvw0vYCsd528es1zprvBLfV5sqfrtNlwG2I3uEV6Y7nuaEmyE3fR88QX1zOd80K5HybrYnT74zlRK773b/XJ/En@GAWEJVJ92fL7K0D1HScT@wYl660o1st3Vdwv7RglJ3KD6vv1LW3ai8Tq2m88TuImrKQVKkNMZxqVEae8CSDXGl54vvpueeTjpGnNM47mzJNZ5hAKcn1QCF9SJ7hHdZyBT0zzqeERKZArslTAnpzKb5mXfXYnlvgUYa0QV6/v2LxvWwwT0MYHOGgPRidBH6wYQKt3jCrgWra20OGFB5TXjaymx@Xi9iqVpKrWJc1PnsZ4NZ1QFRWxyDaN1tE6G71IOZLQEwmukbbqSsM6QjRwc1RKQL1qzXNZoba3jw45ttAQGJF97dF5sb/ptjFJdb3r/IFyr@@JXXmd29XzLoETmiQFmS/sWeWi97/6AjeG3qF/2cl@Fq@HEsMGRA6BF/RakwgdZ0z3ClFTeOYxnpaLv1D497mkCszlmEa3@@NjUvj@ffQ2Ce2QfAIdTupnIjI7tCpw0uqWejwhXPXMMZ73HZHLXsZjAymeDW6rf9ik7B6id7hHvo5w2H1hJ7Sm7CYyQ0trT9lU8@1Rim4PKfu@p1Dah/GYYn@4R1oiPfeeFe67f7u96e/oe@7sv@Tplz7/nC@9Gz3y@97iP3@1@73un@@C6X0AnKYv@uP8yeFR59Mf9vLDnmuGHSqWT7tcxf7dFmrd@@/r7LkcaE/GhY/FHwxg9XhaLRTO0UfdgNatjw@NvhTmk5xsep8R6dI/p8byYoHXe9Lhf64PwfvNjxf8JJbA8j9Y2nHdtz7e1txEH2/OSwI1wCcfzd4Xj93yQTN3jCuYbLa8HK1yH@u1@vG7sxzYcQZmuY0drTuwKWodi@mpt2t96FY@sNWy/Xtdi49Rat1@vf9HxH77B6ySRFiEcutfT3e/@gZLqHkMQYZAQWp9jmGrNJkJZ33d/NtyeXu/xgnXe8r6w1zJq4ts/Njn7Ora9z4QZaATG9n5Eekr3ON639tlGc1zvbxsftBkCq3tcwYsb8WPht2OIVz/HxqR9lfyvERvef0nG13c7zfv0aYYdn28/P2TOdcz7ftj5sgVOt32A5697dNsRZxiGnLkKAUOWbBCgu4aGGI58pu2XQ3y6frts55xlGy5mjIHA68hGOtt209mGJ5/Pvjox2oVIObbDzjFM@Rzba@d@6JZruw5/Xudd238XJHEz5FhAlMew5fvYnrzt1fPdZrvzfvBl8t8CupBFrvNe27HxyQ1j/uzdG1NGaJduu/gOwZmjZfs5THkjXobtbJbO@m532h5ne3s@qLTusQRvjpbte9JhjzE18gPutg0XE0b@AikfPcuxX3GP4M4Jw9Y9oov0btd@yr2CPUdL/szL0i58zSO/B8SO4M/h7Zd/FK0uCDQfRvCdZhh0XKT8rZd8WuEknld@Wbgz@ubRkv/2pudf53X5ebHiCRad8HHdY@yt@075jdESPBr3qOuZ5/V7LPmhYF1qXYuW/FXgRLX@JTRd99iCSxfGqM4D@V2/PfKTAR4Zi3TlT0erG@d0l4FOV/Dp9/PPXwISPiY//g13W2in1uTvv7ikJoUoLoCbJ6wHHrggT@8x5ql/oKc@PtTT/mBPj3FPoxv4ND7k07iGPsUyJOzTnAY/TcGsE66ve7Dt6pjiKiSzhI1hA6nv2z4ETSy3AtXgO@u8o3jOy2Ki610DdGLqCbMT06J/QCwhexhsU3wZ43@IpYkS1JpQQvFyAg4B8HqbaQaCcYXlcXRMca5oCZaNmyyo0tuNXsokfR0bgmeTIxHsKdFSH4VB95j9O7Z83rz@7Xp9vfXdYx3fl02jztvDz7e3n/l873G63@0sv@@57oP7ul/u11f3GEz2NOPLnmHIGdPio158wDRj1ZpCpdG6@pbsGfV9@4d7C2tN4wCPVOd1BWejJXh30jp0j9E11uI0jb8@BfOOlsLBRM2NgJsKGseKLLh3hSjqt@toLgCQ0z22YN/RUpiaj6q51Y@C2YQ39D3Cq9S8jL@ZnnUVGH/xJZ9mOoqgdkRsdExB9hgugoMTKdW6EX6j8XavAvbREiw8/quwfgL1hN3rXq9GFzw8WkoRxEB8tdaNoURCtLwmxrqgdXLMqbVzTCUlYhsRVjxpNLoHedY6tpXgiJbw4i9Iivq@w/55tJQsiZYw4wnY0m@j/3S96/0j82zCEyo9E62pvWc@SuK809jxF@/u6tgRhSc@c@1v0RJ@POk/Aij2ZipQV3LpxZMbxigeQRKHKUUEjj/gomhH0CgEbwx/@vmoRbrHEpY8A1k6L3wn/XYrgcY08T220mwvAAljIZWMyyCYntkpuxemiN7tKrGHs7CFiHyU/ovWMSayKUn4riZs@YsPJlgkWNmPEiXI5St8@RsjvOywaI2yzaKl5CXYJH3z8LeOj22fN5UIjVb39ZwufRfo0jq2lFR907eq3y6lXgHc@z22ErTRun7fozRutJb6BSqX7nGFOX/BvCzBQK/6Oea2SGn78ffYj9LLsey@@m67KQkdLWHP3y9VHa15fEwJ7bis8OcASkVUC//I9xhKjr@JFRHeVCl08MEap3hFuscUDv0l6FLvu9fUuE9nR9BUz4@9pwlsYcId4VUFAIiW8OhJb9M97qt5icv0AVs1f2ONKr8sWl7bwUjrWBMu/SUoXr8luytU7Ct/MFrCpkdLUAjwmlqHThdg4gXWoHsMwSqiNbWuxTJd/ioIJK1/xxANArhaJ2NVK//3TSR8/XYJ7vGG7/QYfytQyEuitb7bOYKORGtpHT/2z6NlvHpmUgXVfbQv3EdglWh9SNwmSEu0uvG6TcCX2JyNW7@GxxBqNva3C0QTLWPXw5SvuMV7h2IZ4MgrvgEkWPvlnYLtRGtoXyW7qXssY9jvEgQoWkf7NGnMLUCxv3l4HY@O4bDWeUego2gZy34NTSIoLjsifI2KD4FCFk37eQRz6sAMhC1uAkNFS5j2@FSCTIGnLjsnKZaGLgvXHi3Br6J1ym4iylrxsGhN45eHoFwdooFQzlOAr2gJ357@iu4Rw8DHrs/b3b/da34Qad/jdN/3bD/Lffx8YTLoma/fI0lbhZR@BH3LNxNWugkg18FiierdBKMjX64@ba/AdoBkq@@Tdqp7xFI8dEzAvZ5h5yuo9iOiqnOp0RIIsBNaNH1VUMEyBJsprbrHFv69E9rRs8TI0fMdgROjtfweRxDGnjZ/nXcFdOy4pNUvr@GQHWet@i82sJpHCRmvfsaxEAv@VSw8s85Nx4yHx0B9BC5fQsS/jrd3DCwfE@QzTNtHqHhMBV1vGhdP4lv3XVPI@NiQRL5NokEzzdeE3yt0fCx7IvHmMiUUu2CtpHaMkL8Cv3ZQ/KIHP9OE4ef8hkIsMHszTr43wW17h1RSv30Fyu2/wcp3QXejtT@0vAC@HfdS1zMMuGdeqI5NgYWjZcw86V8981KuqPct4HEHVl7vS76n@iBB483UZ93jGDsP7m0Jlr@Eno@XrX21AxwQMv8RbDoevglBP5rA1dEyhv6DYEdrvT4moHZPi7t@2wXnxhHyPYZA30RFhaXH/5buQmym9cxsYLrHMp5@LMHMe068@u0WGB0/yQyDI8h6tKZQ9dH1ZTf1cY2rHx/8ndzJMM9AIHki//UtZzOUfloyIFoG3IeT4PNew/Jn/67XDd6f3Rj7WCIE8Sf2Vs8XG46IAGE1v@YzmC4Q31TvGwuiSAVzCWufNHbdY7v/CEKIMHGEt4@WaQzz@nukAaBjx/yH56NEPP6@q/0QJ7q5FM30CthG@u1rEsYy9p6Ylagaq3v8YfHX88UKq3G6PtrHmh7PYbiJHJLB1frtMoVkffNjbRNNAJBWn5LulrTJ8XyDq617XGHxo2VqS8xtzd/9mACzbcNFyzSZ3bwe7GYyDR9hNMsGWDnE60tYuSLm4KPW8@1h@s4eXq/2MMlnT2Hzo2Uq0J5e/5Ak0D2W8Plh5ZhWtLfX07B8RD7axuhHyxQltpn6bvuayLSvcPopdyDiyeP1/jSTogAEPGKsiDrVz7d/RIdfiSa8wuv300XDipb3I6QUdI8hzD4mX8UjSFlrfztTxK9@lmy4aIkeFi3vl2mp1m@3sPsp06B7HO@/54iQxjK5zaERbY20uFk0j8ht0RKGH6bgEJGm2T5AAkJUmlc4/miJTkcYRPbG7SLd9Wssf8cOvDpm@wU81DBZR3bONc2vEww4OiYyYL9bmH5ySxUP6/ezrwDMNR0Trr8DkJNwxZW9Nj483EgUnI6JyjhAvD1iBYnwOIDNiRf0ihYZLdmTkIbq@fhTPXPKYlggQ/bpIF4jCtEUzp@gUBPRaD3mHi2ROqMlrH9sW6J@RmtZxujoezC1JWf0HNFIY62SPU4OtL4vppJ4N9iTPib7fhR4q1rC/aech0hOr/wF3P4af6N1Yf8BQNQ4Hc3@xwB2cHVM@H8s7xr3gwR19UvStOseSxwAYJJbVKot/2iQvBOZ6lhWpB3RgQe4KvOpRBoe7YoLMD5qMURXcXRiMdsmXokPEC3RlAdxYEmXvCIzD7bBehYCj/V8b5d/mRInuscQLwDeVq1r0ZK/GgbFY2UlcwMGgYvqv7QJxfASYRuIiJhPr2ndACXFjwIBX98tsUfF/HpEER/da/vAsdCxJp7AgHBZv8UwrusBcRBJrIsrMIjR1rP0rvjB6EME98EfLRIlGjyUMfHJYtvdopitbtaZKfUDaLa4aVvE@5GLcf32iJ4frY/ndkXij5a4AyMnaxHSHsVfUlLGUl/iD4zRJBvAbiT@HZ1f1xvmEMB4KzsiWooPDTL59XygiSVbYzkD0OPiBY4l0QPCimIPEmcTqc7xq0Gs1Jpa4hMM0DEi1l3Fw1IKR/e44hTgtx6R6x7F10bYcF1kuvbx65rkH9JC13mvRCJGolmaZXZE3xuK/4HWE1GSUEE9X1huokrGhv2awyfximiJYxAbiiQuoqX4ZEr46B5HPIOBLVd9ynsPMwBFmlzmGtClok0Sw67vtpoEOqIlvkHmr0QWfBWPDeNaYh/REucgWpIEwa32PYaEQ0ASa/wRn1yiGipenNJDuscS9yAWU0mVFBOxfnskaDIIoegeV7In0VI8m/yQyJSxHGm@bUuoALXSvNxNQivEoTV/9ys5lhhWXtt3l2hLtMRFIEAvWiXWl643TazcU3wEYHHNym7KBzCERa7c5iRE65heeV7zK882wfI2MywtXJNSAdV/cf@PZHk/lmU3zdL5D1g3Jlq@y0zL3ky17MqnpNST7jHEUYiWBHkGkED9dkq0J27v/eMsCfuMs5XviZbEfwbYBT2zBYKipfzRIBZa73uu@ApMWglVAWcQq7NJjIicqvbL2yRYNO6r/FZKVIk02l/LVvVt4aqhfFm0JI40Pu5CtCSgFC3l3yCyXf12ib@Q8le6x1Y@D3jd0bMccRgGLEE9s/OD0ZLo00zAUTFNHwlDzacp35jSWqKovuIyQF8VDZLYnLitXSJUZFPEn4xFQ5TKZygfOmPqi3jJ0v40y3bpHmv72G4@by//9jy@3jH7Mz6B73uHn@VagAvjv565PX4PonD1bgkWr/Ne5ZNney321cxpmEBlRbjtyk/PNiwaBhxSnNtPWKxN5bshkom02dayHNn@BMoce50wqnTsiNMwUXLRb6/y8UnnrXvEqBfX930kmAbHV4xgEvf1zFA4xO59JbwW26HwAtGSOFu0xGlImTTdYwh/MN8pkTeINeIz4yFW379LsfD5bonFAbisuTpJJtS3fI/wEdlTuscVp2GmkkURiR/hLaIl8brYMmTDTYSW6r5p59R5r0TwwgMTpyHl3UxVFh4kWhLTi/@I0zAJa1S/dONLYkxJlG@y1orVvCXcNzOz/EnH6R5HnIaJmyXS9F0WznwkEjiHbbhJkEnHmvA0hFpqX5iZJ26WpRMxugufMxl@Eq0b4jRM@PuiXc/XvOsp8UNo1lPM6yWBxBlb0zX3epp8fcRpmMRbq08zgVW/vRJjnMOchlitJNgYLeGb5mwSdZwgdOv7Tu/nk9SOjnWJQ7J8LP12SEAyWsv3mBKZjJY4DWTQmujhS3iulOrTPbY4DdGSoGWYOcKHEbcrO2dC8dM9roQxUaoqG4lAVtlN6dVW3y8LbMaHFH4tWhLhnFgo9S2BNkov1blUwmFdx@bj86YEPye4TF1vyU6cEIt13y3hULhOfr4jcdFoyYab5OUlWHiF/5vMT4kWPuI0pHyhyOtNeEJCc0sU91echsmwNxHe32MPiaYmJ76@Gwjm@pYkBp5PGlH3WOI0IMKxdN4WfnLCftX1zvA9jjReZwK26rwrFdjYPcRpSNlFCTA24TujJSXZtGzFw3@lNYs@hZn4XWq0AI41j86QXu1MPZ9P0lH3WOI0TJKH9d3OFp41WlbFPcZMTHicOnaFj42WlXVZCMXvf6y9ex/hbedtUueNljgNGNflX4KN0XvcLoXfmczJOm9IA5igqdY/dkvdY4rTEGNOOsLIdWg9DSOo/OQJNFn3ONIijpbwynCxyu@OljgNKXMpgYFH@Of4ixSPgTOI5Q@7sAj7z7stjdmlmrxSv7DOG9JVjpbw2SmhqXtMcRrWs6TNHC3hvVc6VHU9cxoI61R8I1rCj8cIlgJ0tKZVER7FSxakwiGlhKfiKmgmSGGhgTwsaQRjoxBSkAR16@I0LCgo@u0QXj6lP3WPKU4DEZQuOYYl/P1KwGBdb08rMsR8kiTDEZ5/AamtPgCoKlWG57EswyN@wGLmS5ihidMQ3fNUPCwdr7rHC7itjnVxGlLCRYKlY/5GstTSD9@x9Z23vt/u73r7u8f57nu@Z7nf810/c//eIzNidaz5fXtzH4DTuZKYcF/17v4jmVV92of7GatgfVKrusf0NwIVVN@N8H59S5aN@r7dNtwi0qFjx2MjvFqNl349hsY3rsbjsTaaxx8B5no@MGP1zOStpGjRPZ4JwNT7EhIZksLwXBjf/MCRr/5LV6POW55bKOpU3w9zGmKd9rxMMZw673r@jus5Pb95nkZ6k9BGrQcr931pbmjdYDRbsrZrfVlpQtV5Q@sQG6LVObxeRetYn2NpXVtp3NRvt9a/BepK9zhaJ5P0UX0aS2GtpysXrGbZ3LoHU76@UUzHWp/DVtKajQpIreOxulitI4bJ1rGhPWAlK6V@O7VXpCSv7rG0pwCIki46HBOpiGztR2uZ0xAt7VuQUqYUSa72Nyzv2vNS7leCI017Y5JXJAb8ag9FPa/21TAotNemaVHfCExxfbc9tE@vPbV3r28/j5b2eB556LwtW2ChfKnrneV7XNkRkGbKtiCsU/YGeYGyQVKm2ILFslXojLJfoiWbhnxi2TnRku0Tw1r2EFZ72UjrTNlN0ZItlRLIuseSzQVZ50ho5cg2i5bstfVxGqIlu24BHK3zEFI4ElWWTZjyypJpeWU7Rkv25LpdNma0ZHeua37tSuG/OjZls0ZLduxKoYJm6WbdY8sGXvBPqk8TRFi/vbKfSdFKW@V5ZGdHS7b3fprs8Z37dLMstERhXtny@@my7zc4QP12yA8AEON7TPkLKeFV6iOJ2K/f7scqM/sTnjmPtWjOsjzNbVasufJndjOnAW96SrC6yRcCzVr@EWo1Nd9SzrruAXe9dFhal7@FXmTNXyIP5Zftj38Ouvjq2JJPRyp16bdbvl9KZeseRz4iK2zTs1z5ktG18i9ZYPUeb5MfulOR9Eo1p/zVDWi7@uW1X4scUK2TGyhv9SlbXvUzgLzqe6CeuseSP73DGD5S3dnyuwlPreeT@NY9rnx28FDlx2d4sn7bm/z9aO1Ps0dxAdR7jlR7uuIHG36ydHscZyDIWfvWTmBBnbcUo4iW4hZJSNM9tuIb8RaKeWxUx6qfE0HySZNLHOhRDIWdQgLkSPrVtySnUN932IbbZBB0rCt2Q1jHYudDMZ6UPdc9pmJBeyzFhzYqdvV8aNVNiRBZah3Eh4SJrmJQLLsVl8JCKjtnT8evNoGp6r9ER9d5r2Jf0O4qHranOQ2bkEN9I/zp@m7hlld8LVqKue2Pl4pMlY/t7vP29W/P8PWsXbKhhtd9ifPXs6xHccKNiVzPvBxPDGtcMcadUM46rysWGS2L0q8hG25jZsxPaqn6dC2L06@lGGjKzOseW7FSmFX6bizfUm66FqrfzqVGy2L1uzXL1bdPsP5VLDcl7CXg1BXzjZbiwOSCNCbjw2mcbnMaWBY0npGKUtmTrfjzJhpf/bIdp94o41f/ITxSfYo6fvUzCbbq@2PNng27tr4RstL13c6rOPoGYvN80vsS3x@KwW8IfTpvKla/WYp1vXV8j604f7QU@9@krPV8VzmClPWXJNWjXAJIU61raGRVH9ymPARXU1/dV/mKfbtyGBvZlOpnFIB@SgboHlM5kQ04tb7bXcqdIIGldfzaPwdAovX@XuVioqX8DL6JlKMe53FiD7S@1PMq30OnSIUqfNjaj87zaVU9Q/kjEiZStHqm8kzRsu7V43zUwXMt9SewVMtSXNLQeo7yW4e4t@5xlQc7yUMrPa6mfBmQF6t2eT@P1qft1ZV/O@R89duhPN0BVKfSC1P5vIMOez0LOgOq5rSVC8wSDbrHUc7wpCZcnXeVWzxJJVzSCVNfvU15yQOvqfoU86/6@e3KaWb5B8mGDeU@DwSV@m7xg7LNgPaUvXY@bZEDDEDH9vZ5R3lY/uvrOV970hEubbJHed3Do9TzoVdWz9zfbn2yV3nik4TIOm8on3wACkrrzHnnaCkXfQp6Vi3lrE94mpJtA9akexzlu4HV67vlnlcyaI9y5efLnx@Anjr2Ks@ObprGy@jKx0fLCm7oUdR9Y1nT@AOJXc9HmtblmSzjNrawAdESXiDWBWEIYtUSruAMaxMeNCCq/2Ll1DyaTTiFWBCFXchSHnUPgv9SdOvHkm6jW9Nt3E/U7VN1W82ybkvYikNwU7/dwmBkmRDd4wqrwcIkcTfQhvV86xHOA06e3oNgS71bakbWeV24kWgJS5IlSCQfN4Q5Oens1nlL2BTE5ST0tsxpOIhG1jdKpYE67wr/gjtT63jy2@oepEN1rAlPg2evcif7Fe4mFvTXJVG68DnhFAmzc3LprN9OYXuydIrusYQBCrtXuKCTIJ/67RF@6LDg6x5XOCOk0FTqJVn2ksMTRinLskgQ7xWWCQqHSrnBlK9vGZ1c8Zdw2rS2R0t4qcMH0XlLuKoDLVXXM/4qWsJkIbbX9SxX2C02tYojnWtOAx@j4k0n/bw67xU@DDpJ2TlZTqbuQcqr@g8JiOrT3Lfqt0u4tHOtRXsyuFrHjjBtJ5Fx9dsr7Nv98HAp@qdjTbi5@zRh6ehkic1F10t/7unC4d3kaNd5Q3i9y5ZymsvguCCOsH4X36RE8J4tTGDqwJRUHh9V97jCE2b3HSkOCncYFrCwiFlip@4B/r/0@lIWqc7rwjbeuKmE/j5OA76i5ADbElaSjJxEA2Ohlo5gM84yWsJexv4vPOaFXF/PF4uPZApfazBfSND1bu/brW/4Xkse9mkVxPEJI45trcQpXOllZ6p@RpKj@p7UmO6xhVPFXZE6IwSk@pZg5Ov7fjL/0RIW9ibZo4QUX2FmCThcFSrqX6miLrztTdx/nTeFy42WsLpZ0kj3WML03r6F873g@asPErxa1zOngbFZ6@QFDll9GnOi1tNoCXOc5ZIk9diFTb6EFCT2OIRhZjusdfx@2uMJo9CxJUx0nCSc9E0F8OZSTLrHFcY6WsJdQ/2pvefOJnx2tLRHxVQVjhsHovaycLaE976Jkm8u81T3mFNYcdRGhopALWHKEY1QDUP2Ht3jCI9@Sf3Ud0Ojp74l6rPPV0LK5SuFeb8wM3TeK2x8mMDCyxPk0j3WEK7@rims/SXzuCR9KUx@lqdyoSph9wGflP0CF6FsGhy1K0lMa@5fsOcSzmziDKRyZvVzkmW/0ld1jyTA17EhXkLY4OIqREv8hfvp7MYGL55DtI7PO@JDQGbz9cybuJjmSwqd4lfc8z0f5mY9M6Zg3SPJCEsKnnrfM8TruOC9pfhp/kc4E@4/4tUS/dzijsSSLT7JPeY0XBBHEv58xEVB2ONK@vP7vtd2OyoJGgdMVp03PF5i4G9dz7UmCPp1yY1@4w/8UD0fNIJ65ms@zk1fqI5d8XYYcyLzoKwuhg9NS8TFViIuEE0RhBrpHan3PLl/tq@ambVM53S5sXDAXYLs8VRuJBJdquz5xOIALLmk2XO7y5yhzKEroAGq67b2lUhrXnKQRJ1fKbXevvJqfbvkWjPVIZpTfC2aInEhoCpmF00tjVWXzXc7IobRFFusPYkZu5Zblb7T87oISzSbGGgtkVeSB0W8X1qv7DvPT/E3K7YObQuMLvHfaF4LjOID@br7kyLFmvIznGHR0veKfUdzW960m6fXwH9ZCBVdf/VD95ZIU9y/xvj7RGKHWII0r2VYQRlbJ3Y1C7Z2Mw@j6a0bIVlxFGlui8D2KzZjqlp4lFDuw0db/4RlmxiSKNCuT4LWXEqa9xOrHWJdRnO@lrUdU/zM0qv13baYnDSPpXLHEeeT4FizqO4wOxR122H53dnEI6W5LdQ7XzFOo9k/Sd/ZxU3F5e8W/51DLNZozmWZ4B/duSeZ@jq653euTcsU0f2uey0@h@HnZ6Aum56MdLael7yy3mK937stm8BIyD/uhzW2ewcNAfXZWp@UMPkx9S/@msV69/W3WDbVq36h73avvyZJB33j3V5/@d2ux8P@BOkSFeOjdimiOabHGfFWX3d@YzJ1C3R0N4/fvY9HdUwsj/XP9aG5PS/OMzxbTns8h07bn8Tw@803RMMsMty35@axi4b08ON5fKZF6p7sJx3dj1cCZDX15c/pXjU@Jnyu715hAK7o3NiavBrBJ7KCsSkWNK/XM@hDejL0u/W81y5v1ZR0ecnlonSUXfCays6/LI38ev29X5G7WOylLIBi8mv54RjHzUUqm4vmZeFKKym/1xLEWKfSEX6Gi/AxZbW35CSSRDBAYB9dLuqXCShf4byWIn6sv4Aws4sE5kPoyZpDHS0raOotIHtbvPk9LqPZ@rQkMcEGaRKzY0mUuM2vnGZzSKZlfEq6xIBNLQB9XpfVbOcrrImMmfSjCctJVPp9pHzBqqXQUdX5tF7066KNpNquzx0KR9GU7gba0uursb2k0EHzutI23GlrUx8Xlcxior7bVdgMjWvpg9B0kcqWBZOkRu1QHE1pjjSkciUmhy6u1O4QwZXsXFYs1d1we/Q1@5biCU2FDFvW6NR4@EpZ0ZSKCrzk4XOztpQ0sZuLfGZZVKtiO7RJUxouqGa7aCgFPKV@14YpGw19V@nfIebqfojNZ7rgqkOwVXvVd7suaoph4xLnmEP6FpBa9YXmVyQV1VSXS58OFUdzSBOHceiiq@1Tz6G5PHYSRqhzj4u4toR3WOHbkng4z9bQXs9XFBagl56XOhwuHvt@utyrf0Vmo5@t4L0ceo/mnNb6Xuubb2tdq4KvPT03gRzoW5A8Wj@lanW37RQBwpCPNcnZ3fTl99utXv5RO2hu65yjLOpzZ7Mi@nYqo@rh@m7bRX@jeayyzte2tPl9rce@XUMYcar1fOrmr@XcUau0vvm7LPx@@qcGf8Zjifh0XayFPiwmD2lPX@hLDWFgD2vRn9MsUA@LVV@ejtR4uD/69ve5Fr2/bVkJ/zqFhXK9tLpo7q8k8JCqF2uY0mK5nG1rsi@JglX5YN/NqbbWEimhc6@ExmhKfYwImq1XVBJVL4AQqvb5NzGMUnF3SrBqFEubHHNQguXULZCKOflGSZtjz0jv/NmfCPpzpLyW2P7pc6802sDKSLitCiFbNb4pHQrdQbpvDRlB2VEvUtt6i@YUKyu8tORoSmAu5eZV/eFFKVaS6M36dDQlWhfNKyW71K1/LD//SPMOnfr5CdW/UsdrKcsnSfssRaArDInrtR/FPZr7O7rGd@5u3xX2@a57fu523@8Z7vWTIcOq5@1OrVfd6K@E9PYbI5NhdfzR3Dsp4FDX7fPryfR2dNQQgIY@qb8F/PL1U5zad7vbXxO6sb7xaM1ffjRXxHg/qEJ@YY8dmJQ@d7gqxjtm9@gbX10Matl6pI7tyhhhRL0e1bGmeKyP@82AlPmto3Bs1A@zuT4GIm2aWVlm2xUADP2gLIBrZLxzSviSpqtkvNOUEtQwXSfjBeHt8t3HlTKQTdOqkduU7pbkQh1trpYRVodgL5QccL0MwPtfEfDhihlZeVZPluFZXWFJSLQKhvtuR/Acmq6bgWGjlfZNu9vVDLwqQ5fRWk1lA63gb24SqnLQBSOqquSuczAlokrTFTTgGHeXSdiuocFc8CjZx1U03n0Fd2pgMrVnvUnia1/pc93tGEJFMQXX0oimBGTxxF1NA9kuvxvVk/TGZ1mUFm0u7ccEsbRLZ3113@1a6Da56ep1Mgf6FgTzu2s22FKAOO3KGteQtGiOr7YGl31@irjrbkQ5fXR/9TWoL@ornK/Cxgeda6lypXoLLHIu/tCsJkwW4SsT8ekOR9NixJ2YgaouPIb4tdSEVt2FZ9nCiz636nEHAnBcasL6yJi/LiPfPiXlFJVSuYTce1Wm/rUQM4UpZKf2n5LypA6Oj875nbus@JwVfn3dTxuaJOf3DNcq0tG0tHRHvldv8TZb5vFfK1P319BOLHdrWMdyaWFrCi64egUVBtW/5P7V61n2WVfYXyWO93zf7b1fLQ70yVxQ4/mqcfRmqe7@m3oc8TsX5Igec0WObqhsNOdPTY55f4py/FTl2JYU7yxAet5@LD7e@/2pzGFIb6MesWtzjGZBc5wWV@cYprLQ/Opz4DKo1yF@61sMQ49pfjU6KPagrwkRV994XEu0R/Or0zFNXmtUTHCljmmINM2vVkcyPVVg5FONB9/nch1zfvU65rLoPJqK8uf7B@WO5rFmfc9VRcVHHqvbI9ah9ZdQh@fbei2O31G7VK8vQ87Jc1lbv6/pCAZMNMU1kOzRftHXtl4/Aj3aW/qPsj@ZMe1DnRJwOhfMoq6Q0ml13W3KC6VRXFcgVkYXG4imKxDAMNC@SeLQ75bhJh3drmqAWI72YzL4ijGRNXJPnseVEhB40j7fWeL1LWKJl02Ac@vvFku87IcszKJvHBNru0jLckWHrP7qux3XfkDzYfrc6yoR1PAbLuny1ZPoaam50IsrT8Ta6XIUJBcVG@yEJ3W3O13NIoaIS1xgDinmiMCMbLl@vwoZ/Zpi0pK7rPopGIDDRWRcdSM1gF1Gprs@RxYzU6GWZ7iSx3hMhanFVfVRnv18R/fPuWd@V7jfdcm46G5ViEy1alyGJPVZluvWuGAJCi7LlWuGS5sMvHjXuFkughJN99n4qEUUvHH/phiLCr/gManyC/rsKv3yft9tsJir@Mv7@huP1xQodgWPhzBeveMM7DofXV@pGKRWfYXzFZV5fyrNvPcrPxM7q2vSoBCh50WEcLoKz1fSJmXvdHR8xW9Sck1XmF@ZnP5TOwdwu/qX4Ix6nXGvb4G4iL4QKkO6W5Yt0dH2U87n/anx039T@OenGtD4KRE0v7pBY33FhLKEmq67v7JDRDj8DPcrUFTUfjW/Ukbzp77RfL@iR7N/lZBm/8ojzfHVTCKp7QJE66uuNNdXcmlur@usGVrtUxPEVYhMeaTp/YLNSbsIkDLtLeOj2rSEVPvocBGpeC7vWSnr4et@@xuYIO16sel5L0S8QzvkQI5Yb0HdABc@at5jUxDnK5Hk/TirJanP9ldVi7JA2tFH1vrUuctFuah0IJtgfFTXliob@pr7utDXAASqL3@aS4KNn7oiWcfcR7ttmHFMyc3In@ydcZYLksGMkW00EMjVk6GLoec910XOxvkqn41r6nBWFJB9hvy4rLYYcbblomnrFaVA2X0DcLp6/S7biLhIshwxDvzdkumro9e2J0GA5hJRj@3U@Vgkh9iCbVrkKb5zu@3fCYlUBaWerzoda5GegRrssqvns13cDs0J2eDzMWUcXKzt9ZkJlTqX@KIqLaVrrlJVnx@AkIT6F5CjfAbKuOtbxNS0f5FyEb7bti8y23EJwNmu/ZaZNTrquj8VBNFOPz762h8CzaJxlnJCuu5r6g7Fs@xnsXFo/ELdl0@WbD69xfv5b2BjrotpPfb1Jrq2LrvV7BfO/nq@xTi1D0kdZs1NbEj5mzMVpHXdr8pjeE4u/TiTCaJzj4tEztj@5fP@SC@gemv/OFYzF56Mpn3pObpLVBIYdN2xMV3MEiqFfPQ5LBFBWTD783AY/W7j2vefpbyiwmGOE8DG0Po751eJE3EErdVEqxV/mEjX61vM6VhFLGD9K0O2HdeY4IldiOw4BjKnJTfa/ImXkIgbPtocW0HYQHvWXN1xmDA5vL@RU1LMBqil9sIwWB3fScC43mJ91VJn0jB09DpuFE/uYqsTDqP6bFvCJCnXikfN3V3AFQ0Cxa4QopNNgPaAvxsy6vqaezsmxtPK1sDTUPwMWRqPkvM41hYGikvSppi/rgBwUdc9X0XbeSwJQ0E2x/soIe4CdSkhpeuaCkTTccQJZcIF2h7HHOe1dA2l3ByfjKYL9xKjUixz5pqgK0zHPROkpLvd5Rhp4sv0jZMupStcFxheP1WHV4or6mhznDYVWFX8jESxKqJ9UkA0Hf9dWe1U5y7HivEj9BYgC1yP7TkqqUw4xjFoBqp6B4Ur9RkcIxd@I2SlanD4gCoRV6aW6tW9XxE7l4GmeX7K2Dm@joy6C9m161j8er9RQhXa5aNtuZgdxWJcCc8SUHAmPCZX@vA6Op07SKq8njfsX411MlvvVzjPOYn1WqqKVInzF6u37sJ23WW5aV6XtuvdeRGI7y5u16dzKGFAenbDc9ecX8g36xv349zMwujVePjqoxB1elzkDnynzh2W/qKEn/NDYX545Vope6ejU5Qiivw577TGVkl0cnleJ2MFEq2IpvNZsMWui/41574Q7v4pD@g8WezWKtlO0zk1ijBotYfI5u8WC492hhWrgvYLKObaRRYSiRoP69txwjZ1DnAtS77BJXW@cGVUwgUJvb/FOiqqEcUJnYdccL31vGs7Z7k@aToSmc5vxqldO@/azbnQaIpyxIj13k1Ha0dPHrgrIFpCD1/R@VjcRovnEiboA1C2qsR0SBQnQTDSll0V5TwuCpSSpsD5j2sIDuICr2ii5GfCzIo5JqjeSO39kcycqqSC/Hzs6JjsYi6lNHgzJhOJBlab@RrVtO5BNRCpCFFH9k6uftxcvt9GkoEyi@v9GCep65pUUckogKAFGWPk7wtfNzYYgRGxh@GNNMfgZpLXmUhSbouevcCtHxf6otLIzsn/m@KQ6LyM1@JtL4oKMwsxHs3ZsxtfDh6jJQA2@qH32kthl7gPIFZr8ccgO6nIvkXNnKnjP13FIN5kZuppNrHrUyg1PJGfMGAs2oT0ZlMw@6W@a6WKm8noFxrIM8SQAXO5OzbKUuJt8d2yYO@XnuPzgshQpxxgbjNNGJW5GtCNuzIJ6SkQ9ZcOOR93lMC2CHTIV2BdGF5F4HXd3h@RUt7UuAFMJFA6EYuNoE13NTUiQF99YbSan8T9Szhi5ldOpoJLU@JzzyS@qqxc9ALZ59dbO6hzOM5Abh9JOMGWG9DzVFkOnaqMxRrHGncGjNS@yledciboy3/pe8weuuT8VEXc6B08JhtQYYdiYMCEVFmSPH6Mse1ySzF8wiCHsqV4I7q5IznZoszyVATDzexlAyYt@BX5hGlys6rdI@INbiOuBgAxS0SzYt1PtOslrgxM9lzXYnyIzsPikckEUD4JAL3brn9IElAHQQXocD0PsILjekP0FaKaCm0wEgAF9G@3eBEb6MgyinCzMhe5@5f96Vk@C60m1X9h0zggAb@q8RQvTlzpp8RA8AcVj69cLOMNpkpMXom@wzymLssQrDHztz1j/cLmw51iRr37JygKyu9@OxFL8WXfN0gEtg0F0J/9uGoHY4nkkbqAvBaphfgcwsZnD4b7vUVMyyUI3RlXFUtnAJjkp77zkj96d6zVywXoUGgaUElckPAl7eBENqyYPfHTPh33TCb3@yFWD8qFDM/xyQLmOkyFgseD5KQ5qbQlufr9xH4yRewG50YRASJ2rqG1Y4NmDElkdmdQ@JDrVtVMNCbITW6FQ2fBR@b9ok7RCwTKSUHbRQYG/gDflBQA/ZdU0CZMJ07Vm6W5ZHuiRB2jmYKhny@/GEpV5kvFVZHG79Q@kZ97FvWrudunnFsdNy3ETwwEkwlMhcrkTcLzsD/adIjygsOkXpb8JRZIaM1suJKoTaZFb18WNvodGc0xvprbgBjCaqOAgCNKRATBd/Zul5ayI5lrWF/NX6pj9hSKMniWZQYq4RUXbYC8Q7/MNKs3PxH14MZraAa7y2LbcVk0KLCx4qf9eUy16riijv6@iftMD8AlfLN44fNDegemxLNt6olqT0WaKCYqaoq15mHCFHlAQuQv9RyAsEq7hK/M78QZQGGyJVPRYa@blYGwqZUOHxmVGNiyxgxQa7aKoBmetylrPId2BYDEfIJ9vaAngAcHtH91vhKnntW23f@xNgzm9jJFg0AvyRMcGIWgaCPMNaEs1huBH4gef7@l5aGu5x1LbFmqECGb@RAHl95EigQ9XtQT9UkN4U8xiO33ZFWRK0JkPH9yoI44bY2VKtZRkkKqgBW2S6oEs4ZItYtI3CKTbhHV07M4dBckgpLDDxH@32Sh4nqEVebjNAMrOJD69riIHNpKY6Q2jcqEYS7M8/xUcSbisNGoFaaW@gtozjDqVRzuVF2IrbxDmDDYnEhAV3QR9cWJd6NvmDMh0eBWRSaRHyMwOl9l4U6W533ACxgyHtvJpoz9V5CSCinM6vdDBJ2snD4pQKQvhvkElfGIX/Nm4R6KnRibEZ@OjWrCMTR5OsbNHJ/yXwrz8zmuXpB8EFJpFhvBU7pfKpAtMWtfD7GPIDLCQX1@Sq5TVgLh82/IIhiwH2ipdpVBZuFJLUviX0DbrxjP61wyFsBulutWpmEYA8HVjKnuEoORxISrfya7IG4jfwI1gSzAJ1236FnKRFPtxa/WWxbcgxMkbXHKBcT3Nm6EIY8OCiNzqWLnQs6ZSfLYOUiyA0EQBd4vKru8m4uQIcM3KfJ3tIAgsFqyESZfxRdhBo5PGw8fbrQfMTpQioiNftmIh5xIPqrr78KOigPgl5W0jsefDE4XUeTT4f8byEpZW/yD@ObTdaxBAaNKfFxXMCP8GylxrQQ9Y@gocxkDC2QRK@pKMwEQ3qRs4J5i/M9kviwEOUQbh19@Y1oZlY8iXczEsNgcR4S4NLO40Gs5N8QOFiULpAA1qiwfs1NhPb7NRUvDoc0EfaYFrhpKHbNlE92XRGDWVIdXeQwpI0iK@qnyxXjpg@JKVyDvC0ERnd7pEDfoqZMlE6XZBYMjlQldZOUg0JSycKqfmRlkdOZV15KVCNLf/E1Qu6cKk6rQovET@x3JwyvX9mVBi7GiojwdsdKTkHAHzqi6iLEvpY6ET2KkUd1WunQPYZrxEcNJmsWSDexTsjZEKng97BJBcR8gSlRd0hr@ANkflGxWYohEF8EQZaDCnZyI7Zy5Xe5zQCiaLhUY7g/2cPvJ4UfvU0boS6wg9kDRHKQWitUZSxGTdTvXjLkNsK85DgdJHHwbWCevog8VUcFaqTTO6Jmv@qRaoZahTWP/J3aQBbCNJVm0cBQc@vzJGYNYQq58u4QM/F@co9cThthDbMfOf2NL4gBhP7j26JO59gfeek0QoriAa7exeh2@DADlx3b6SAG5d4jm2vATXrbJ5WJyJB9hAlvuPldmKEpbemmpWkcK3sWJIUX09AckWJdh1Dej5KoEvR7sRhKJw1yKm2P9fHF9Xo7KFEAJRZldwJyeDEU01b2EcTYsinQSRxxd05Urjml68O9Y4SSC3rM@7zZZiJWBuBSWpjQOOx7URzcATkDhGlfXBUIW42mjm2oN3A3muG8jZDEXYmHCZFGFjwRiZe5LxVIPsueDUgOqtgaSJk3aqVLA1OllhTHfjSgGhRGznpTWZsBHuAMye6hLEkso6IxK7a8kgq@EtXxwxDC1CHipNHEMtNiaT9XyLtOPDSQltR2FYbb3j/Qa/YcMxrAy9qIwFJDUrzRHzFCssfNKO4d4DDNG1Tygb@6qN1QT9aYE2UI0/Ltl1lNuzYCzBbsrtq6MKKk2OW7gPc2qiGE4b6SWhxRS0aZ4QSs4CkuJ5KTYbUum3zdz5I/LB7ZcYMNQiM9xTY6LATMT4CC39GZ5jvUpZaNkH8YklWzuR5OmwvBXuhw/B7bdMekcoTqG7SP0HtXMkL/sH@JKpraTJUwVFr9tHfEslphD1mIHhxgyOS0np5Er7fAMVeouzK1khn4JmPBnYQbiH6kMGwipF2kz@3c7QQZv4QukFkLu76NkxSoHYPc4sZxWZ6qVSEWKz95nfqT62LHCEbBgYzrWlCe9MdjFVNB5oXLBh3OR85T/JI/UFf7Ck8bMUmb1vbmR9WMk7GSEpdHi2iFhkKAN8bhwHPIaEBMyWlexvLUyOzh/82UH2Y7bhFzPu2D@GxL9ghuE7fotfh3/5/zUIh5Z2AtkiiHmTCWCatrWALin4B/x4uc3xbCf50e4JcPRqRqt2slvJpCY6lZJJGiRgarr0l7Q35O9qyrpFDl7YbE2Me9XElg6QsyOScQs5gN@WqIPuyNMBVVRHrkoEclwQolAc0w6BoKqTbP75ZJ3uxU6T091imlZLUKZb4rtWkObRWRRvXhJKo6pfEbmw8o6x75Cv21IyZRVBS/9fmQCWEEAS9CRLsEHUPk5eeWoJxbyHmnsxuJJ3gVJ94@ZlNDiquJt7vBAOvoguWb4LAU25w@kuqeDe4cT5HD3D6orLuKNvNXTLHT8plzU7inGWdqUSOQ9P2U4CbpC72fvqfXvsEXHIpAAOWWXFs7ITGm@j0OLbzkNDomhNoH9/ZC8490Ou2j/ZE8pBYJ57to5qfxOxFbUc3IUhMJeKyEQcMx@31bFBvN4twto94TKMO2sYJAyVAvyVqVEZ36zndx1edFhG@Mu7Fc0QWpy5B0fmW78ZFPlfB@n3OMnSafrgrwSA6POZHcBH1hx4cpnGv@xCDdhTlL8rsVHtVkyx0aGIs0ZU2qmeEdJ1LEVZOk/qaUh8h8LJbt@2fZssGg52k8EIYGePMCNaWwOpPF0k1y7M1YMzE4b77hzidXZpvUAmMowkQPaRJzJg1faWvZNLDud0IXKRby4gXhkrgx/QGW@DPCawcRSBoVJVrcHh7wVe97HCH2zwiz1wZS2x456E05qk5aaJMCrX82sF@3pnnjHWsORiKOUuQFxCNensO5tBtFkdZJSg1C9rb0I0pA97yp0lrFb0d5hIDLEtwWeoLMd8LIuZp75nTcHtV4fHUzYrq05nQeoluBrgg4UjAYot3JNUhYItiLs9I/hl7V6nqxO6jE7ky3brcTN4nOJC3bbWiNxshubVXbQTupvVjJX@omqyIM4v@CGmznKijMlRkiEksyCBbZi3LEuxCKnoBSd0GKUgr6X6C1FwErLUpsyG2PclRiDak@TWMBvc6l58LasjVOJbIytGGupyGIKLvXNR0Ira7cAyQUT/gj2mwzEldEcef4ztbIBb30hhrBFM2MiSiY5hEv8S/rKsAlB2CG7pAI8rKSUBRFW6X0SVhvPfuxOUeCARLKrz2QRjsxGyvG7SRLLwP@HjkitQH6pQk4H4yaJGLKGLpUaZxOfI2UWsuxnN8XpRX1x74pl/Oia2@JAsyh2d5Zo@TjYaGwXz1YP7oxfExp2yWtQEDACX@PWkJCI@Yq/eaWkTREPjFilzZPuQa2o8ZpvjXEQW31KQ4m7jGYzwkv9E2c5MzPv2xDFDLi/6XMMa0b235hQ7SLBy6KgzP8lSs/q4SJDBNtbBfgsS0ReBBKJqyK@kB1nVsuc35MgvJ7CYZLC44/dZJ45dsZLPwl4NiDCvfesT8Bmjx3@2F2vq6/EfWIQtR8aW5gXgAS7gIgQhIjuYnuaODqfrMHXhL3egKce0ugqnpKeYVq2cvTDUOg7KxBbpCzeY6B6KMLQm@ZEbjiKTBISZ0btL0Cf2KbYo642f7JaaKvtvURGYjtGoASn3UlK8oaZdamyYHhxZJC1yGd/xxCJ2dycjt@UqPoNzY2qcfiDBxUtdQlGOeP146EQgWPZ3e42Yv4jBVe1emaBd0TIrOgbU@AQPTpLXlVYY9gODyFLhWPBpcC9I02iEvP0S0/FcoVNISSgudSNHM1ANaNSYByCCOD9M0tuVRMqu2MFV6DugSvCPiZoOPC1ykC40HpLAglgv/ZJUI2UyDU/LMxnwP9XBQNYN9mHOPI4IkTY9u7SiK38EMEx4OlGv7yoVbHYqwTCZDmjeN0HWg9nL@Uyu0jarEREUPfVCgTQlDXoXT@SG8kzblmoRvqoSL6O7PoKLfeEZaAwpHLV7KmomG/574RrF4/nMkWI4kAi6bnz1NZ2IVIvpHOqm14yDxu28iclTfAVT7E51oDA3gHM6FgrSpiAf8lhCfFxMr2bkZ0K2GR84xnbVWM3YmzgIMdXcg2JVTzIx/S7NdJ@twu2SkATXEilZ1@AUYeauZ/sC10aXdt@cJBg03Nzl4hy6pIQ6VzS/UV3prNxZzTPUjUJFvFAR1EcY/Jamb0nmKCYmDLqEH1EPPd9DZdLzkTYSUNAjp37G0JpBiWQ32eLH5aaeGNzQjtgpeiVErix24DGnxIfehNg03DNKjmLQhTLwDMUucIqJNcJPMNTFRAJHLEtDFp0UXJj0b97VPIzx@Ur2gT5D1Z9xFmPIYQ7Y2iPgc9vKbTFvFNhrXjCPZLhrro7uayS1GsWZ1pMYhCKHzs2vlScv17DIV4ocHjjIMgcRCafJ8ArEvgUDbrnGgfJE1DgRH2GjE3a8q6GTvYYxNy1BGGKIIdP33/qBZOCwE6SCgySziM346/@wUjRseaVN7M7EOyVIiI7hux@fnTTM8jdhKk4vwQ4vgxwOWmE9Qwoghgcx4s1gIOJRvJHiTiJv7MmJfg4kF@v6u8QAUkc2qfECIYDsMvKwudVY5rYGxVLJD6U1jV6UscqXYf4GcOqQBdwI9D1szbgSLrG@WFRZrHsBxk15TMJSOP3ULNRVU0pTYXQqmXOZoYlkmtR6wToXGLekkO@ZBfA2UAXqohIEqwwxlRF6JALSNtfYVi@Pt5P9El5T5RHYW5Ujr12KkyXVXuAsxD7/EZoAs4IyKXhwjCYYg9OdpfDyJQCIN9MQiD1DL6BigIfERk8Cbl6OSUL0QrQT59cIGYDUo5bqX1WjJXyfDY2QJKirWrSFwyKGhMWsqBGcll4oscypi550a@Ea3TbS4ptS3jtJU8Ts@aen6LUO0dluSfoR2QReq07qZ6ANaDiuikxhgqsJAdjj8Q9GJ/oH/rjwHBh@kplm1jSTmDbh40cZK6maeu755KfXI0vQAx5Dy9GuS0wARs98S/dech88BWO4B8ZjwYSN7bA13zXLCx6ritS7sQvU9bpWAoFftAL@Ls2IBhPN2stSacg8VhZBvsT8WdVhwP9KFdzMqM6JD3X4aicLN8ibXfqAzBCtoQ4GYmXsuv4j4Lvx0eiVMF1QRYcSdDez4e0w/udbOOCZLSs/kBUXMbNSj4tAUsFTUC5wc9q3m@JlscOEBvNNhtpAGJkMBshS06MWLW1YAeS3sREl4lEvA3gkOWUCBhEgj6EVyrygkBM3Kl9gicZU467/gbnQeQYHI5rOVLftmogyBY75F7AzdwfGZKE9D9aNnd@ThfcQDA2DLCZ8s3KmBJkrKKxkmC5wF6zQstTU2ahM0G5bNWZZprGcESZelj1kTQ9c8p4egoujRQddZk9itE@jL1KKr9ZYZvgZpfe2MmUVEZKXwVw0Wdqn5AqiMOVNrtgotQBx9NbjrG8AEQuuryKwjxAPwcTUqLNYHZRto7JKC1ZLDAWfDPgJpQncCCvdT57lvxAa1LoJ5jupBqMGX1SdTfV86QiOylHntoEljYlr43DdptzMRNMDkDyqZqrsTTHLjjN8o7xN2/yUc20JLv7jC8x9WKBAjwcnyhxGOtZFrSucAG6Y4s/x6I5DJQn@RSmf6eQyckCi/ouQAJ6kj2qVCwBClBiUuTtSEgvzH9Vge0UJAYTLnr0QK0A0FmTluKbKAVgiY8Q5JAp38q8KduX8jc/JDbkLShJdcXGnymtTAzyA7cm7oTV@Yf0hysDqvb9dLbeRMy8w4HJC52KoJb8rpiEgC5YIQwhe0jsDSP6kvsXtl@XE4xCzpPF36aJ9wsg4x0uTZyqTQ@1gRwmytpogEJUCSQ2XIx@tPoc2HsgyfHKtY2wss2sc@@qTcQlCI2s@1Mx@CZCyFEhYC9EPJpUgUcaewjiO5FL7vbsZqYc0br49NOccxDJ6UM3E1EIesYTzqw/UR4M9JhC4GmXwSInxJeA@@snJb9D@cRXgZKYXoc8hXSbew7rzmU8RN5b2d0joWa@DA7AbQbZUpIDB9ilFFrWjH8@ybPoT3RYnv0jdgoOEClKg8KAvaZM49Q1Ek7CBtKd0OKz7ufTxx6TzMVvg4kxsski7imuA4FF/jWwzkUQxvpvuCMKwsaoJPgwpeBL3wAnBjmhhCYqmtBBrAs3MkhvWs1mHPNuJu@RkKAcnRBzua2sTyn1kmQE86sCaKljx1JIsuy1jZGI5LdpjYotA0x7/LJLgXNgSL4Zp7LqEVYOtu/7A0GZELLRd6gBkvXRWbZcUBv7JGEPgHYs1tDTRoM89SiEx6pM1MvCe@RUIOSoHFVL2AYZI1czaWm4IDTQdZ9YphMtIwX5VAoG6d3KEnsTCZBFw34AYcRiARC8huHHWk6I7oquH8@YZWyOFGIX4bEnBSZcZycxz0nJrU0JHxMsj0MsxEkItpOIeLWjMqNAHSm8wDNmMuSRNj6JH9KOfX3adA9VWnEbZP4uQlOswVZIZkcBH6cKWA@iMNj7KpgQz8QzAMuVZ9vxxDPqWcBG9lYSRh8PcEM4HZDhLbuNUcRcwYsobzj1bndJd9e@1glqwA2vKFVl9Vl0nMQhfgErxuVsCbNgUI4t5uNiyIEed1w1ZfUAB5@rEjao3VEgsV9NGKhEwAlcBe0m3fOb@CxJWZ39kxOEOEZBOOuhLiJnZODGJ5jwkjpGUqMbwj/h3Mc41LQELj5H@pNa6BJ1CSLgN1qFMXVnhshqnmUshBgHKUMVdtsotWMPvvUuZE6WyXywAPA9@3RxVCYm2aPXkYwUwHwySKzP/WYxV9y75qo6IGrjxGkwA/LjKMOiY7GtPI4hBOtW7B/iRCCQX8dmcfbQo56fJu2GmUOxBkFmY84hZbmtNpFJInKuzUTR3FLIGD6PJRcSZ01o018jOZYICpsPTvWxntVrv0pESXd75OwNhjWJg58yaWH6ZJb6e3Zqj4EIlto7UotPJsaOuCyED4GDnt/IymVpRIiPzZGZl9pQBCq1AbTwhql@Ms3Gh2r4ZkpblY7jlHDh8DJlqlLuicjqsbjGTnFPoDgqOoab9WQFrWPKd5yeQX2Xq5wZeiY9rYAwme/NJj8krTzTH0SdQPi2cJ1gi8/kHTW5txvF@WGaNJZsmHq4zebBnrcSy1fFG16Sm6mEJq1romGYNFPoTui/0UMPWCuHybO6SCz7n@Ytoh9oEcgDopYiRkwMOJsN2OQnxcO2pfQ6iL8wON2PYVM/mfexRMYDRv2Zrh6HgG12crO0MnkWqvBcVXSJy4OtOincUAYuopUpnlM7CbDMThKyFkoQ7fjPwHRk8MYUYqS4@BorbbwcYl2m6sCTTsakqKtkEEhZQJOqrSY2fCDCKfliwFJWuzxSHMe7uRmZeK1wi3ICC@G1zFHWYAyr7XxBQqBTyABOlwHoxD8fGB1i9GHs4pl9hOo3A5gvYWeXvoLiaoY5gx84Y/sJmzIxr9CJZb1PJNJi75GsMSUGALaGeSpAJ5LKdKpIgWkyu6hkqhmHb4x1V@Yh0d1L9WXT4eDwlemhNOklTpdSdxZDANpFSm/2/UEmUnV42MUeiQ1eXbXwgEETpTLvAI3BlQwHMWzoILA1d1hwELYGwIsmHihicSdXvo8rhkYNucmmqjgYiiTNG8SzoxTSXVVws@ZxbvsEFK1@QMgcBis5wY/6hT3z2TKpZIUH8XifAeRJ3C3WSWeQsG1A0awfp6Fn6Ie4heNXPLEVZ0iZch@eWROb4plAJD9NlAH9jo1DCSOkUkHM3OZO6bBrCEm4YBN4qFwbRNBaxFKyArdZ17EQIBp2hytc3tReIHci7TliwwTmxaTHKx5Ibnr5xw2DrTI@7yamEhsTNPtatyeqmInKNjMfChjQ5fc6QJZp5wtdXqbpSbl6vCxVzGVLJK0Dfq3ITGyhfFpi/BVlwvxnpX6GiqbhFOL1pZS0bHgqpJgzkpEQwsTxU83@GCCZjyTJ5uIJKyFtID0fkRGAQUyiyrJGSRuzAYxtAw0AEURF1@FIPUtg1fN@6kSEEiHPiKwITY63@xF6QgKXKMf8hPXOTL1tuygzCzc/ayv5v0CvMRat5P8Sb8mSetNp7De18xRwlg4C@Iu9pPb@skyD5f2Nthxl7lPwwsDYnI4ri1opeB5jnrGwjC7ls8O0JP5c2/5DZZ8lLlpvCfB8/W9QP/CbekrxK4BfojR7a1jEFaCy3w@cD2QqZmyMgj6tyBRXjKUcjUdrEMITmYmXVv1EAuup@6PyC521uUqRqxogEc@MzZpGvgkurSy3rdJZGRCrraGyjOjOsYq9ir9yNoSVo8ovb8YYYW1Y2PgSaY6Nf9pQeqVyrUrF@LfvdpfPjDzk4qJUepJQ4J5YjK5QEEk5Uz3H@G6UO7G8UzwQ3/u8zdn425O6g2FfQZGWYRlmp2RPQB5grEBJlhhkgo4hYMnw6sVUuY8okYS@WKNdtGWtpBakWIjmWdbBwZMwaQDsQerxZGdSjoz4xduNKGvJ0n0/1gl7DF0xPp7cm4SARGjYC9gZ6j3smdupKNJ1PSsMSdIiSz9CtVZYiF2FdzmuP8PUjN2kpcKtKJ5ZIwr0pDJljFECL@KnZ7R7YuZa/yeVRyDMfhrj82bIEMyValmD7lqE3lXqbCRt@maUIoEESWnLpM0Sy6tlaLptAQcorp4sQFzVx@rMgEpW8akKO8H7YpU7icXHATIyZXwR3iS69tXdAevEfP@qOLxV7HAx8wrnOxKhyiSSBw5ELrdg0UsGKUli3/2TO8a@SzaQsBWxaL7oOydYterXIQKN6JA1YRWHeZ2wPEn72K5JQ4Kb8AHaCk6ddAo0sWzKsSMg/2b@WWPgkPoB2fRK5oyZCPnWVZAAFGDKXkcOU1/7yZplst45xHTvAP3ZL9lcumA/MWNYhKk5SIaK1A5r5zBIGKABgUaqzVEhYmQ9ww4GoH6fMh@MQZifIJwBsrAACfoJ6Ynqy2GEVzlXoFhxbakzz6TP8GT8GLMSp2ad604irMbYiT4CRseHSvGB12WzAcGOzA/nGgcBjiCJog/QU3dGVlcVxU1tra6S5rC5iRjgQWHrLUofJwh6CSI@oQJBvMhyXqgxJ/m/Xr1n5quhptqpeHsRCZkOOiBHi7ZCsvgOjg5eFpvOdC17YA5ILGFS76x4iJxE3TqdyEwkUeSanCyxraaizwNZGkDHmDUEDxGpRlxZhQdRQYa3hSvbdmlg7IzaP7UOYhKwKp2Nc0uUJrEQX/GzzsJCQa90@CdAAlmwhLhP0vshbEEKJ99HAQelxFF5y94YLPNwB7HVrxSRUf9iNhEh54UnVg8YMJUNX2BqUP2Gq4DbfEbqTYlc2HNAomUB4D/9NPg6KtTOEgogmDoibPspAfdcy2RuZjhe@SU/yecha/ds6eFlUpNqrXChQGwl55TaqmVf3ZOyi4kkxe7fqYKwmjfnCiYCuk@RdeyGB65RvRj6xQDsSB8mLnC9qcHYFaHEtUVsjGpqsBgI@BOw31ZvRCDnvFk@mszWSU2bA1S2PGhw/gVl36kSRIaEbyi@fE/sIvlzgAfwCYkGYtmWa4x67x1ZwzIBsh2LNDm2Fpc@SVplHcVWTbwkYbtPXoWyG8SaMzUzEyby1YdNiBKhMgxPwEXAhICSC4rBNyTMAGznkhPf6IZdlacZVGhJPFZa1qh5wxAjSFFZdIg3xQiDw7tS1cjiksgoMl6ZTeDpAFfyZYR64VZPVr8E2wCADD1AxqUCdAkbJekFjG9kYB7C5HTKkHR@ilukOsFIfCrImtr3EkF4sxQun@oQxGypN1JVk4FwtKo8iQ@cFOX2pbT57yJIQM@jXZDxr9fSvdlFLwkLfMqZlSxmptvKsD0wJ2LGAUp7@q0ozfiJKWElQEYigJuYaVJhptjhCGeoJ4WYsNwIEkMwVGHtnenDAc4CRPbkY8M6e1yxDVECyj6CJM/cAWzyNq0WH7OYZ4BLNquoO/ijZmIc9anhCqV4CJFJRgHGnUvyDeo5MqVG0ukRg8qQlNMk1NZJ7kjicJNf@qYGTlmL@GvoxCWPIvZyQEmg6yUdBYjrYXaSR@78b@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@VPgqUlM@kDowS0g@NCBenTckkeVT4kqkELpxBVweGfqARAjrr@3DNyxaGy2NCoLoJy7TBLFkSDtkSE6tn9YiGcqTr@JWbTUzAZrAi16Ze0x6Z0TbaLc8M4q2Z1XpQbk@xVWI5/GvgZEqCVa@WJWdlXfm7lIAZHPkhqYOcDezhX0ncwlFKKZIraAxpHbeKWk2bOyUXxWJI0TUF3Mvlb@ctbXI/ZIUGvAsGU@9gK0i00EPI40CpZbS@o7GR7tvqzpGZ7BlmIVn3AzWvsqHcbnRjyBgPosLZtr/AoLIPSnhQk3k5WeElOWZ@MrnBS@gSWEKDTJ75HJwTIIFzXRAKSRfEjDhwSVZL1WfQgSbRNCBbLz61O9TnXbNEaT4Jal6zKRohTkIWuEO4TL0BIMhbk7bTi8@WzxJcI/ZUFIwbOhyA/aFwCkAPMMeK4sqiRNbgUuSB7DbSdjj/d@qZuSekquX/H0dDmeEn0DDI434dLXWHg74yOxEaQNktR/tvAj74rYL9IaLHDkRm7ut48/G/ONuD9m6yH/k6Jxj0NkhK52civJfKY@IFUlHOpiJKFhSiUlYDwzBRhbd/gM5RbGMeZPmqlZ4XwNIQvQPUsrnKAVxShweR824hI42kDxCdql0hQkXrRx7hHeiPLIuSCsrJMAtozM/vnkcM/J4hOkZ6BhDqT2MuxQuBgsuIVEH5wSInJkSG7mEb@cNktRvFJs/OwVPRH6dzpvjGIX3UvRv55FArE@TKijVgqGC94l4H2C58kpmR8cfLGI8zVgl5I3JFm7DePA@SctR145g4Qny8LXrAlzm6g6A4MaabdwtMsAF4KbdAxq6RhRgG3YR7pE@PFMAIlskKJgushoHYQbZlYeQi@IOFYKsab2V3o90EXwdCt3CpsFdcfUqwOzmbkO5t4zMy/YcyNmmdkUFSGkDCQt5UkIfpC@Y90D30BVqCSRYWrifnOpmxtncifAsCYKqb5NgntZ9ADlM7YInhBt7qnyDTUwByXaEgWyqd0eQxrgGpbOm3XdUWl4s0ZIf5NBcrM/dlLVgfMl7BnlMxKbbDAopzFzobBRDSwVlG652OAAUJCnImkvLMpgbdwZ1K2Q2YCDjtpwB0vTM7EML3il6lcMChb2TWk2WEUp6Zb1vqCH4DmglBzz5cn8dNaEYctZ1EmbWcJk3OT7hI8FUW0DriOHinEHVhnYErJ@qRjCbrNTOI@iYSkjCzBGeT7MPPbv9/nAhfl9yK1fgCZ8SwoeEqfIAXSTpAUEp5ifKWlGobSD59bTUXrzvwm@bNgzYHUp9MAcWulsPUndRCsMWuub0yb2d8YnNg@qVoOcVgo2XvKvFOeE2A28I87rlF94CQ0gus/frV2OeDlYWIDaidBPAX0mEFjvVB6ByQRkHGftwppIGC8R0/jpzkBcfsOR/8MrYesF1whAnCwYtm/WfCN9kttTp28uiUMWoZNVl1BgBW77stG@CYNkjvZSOKoYCFXYWVGMQ3whjxxyxrHYkrfZSWcjTJnOIOhgDAU8vYvm7wOaFug4zL@ECsa0emsTJtDRE9WS6eKV6CTCPrhczJ6FVXEh2LGEkZZ9s7wzYBF8YtZ3yvuSB2NT3gQe4HzsXkmRhIzu7ar12HpkRsIW3TeJXLBzSQ1AacPwRIxho/cbl4Ob3VLBm@di44BOnJBKtHjRnIgZg28dqyva/MhykdVbCE08aYAjQgo8Zmc@5CbKlYqZFCchuNVTh7GlzUVYHmVg6K2EOVrStBPnWhQY1CzIIYFWeFIMGZDbzp0L5hoG6APULnErhIoyVzlbjiv0VHl9nCIAahfuAJEs4GpVJu5Qx5Wo1aXWEbUcUbFiiSCCmpXibk4qYoJgdEGcZyiZYQW4EJINsiNEAjKVPO9XGyezYmnv47TR/bB00hCkfhlEhBTMTOjAxUdIIx1ZaUp4spREL4L1yUlP9C3xupPy9T0LyKLWjClzU/IL0diG458FhcDbIeGBWZCSIRWwP9QGh5ICaZ7BhgWGpUYyBGbTLK8QaamT1B3iRyshiSSjcJ1JYDORLyx@Qu/URUQKLq0XAOUUD8f8ZR2ijCkZ3CfpXLiKmN2TCj9UyksxHPx9fFZAskBXZ0kqhSVHiA0cCDrFxGafKizM2UkmI8N2SmFvv19@CQDiJoFK5vxJOgPRVkw3JnWmEHiGvMoDNqGDQIS8wNhO@PpRegbHf54Uihj5LgQrWaExotiHsrQ1azGZCKyEkxkYBt9KVRLIjSOFZfCuQRjPkdwd4lSp@Bz3o0eVcCDUgm7PxcrJor88E/Ol5z6z@RnM3IFGNYYUSFqCDx0Db7zJaSIIz8qIMR1rDQYxY/dJuuFETZqaIjtfFOJkq/ztw7LwIM/zEBLMZQiEG3y1N4Mc4I1gDszkrEJ93SvZWsPqHcQMySEn/wxrFAA@YGpcaQR6wR6zBJYD/GZXo2OLMXISFzWz3h9UWbQmEMNZmfhifyDwB9O@w/dhGWfVQfx0ZwmqFEEl@vUmwRsIbwoNj5XBg9EzoD4zbJiLMt4alqkzphSYx/nAuKX6EdI0aKhXYo3VFiEO5Kkg@m1MQkJPE3RzTQtibOyoibYo/DRRv5k2OYDJmEiom1JGF0wa4f7MqBLwxCqkoBeI0NSEfpDKTRR5z4zDJQCyUs8W6BrVjJLxKXDBYHWl64kejjQbyGhgMvbUIEyFbpwgtMEuBlRKCyIrSZgnRaHw/Bg0fDaSUie50Cslc9hk0vjducSf8p9TjyvFJbJcL@Y@RlyCWQkH4oUi50VuIMsZM2seNlzMAZH4UP0YOeHoR@o4U9X1zbrt2PAIW@CEnVRQSilJWA14K1lyMaX2ZiKsMVpn5nsS5Xtm4uFvlgALWxhnBkluQo98yie5jynDgSneOfUpEcncY2NjAABE4gfbOkuoQzU8PYfp@PWX//Lv//K3X//5r3/806@//PHPf/rTX3/3f/7TX/7w97/8f3/3yy//@oe//vKXX/7TLxz55R9@ab/@Xgf/poP8@4//8svv/hf95pd//tOvf/nTv/7hH//1T//td8@vf//7X/78h7/@7c@//v6X/xln/r///Y//@odffve3X/7jL3@pG/ySl//b77PJReOP/1C3@99/@dvfx/978578uq70y19@/3f/8@/@zvf56x//xx9@9x/@8n//@a//4e9//3d/98df/@1vf/3LP/6Pf/q33@W7cOy3p/4fv/7X35z9L3/68y@/43X@GHd@fh//@Y/VBf/4r3/49b/99b/HkX/4h3rQ375X3eQ///G/xDX@57//@/8P). Currently, we can't use TIO with all of the inputs.

```javascript
function iroot(base) {
  let s = base + 1n;
  let u = base;
  if (!base) { console.log(0n); return; }
  while (u < s) {
    s = u;
    u = (u + base / u) / 2n;
  }
  return s;
}

const inputs = [/* the gist goes here*/]

console.time("sqrt");

inputs.map(iroot);

console.timeEnd("sqrt");

for (let i = 0; i < iroot.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i]);
}
```

This is based off of a [StackOverflow answer I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64190185/how-do-i-extract-the-nth-root-of-a-bigint-in-javascript/64190462#64190462), which was based off of [Newton's formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30869049/12101554). This function is better than the built in `Math.sqrt()` or `Math.pow()` or `**` since this gives precision even to the last digits instead of 1.457746e57 or something like that. Also with BigInt, all numbers are `integers`, so you can't use `**` a decimal/fraction.

This code expects a long array to be prefilled with the numbers as bigints: https://gist.github.com/Samathingamajig/23b8107f299649d6bd3399b04f65c257 , which can be compressed into one line through this gist: https://gist.github.com/Samathingamajig/88f64e58ba21bd8d392be23bbb85dd9d

A Gist with all the data as raw JSON can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Samathingamajig/c15fd1f15a7bca6181a2e792c469503d

Comment: why the second argument as the challenge is for square root? just using 2n instead and removing k1 gives 111ms, also it's seems timer gives user time not sys time, which is less

Comment: Your TIO link suffers from rounding errors in its inputs array; you need to suffix `n` on all of those numbers otherwise they'll get converted to float and back to BigInt.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul fixed, no improvements in time were given, it is still randomly between 100-200ms. What do you mean by "also it's seems timer gives user time not sys time"?

Comment: @Neil I fixed that

Comment: @Samathingamajig about the different times i'm refering the debug section given by tio. for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1 finally it's user+sys time which should be taken

Comment: finally it's not exact because these times may include compile and launch

Comment: I have added larger test cases

Answer (score 8):

## Rust 450 μs

```
use std::time::SystemTime;
use num_bigint::BigUint;

fn main() {
    // Parse the numbers
    let mut numbers: Vec<_> = INPUT.iter().map(|i| {
        i.parse::<BigUint>().unwrap()
    }).collect();

    let start = SystemTime::now();

    // Do the calculation
    numbers.iter_mut().for_each(|s| *s = s.sqrt());

    // Print the time.
    println!("{}us", start.elapsed().unwrap().as_micros());
}
```

I agree that the input is too small. If performance was an issue, we would
not use a library, but create a custom integer algorithm for monotonic
series of integers, do them on SIMD hardware and multithreaded on 64 cores.

Comment: Rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=d9358e5557fa8e640761e30baba09ce8

Comment: The OP's Chromebook won't have 64 cores, but yes good point about threading the computation since the test is guaranteed to be multiple separate sqrt calculations.  No need to find parallelism within one single sqrt.  And yes maybe even interleave limbs of 2 or 4 integers to allow vertical SIMD, perhaps using double-precision FMA instructions to do 52 integer bits per 64-bit chunk, like @Mysticial's code does for prime95 / y-cruncher, see his answer on [Can I use the AVX FMA units to do bit-exact 52 bit integer multiplications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41403718).

Comment: Although Goldmont Atom still only has SSE4.x, not AVX/FMA, so SIMD is much harder to use for extended-precision, beyond how GMP already uses it (e.g. for right shifts, not multiplies or divides IIRC)

Comment: The impl of BigUint::sqrt starts well with a f64 approximation, but then uses a refinement algorithm with a divide which significantly increases the cost. https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint/blob/master/src/biguint.rs#L1735 I'd need to check to see what gmp does.

Comment: I have added larger test cases, might take somewhere in the range of milliseconds now :p

Comment: Be careful: since you didn’t do anything with the result, the compiler could be optimizing away part or all of the computation.

Comment: If I get the time to finish it, I have a novel algorithm that uses only multiplies and should perform better than the Babylonian algorithm used by the other examples.

Comment: @Anders Yes.This is a danger. We are saved only by LLVM being very poor at understanding memory allocations and the complexity of the BigUint impl.

Comment: So…why not remove the danger? After stopping the timer, print out the computed numbers or at least some kind of checksum.

Comment: This function https://godbolt.org/z/898GW9 looks quite promising. It uses the inverse square root in fixed point and (hopefully!) will not overflow as it always underestimates the lower bound. The inverse root has the advantage of only using multiplies as divides are microcoded. The function should also vectorise nicely.

Comment: @Anders even a checksum could be pre-computed by the compiler. I have written optimisers that are quite good at this! Some compilers will attempt to execute the generated IR to completion, especially in benchmark-busters.

Comment: The compiler can’t pre-compute a program that reads numbers from stdin and writes their square roots to stdout. And there are [functions](https://docs.rs/criterion/0.3.3/src/criterion/lib.rs.html#136-157) that are guaranteed by the language to be treated as I/O for this purpose. This is not an unsolvable problem.

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to confuse a compiler :)

Comment: I've tried the following methods to beat the Babylonian: Reciprocal Newtonian - still looks promising, the Martin Guy method: https://web.archive.org/web/20120306040058/http://medialab.freaknet.org/martin/src/sqrt/sqrt.c, the ascii digit method on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation (good up to 70 digits with u128 but falls off a cliff after that) any other suggestions welcome!

Comment: Of course, I could just use the Rust gmp bindings like @Anders, but as the poster says - that is boring :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), ~16-28 ms on TIO

```ruby
def newtonRoot base
    s = base + 1
    u = base
    if base == 0
        return 0
    end
    while u < s do
        s = u
        u = (u + base / u) / 2
    end
    return s
end

t = Time.now
outputs = inputs.map{ |i| newtonRoot i }
puts "> time elasped: #{ (Time.now - t) * 1000 } ms.\n\n"

puts outputs.map{ |v| v * v } == inputs

# un-comment below line to see outputs!
# outputs.map{ |i| print "#{i}, " }
```

The former code is a modification of latter code, which is specific to the square root of a "perfect square", and a bit faster!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vb3b0jXNcZx3jqv4TJ1INiVPT@8dpi/C4TPLB5IJhRFBAgwSkMIh8drpejJz3t9CAPh6rXdWz0xvqmuTlfWPf/mP/@@//OGP//CXP//Tr7/59X/@ev76V/vrX@Ovf91qrL/@9c6//tXr31GfV3196q/t4aqX1hhcxrWXi7n6nbROfdffwY/pj1@MQevUd/Otv85d1y1@sWhtvtv89XDd5Rd36W500x56bI3Om@7TXm7Zuu4@9CBTz7T0eEtPunnmdoaekPd4Hz1j07u9T33/9qeuecfTeHZ@@y61t74/uuZyfddve6OfejfesNN/H9yr67598wz98Dz98mzj4TmHnnl0nn8M3mUs3mtsjY9edz68@Wwaoq4xGgzN1CjNrfbl@/VwTXXQmBV@uyb9rE2f69D/fqaGld/uzjPsyfPszbPty3MeTeV5ef4zNL@L9zqHd7x637qQ9mAc7mJM7nm8CjTQz@tP49E0La6r2eJHramH1t6uT0Pz0JYmpR3N0JvV1DV379REvluz@l5Psee7j@kJ10roV8titOV1qF7qFfTpHC2Hxli12Rm45lFs8@jT8t9W15XLv1uahrbd5x66w/b99tXdj5@lVpQ@@Tnvo6e@fofrBXj1fjU4vO376N3fZ2sRtqzCrmXYNGYv3bAoNZ5vluKrsX5709/68Ird@t1wL6Orz6GZq2Wp@03Nae1F9TI1228tGP62tA7eei9@5xXy7ql9u7V23npNLX6tqtrM6uVqvb13MmY1N4xg7YmtraHR7c/Vp6bVW2/Hlf3Vuq4dow3yasX33iQduvZC74e7d@@SmuirT9o/fXZtpumdtbReat95zx1twO3duJe25vE@LTmiT9rBtVweb8nH8kgS6Rn@dPjbaJIHrChtWPVSa0Di75UMGf3lfvUVdy@BZrkmuVMTzHOOKYk05ta2X973a2njb0mxsae3vuRbSUT1ciT3xn0Zs3ElD@fTtOk9urM9@tQsP2uFSZZKrtZXEiFd8nb2wx3mkBwuKcLd59Sz1DxfCRXJ7VlLnyu35HnJZPVyHt5v1qTwt1qXXHknI1EXSGY/k1FiNpBHbT4SSA/jubx2V/en7r8NXzn8u@lepvtcugODxJVbd19@lhppnoyJ5m9XT11vIIH2WLo9er96Bcm9pnffr0Zie1x21yiVHGTM9tAI7qnx3JYMtSz1afkk2pqHvTUr23O0j2asRAF3OI9m8zya2@NT6TTN@3m1Cs6rNXG6VsjxeilBK3k7tZbO1Mqq12Mkzta4lFxhlM7RijxH6/NcrdbrtXsfreTbtK5v0ypnhyKsfVLVgScxPrQ77tBeuVM753of3aVddbf22N3acfdo/9UGVy9Xe7Mu11ZtT2s@kNv@jmefA13bvP7Vri@BJSFQ/0omtCcCuNayP6/rv@/p68/r31vatOdK@HCG6H71B6sATZKqnuLN4SI51lqXWKtTRlKu/pXQQ2VQf21JJNa/1@fPXj6OTvfpdHNYXUlXxlVHWekKOtne5mMvkpkTy5/79d@Hj753dv9@ub93SebXmebjr55C939PDsCcF/3x8YGoH/rXhwuahs697xjsPon6yEE4fU7Vctd49ZxiJQ01nv34jOvXR15tAY3/sFCpE9Tn43j995IZur7Wow/T72ydOWpnTt7l@4/tc3nkaKxVoudl2nX8Pj7TZ/P7zZz4dULp/UsCaDzqKo1Pianu89rjN5d1CWST/n6sadRjPFH3rPA9np8aBv29DrvHR7wUmBp091cnh/pH2Fyf/bp/7QQ9z7JSVP96/awrhamhT0kRaFKm2s76212KVv3r9bnHtt4wvX63FbRWEkXjuY@Ut/rX639fKXa1ujwfpw1/fr1/TpdC2HjtZtVD/Z3p/XeWFMnSRbw/S3ezpuLtW8taCmj9e62stGNt5d1WV3r0lSHB0BDz@vt6rTZvKbx12nj87pEy3EouSBl5HivKpehIVXmiuTzdKnXJAf99Wt1@lpXvx6Ku/o1ifo5VpCulvVaJxCSquvqrjSUlpha@tBgWqNSmKUOgJtmKTE2QNJka0BO1SrpMPbCUmbqBNasm0V6zKKvjLa2K8S5hI3ukOtN8vKUu@fOe/vsZvv7qSMF8UH/YBfr8yu55a7/q/qXU6Hm6j1@OJT0vSpz@fmRFvezPZkNE/Y2mY/AtRUTjwTBKwRuP9b0Z9a@GXZ@3Dth31Lmk6@/zmTTWAVs@v/777L5@Dv9@pr/ad@p/bt@vlAFrlNfPs/J8NY1RKv38q/t9Smro/Vbet5an3p/9ZbXT47Oux2tn/HbzeNY20fju7vEu8aLxzzFdh4fnZ2/P1z6ev309nyfze5rn@3TPf@0fq7bT6@NkvZzt9YPNo79fr6/7eL3drL/7ej3e7vVZ56nG506v35v1fI/Xdx2fUjyfR@u/P037oWd/lLhf/jy2/z6tqD4rxmbU2Ofa4OSglVLdbHTWgSMVuMXwLLEhBRkBqb8vq89oBvq95UGdWpIPJRWter@v5EctWyvmr@VLabpR23ezFn@s1NeLS8f/VP46p/z5tUFQ217X1/Tp993yr/c9rfifbc3/Sl720Z5P97fy37u1/yF5W8aA5G8dd5LHGNvqD02Zz6VdajzqeNL41Lmi8ZqW973OE41niXuNL@eIrj86L3rOj1qMrz@/Ol/QnXQ9lga/Xz6P@to6n9BydL8aZtsgj84zHAB2BHSdd73Wr55/T52HNco6H/v2edn31flZVovO0xIHOl/r2NZ5iytB/aGM6/PS@Vynjc7rfq7O79JCPB@3HX/u/vsdOv/RGvT7a/2ght/93yv9oW6i@9cilX5RUsamC5arPvv5B@Je1x@9H@4N2S/N719WlPSbgZyWOTWk/5RiaoOqDkrZV3Vw2dy60p9QP2SMRb8aJRj9eTb/3fM3auPbPrO@VmJR@tvonn@0TttoQ@sDl4v6614/A9NIf79aXwOxIKeM19@oH9hJM7Q@ByYc1w@vX5w36q/EpQy22aS/YlK8MvyG9NsxLa9Yxf7s/YNtq@tLAdfvl/Xnsbz/xprSr0u9iptoS/9m@au/0kP0vLvZvVTrTO@zvf9xKKm/vSUfRln0Go9j@cFq1ngdGwklxWQzjGP5M2p7arzrZ09cU@rvWn6x7fT3Wja6HjVdDkLLv1Fi2A7DK/lYJqzsnBouyU@cXHZ2TcnXsm1lI83H8nc@VxbUbDaoajRkX81m@T1RELke@RZ3mfprlv/V6Wu7@LUJXbMkqznn@awDx5@Pzej32o7uPn9wvNmSHjGlp23p7vOrTGtb08PG5xzN9vTw@Veb3RZ1TbDeb8SmHj4/65i1VV3nsManbtBlnfv8rWUjC3nWdDz6@5X9PJfP7xnrGnHmzzN/9/lf6rJ/v22ol2Xv/rf1h4m6Pmzq63l2nm9b/9Bxz9/P6/dhWpacAX7fs/z@ZZxqPM71@FzrPzgo1R/HqD5Pj@@1/jRru2/7Eez8fd7mz9a/Vh27cm6WOJJ78/H8lrDQfJfaoflfZTAduR6G1seK/ldWvNbPQrG98kloffFXORJerz@0ErkZapnI6/Ba/1w1TPJJdDuAFh4Vfbb@WptH6x/P4RP3q/ob1n/Ljn/t7xjHDo@l/bWGz/MSUtp/2ub8vV5X95/Wv9f0/i2tU/t5lXqh51/W31Gn9H7LzrK1puRDaUWSF6vUh9delP25hNXftv3A7Gl895Y8KvEi@bRif6w6lvy529V8puTbOrZfcC6rv9KP1H@JJd3v2v5Zd0p@ltTz83HMy1dj@wmfjRzQT5c8xqySb@Wx/YWLjPHYpf8PuXNeyfdSDzV@tZwl/3cZWo/@fnU@lNTSebFzfmwUZ32e13@3/ViLTOfP7nbC1ijofMIDovsx3VxfB/Sxy8jPN2y/bvRw@ZCGzsON35Xfx/7dJfjkjZpN5@kuQSJ/1LT9jBNe/dVGkmupFr48Tcv2966FZT/U55ba3Z9tv2/0DHmmXv9@Wz/Y2/Z/qcXSH9gFun@ZF3qe4/O8lGXpH7v2sZ7/nOmAgP0PBAbUH/NpZ5f0m33tv9il18pT9Xj8alVLP6pNofFFfMhb9RyN/0mcoLTi489d@tcpg1/XlyGt38f/Ur@S/laj6VDEOxyYeO2/IVjhoMV1CKP0T/vY7P8p61f64@lef7WMpV@i/stdN17pnwf9MmEPe@Xsfzq1ehSFqgOF8T4l@Bn/k/O8zO7hz1f755RA0vXL/i8CKOoPM0Wfj/Trs@0/q20k/bvM9TeuPunnZ9v5drBjuF4D41CM@jt23J2zpf/Xy0h@lDUu@@DE6Vfmi@yH2kWSPyWeZV/UQ9lhGPuDmIU/r@6/29l4cfAtOxbl/mtd9s1tdlRe1H15HK/kJ@Eh9ffayXkJ4fB3tpVcklf2FeqonZJd9tctxZ3xKO1V9lktN8l3Ak3qD5e7Pg/Zd3fYMYsbk/G/cYrfOtj92U5d1FxdjxnUHLKyp9MO4YuA5u8lSHX/Enh6njiTS2zJfq3lrvOvhGOzb9SOaIJf6o@Fqs9D9vE9dmKXuJP9XMecxw83lT7bAX4RJ0Nu1ecnjGaH5/N@34zHwbSaMofTkG1ymjb3Wo1Xt2mYlcN@2aUHqYbd94rMJUT3OlyLyirnTyljDts@spPtvrW/SHq/v3H4AI9ut8u3jJL1Bfvc83D4AZ/liNt3zfh9z4zjN56tOtlXvhnb15TW4l9Nhz8UP3TP6034l1iBQ4sOn@A5dhz42QkFP5xl/sbhl2psx4QfvPUtIUn3fBy@qcZ0fPjBheCw5b0e1ftmnO9oHvm7Xs/FPdowTfMUD7Vdwrx8vln7@ZzWj73Wj91mtVvjZ8Yj6m8cvqrGteutYZu3BE7d8@vwVzW23XcKjupXpW/EAT7iEa/5sou8Thb7zHH22inu8Jtise4Z94O/uXY0ylPrYHu3K7JF9lVj73zj8B9edbsz69C0fxOHahzuJx58zna73N/48Pe00xSvqHuu88ZvUQfDil/ejtd2Zjz5J65ZjgqPz33tvG13xJtf@znu/PjzaxO8cej3ePRROeSCf3Z8@l8wu/ZJvPqElO32X/Hrc3ujDxLWfvH1BY8Q3z7eKf3qvfHu958A90iIu68EuXvCxziq9e7viI//LSvSSIeR8HOtELvd0WLXFyp3zzPh67c2keZCvjn9qrTX7WBEZrB2oN3/ZQblmjqQ/Kud8DnRd/dcNoHvdZqDDPhW/Dw1KX7Ccz44xuNARQn8L3w/Hcp47867359gR8L/HJoasY7ZofjEcxww6R98oLfukAonh@aiznwHXVDSNV/9C8t0HKD@ZrdcY/ACvTi0g48qsZTl4E/vBj40loifp@bCTzgSQKrN4HXYEUi6BqMyMRgHoYhSu@cansAVmtd8R2F3oMZgDSEZEqpp3jt9dwfD@jbQo@Em0nz1Lz7QS/PJNwaJNNZRQjyP9zLgCPd8DTCpxnbYDn@P4zY1BQ7cPJEbJSSmQzfo4LoGoTISJDLgp9k8qcaxjCo1WwZMNQyKaTi8u0NKiRkMTbMaBtRUY8pMqsa2zBwxpKphMA6Rp@Nr6rjwr2qFuZ8Z@YxzzffCrLmJT/l5VkBALOvAQ5bPAkJnfq/9AYhKy/a775XRKA05ga2AjwZxXP2KAOkHNHHPpT45WlZaocNnd/qMG/c0A1Bi8VajP/lm@qycz76BrDw@T8GuOEyG@e5vtgztxqvreXBx6AlrGfqZJztP39QGc/QNxIJ@1ad1AOAw7rke3RE4JswhuGldAsSAg3Az@kY96HQYjq8cp9vTgTg8qC0IG/dcR3a@@a4p88@/2l8/e6bn/d2LwIUjfN/zlDLuJzzfM98nb3G/97ozb3rz7iAUHOl7Mj7yKSjW92QMF0pNCw7I4T4CkP4mc7EIWelXb@ZrxYekULK/qb8ESJR5X@zgFmiRe0ak6JuR9bNKTfDzjKwxvAHueWYdLvaQrplZq2t9ALdvPa/6j2OWK2t@7YDdytz3vig7P3HPnb2Dhe/I6Mn@KtveO27dL5h6DYKrRvZp2fPeufvJXt5PNBlM@O5vjiVASV7LhNpelhL7kxv1gJYk@41sqfPH0qYs2pnQ6v1iq5FRWOeOrvbIsbLL9w9Myz0PA@iIwFoe1hKzhMT1pPnanyZT5rflKuaXr1mRvXutRGo/@bwJKeqbHRleWlCivTtyHne@ez45C/bZiRjfnBcbY6gFTOaer8F3DWefsYq1MDWGJe99NhHQSmQ45xcRQ83FaTnjTgso73zn4CHQ529yVpba6tOzTGWfp5iW7rnnzD0jID15hR12Xj6pgbwl8Byw3pk53w9ORP1qRQcoazhAuRU9ATvY8ekdXeLsgPfOp2@U7WsNpHQK6yRl9VpLKbPXesu5X5z8RrfBbvQ1N/rPBXTXAsxzcPsJqO8@0aPKvvXz3BZd637gPgJ3DpkTE9M1b3S2msCA/D697tYCd9y8R/e7w2C/akQ/LOU0sfMRHRKhpbm4M3omx8XzwQfd8zL4rxrRV4kcPInJW6ctKzU97@i9eM999xPd@B6DAYVIdM81Cn6LGx37XoMCq2E9/EWIOj7/WFcn0G9wYFmV0uer0Q0QZLwd9G8BCdavZRe8RB0Up31e2w6lhnsGq2H74pWBqWu6bZASOQYNCjfpnsfevte0LVMNgwdR57ufcN4887JNROhcsqUatpuAHUj@CIrpnrfBhEYi6Brgj/rVsY0GOCFohWs7rho9@Ie7AoC4Bhe@nz34YujmG9uMb9l4RkG0ZrvyxToKJNm2JyaII8sYfYZCvCdYiP6BIfr40BD7g0M8wUOMHkDE@BAR4wYSUSLBmIg5A4qYBiEKg@qeObf8jW1zwgCOtCOgNV/ti8WXjHNwHqvN1xz7AV62t/u5CfDXDnHEv9Zx/yAZxgSwXKYR2UEN4FwxpLw14wrqNQw0AOHxtiBlDeWoA/r4G/tAqmHQIiaa4QxvD75BcUV9MwxexB9tSIQwFB/41j3P/n2zcs28@dV608/6el4n90Iq65o98jx75wnP98yn5y3Oynudmze9b979fqNxT0AkTwuq5BmBmbCOP4jwB0QJMqXZFVaN69lBKGu@@oduKa3Fc4px5Gu6HW7VMPhRqGP3PLpXS13i9dOnQZDVsFsP52ZwLtOOvxKBBkPa8NWv1vHqBQPjnrdBkdWwe5FZ8i7oxw5IzGWPc5k53jv1h0D4r52YL9bN04KNNowGY9/f2BFa026wJL4w7@WyZYKlee1MrYZBk/WP3a2C3xiP0yM3Rjd4shp22dY6ei1txrBTtxqRSLVdLaPGnJZaY9oxXFLaSEohuN0zISZ9s@1crobRlC9hXc3XiD1YDTuoq2FEpQAc/lWNj/u5kc8KThgVZDd4Naal@nzsKH9nkJUvpsf1N8eQ8Zo1nRfVMLpSOHPDi3oL5LzbYf9iaIwgjI4hRSOQdfx/H@jIkHaAwIYllR33fNB197yMtJSfw9eUou9fbQcfWNXpeTs88RK1DX7JAQx5R/yECXG8QJr9FtdBEJTebRTT4zBJNU5wTM2BlHc1Iy9fLAVDmQCpfQB7g6Neoy/fWpfSSaoxpKVUwwEd8AyewbILTr7ZuWY6KFSNnn4SNnoXcC99sxxYemUF6FfLoScQp3nm7eBUNW7e6zh8VY3ldycNwD1fIzJfAuvLEK3rMayN58SF/WSc9@MwWom613OxmwNt1TAy8/1CcdWYJ984WFe9GZ0JysvJDKXPp@fhgN@rQLURYA4JgsDzGkONd8/TKM0Xq13vtdf0WpWGbqBY1nMZmklyKEXmGDvm4GU1jNZU/oN7vq/3Dgr@BzDz/iphIduhGpGiQA39TTNq88WLqV8R1zIu7bWdUg0jN6vhUC3IKsuE0x3MfQm@uufhcG81pmVLSUXZTeAXLH9OQsb45CyjSrLI/noFDtWvlsPObyn6T3BvDky/RJw0F@c4dF2NZZl5Yg9WI2hOhZUMj3sse@/jAHk1PgRccwi9Gj0YueYge51sQXXehOFxFgZn1x2or0aQnaWcyhZ@77B1DORS9jLgO587dxoOUI3hs4nAj3teQXjeZUhBNY7POII826C9zGCpzY@/wXDSNcfAhWoE6XkDbcCL6TO3tGX5EwD5OeXteQyP6IRHjd9rBlBUw4jPGn9DLAAmSgdQEk1AgUZ9VsMwjWoc6RJ40OQnqcYMMnAY6tGB1ho7OA0GqYbRn1K13XNNab65uWb3/Gqv@UEO0/PpudfZuft98jx1wPoJb55ZGQFCHj6GvugdjD1sBsd0QBtOnmuGzxAN9Ii11wAb4GoaVWUPuecSfsPfGKTT5Te8Rjs@TjVKdKkaBvp0PEpJPzIUyHpQS0KSe95Gh3Y8Ar57LQA/zzHgqBorz3wMSerSYHXNNWipYx3p3d/AmjrmhManzgSteQEtNYYox84dfO29VKSt@ZugRVHIHsMxl/Gib/yiHYUj3xiiVUrcY8woJ6v7mUGNEt/zvdY0brQEvZOlhLBtycRKStY1drTkjpOtJC@M9jTcDCd68KPXgLQOotXJW89MMtdzfkvuMuizBUXam2FvvQOM1q9eA@P6b0jSbuhcNfaHJTW4rmPuuJ/A77p87/pmGqBXjSBKCX/5CZe98b1vg/w6aEy9F351vanwli0paO75BFkKAGYZqrqMLa2X0tnUiX8arfoYjlhP2owvHc2AxWoEYfpBGqux3nxj0GOXMqlfdcMiUd3T8zBwEs@XkaaYfM43rRNJT8iZ4J5X0KZjGZ7ZtT/0q20AJ2p9ELbHEM9qTGNOa1ClS/RxgzodH0wUr/UIztZAUnyymp3ZAjWdSa6sRsCope3mmjdw1dm/fnoArbMHgVob15BXHDF6npLlBsWWWvgGxRvYbE2S36vEkYG1cxmJqgxB97wzPli3Bgcfo1GrEfjuvBlnnZn@5gTx@3wQ4CfztdoPSLgHNdwCIwb@7l@9ARqvIFNxahiKvHrWD/qrnqfkmtfY@uDMa2Ydlv5iwLM8Z/rVCiR6fet57YCmAX1pxAjrOd36ZF@QMeeer5Gq1Qg0uzae99d@At7e0WSqEXj3btmnuwUAzuiOlmzL5Dpnv5c6ZxA5xpKepwxfw8z3iNzYI0D0PY1crUag6ntG/pDA6Z6X0aulAQTuvnfkWOkEBsTvIFirEcg8IlxzsW9A9fsaxaqcUMOon8jV0wLMJ7b5GHlt6H4/n3yusbxOKX2NZi1j1PD/akTOk2bqnocRreg8snMJ0Pm8ONNJBr1sfY/GWU5DqEbOHSlm@tU2slWZq@755Pw6x8kOiKgd9LfTIQj9Bf/9OGGiGka4klgyDAFvOU9JhjUI/DXKtRpOy8Ck9rl8uxM3@g3StaMGXX@T8x1oxQi43DrATXpIx@I8/sYJJP1uI15x3MtP0u@nbwCiaf7GqNcObMYJu9d6y/hwMkPwGH/jVJcBGOYxdt3JMAMojdHrr9NlqmE9Cly7nofv9YTKAk46sPWxgalvkPs0ChYvQjMMfj3BxS8n9lTDSNg6Cpz6U40V2oPjcWbfmf7gOU4fKplhPZPgkOYL/cGIcfSofGN9dRj2oYZRscpVNuz@td6Ldan1M1o3MpaYrdbYaNGfB3HT62@MjkWn1FodBOT07kqgU8/LCFlwUNuQ/m19fhD2MKj/JE26Had1DbAZwfU78Wu0a6Ts@FLDyGgytrwkyg7432jZaji9bODTcwL26wS0wZGiu@Ns0vO83faOkrTd8zBqlqwByZZq2G6qs/cJE0OQswNjWOMjjci5BU6mI3BtNP6bdDugUMbrgx/VXAjVoIyDxyl7o0eKDpRjf9OMoh2k4ehXKH/qh8CsExO6kbQDz5vu3rvt09GHkwsHfwmBhNMPyVJw/kKdW9sJDasnwyEpjAMIpHMgtpMch8SffnWcBlmNL4/iOlGyGkbWDm0npT48tt@V8B4qD6Nrx2hOx0TKO5@DYVU/IwhbMip05lbD/oRBbFLPA7jPqfRJCwWV6bySsZw4ijfJmSe4XZyqEf/GwBsWRg2jbQeheadrXPtJlJbvnq8Rt5hPxykbj/0tozSZ7iSN9mVtNKfJSu/0Na8TaYdC6i2Z/k4FGfb/gNpxMg3GqJ6nFBin09RZ9yYfxAm91TACt8S1U36rYX@UyAPc8zEKd6DQaMR4vZE8EifWrCBxGTCn1uB81Fys5uTkahiNq5CA001e@9lKc3SCczWMyK2GU6Cx5tLzcJI02D6vH/xRy2kq9vuJ4sA9LyNzS4g5FdspLPrVcbL2wBB3z9fp3NWwHxIXvBNuSjJ4X@ykhAPW8N7ZzUnjuBG9v/brtPJaGpGiuzvxvBpG6uJDdeoNqoj7mUm@KZvU@30vp7dXw35a1p4TcHYQu9U4ScE5b3Jwzk4Szm3JwkmCvbIxNT51yy8R536ZOD2pOPE/AyFPMs67ko3TW9Jxuv3Yootwz8MI3mqYIGAACPKvpgkE6o6Rz2eZYGCUQW8ZXna4ySyIuvoJQ1BQDfvnBw4vvVdZwD4valeZ2IIwrPN9mgkQCDL53LnNBAnjvo4XiNTCSUT9Dc1F3yG6GI47VMMEDOND9lbDBA3VcPyC1InrXy2je8WT4Z634yDAbY7vfozwHWSc@AkTT6mGCSSmsAzKOnpMMDGf5riMqDecqPQa6UsGk1Nn8NI4t6mbwAIvtrNtaiM7/eYZjhPN2pRO0EGIPi1sHu557XyzW67ZK786T/o5yQuqsc297sjdbwg60GT1hO3JM@OR0VsIjqlrXsfRZntDANKC@J0g25xi1R2Pm22EQATMk7OsPoKRNh3XI5vBiT1trRCS7I@gJF61CeTf3xwjfidp6f7VdZxReVvquVaqM7rexwQppHI554tgpJ4QILOzuF4TrNTJ4rhnNUzAUg0jfsWM4p6H46fznSZwATPu7DTsFo3qu@y9nO82AQxYKu2miXtXs/Mex3M1Fu75GvE7le6rNLHHceFqmICmZLI1mQmjg@4lHUDXvCawKTvBiF/xtyT9zHHqapgAp/7fiN@Jnax374l317owgc5EwDlLbZtgZyqg9lHCuOdjxO/EHnDq212hm3pM4DNHNJmJN8LfNMfxMdYle6diZC0sM05x68YDTJaPCWiGEb@T9Emnzc03eXPTBEQkyk1nzi0TFM2S@De5czPJc8eI34krTSOmmIB@dU2ANEcQvyU1TJBUDeMl5mwmUJqA6DRfM@fgxInub7oJmNjRy78aJmiqxkrP0wRO1TDilzhEczrfMg5E9DrueRvxWw0TRJUKYDwJ7hvpAJMkEvd8TTAF64U0B/wc0iVkWWlUVwiqamqMb6mGCawmh7hmBxCTOcMSXcJN0v3NfHLNNEHWBG7lfpZ1pEn2mO@1TbAFQD/Pc0zAVQ1rMpNwo6mErvE/ky1kOqHHiF/xCjm9sBlHhJNmOQHxNeJ3slSTophx3sMEYkpW1FyAI9Ts4K99Pqoi97yM@CU/efmabXzUJBfK/ZyRno@5zaawHrrmmvmspLMRv2I/Mg1SM16rGmZNkw7nrMjXnGpk9SYvsptxDfif1/wZ5mObohz4CJXc8zLidxJp0VycbRxaNcL0dhLhnaT@@JtrPFs1whKHHHKW5RMOufsYFzdvM8NcNYz4RXOUvUNg3s98u9npprJvdM0wdx1eMcsfTh33PI34rUVj3jsymS3HSjuQjTYBCbrnY868ahg3SMKAbL1qGPErJimndj7GH9bXZuMjDOtsS1JXlD75vDvEU91MfktEQ7pmmOevGsZDipzKPU8jftezzBFYDeMql3R/9RPEL94A2cvVMD6zlp7ZB6sxk3362O5epKwM56M@ss1JTHUGawNtpBTUoCzIVTXdYetG/C5Q1/7VMO5UFFrueRrxix3eneq6jF9dwgqpnz2T7VpL3@muxzjYBfpNbwrIzBmvz5OU18d42sWedNJrM@K3RuCRn0T2gXp@Qb7om27ErxLVTfM15m9EX0mm/b5Z3zXr@9X@@tlfz@e71/nufr/nuXnC/j2zggv6puW9esubAgu4TtXNaPSe8SE8oBHrI2PIMbo@OjL3PDPyIA80F/heNTtsZc1XjyazMJz9zcksl2Xlee83K2F8a2M8WS2jZf3gI9TzgDDRExILcD5wzzrEgNd7YV0PpxBn9Y5vPWM0anykLOualV0AIYBGdQTxW2Ixe0c5/brmZn@Nmx03vz0o1bM5L1n7dOmsdIay9zKrMLRt3ft9SavQNcMygbMlecyRG9U4yWReli1LJ79@tS1/FrAN93wso4R61oiVJJIcWxIcLWxx6pndqJGvPSN5WAqEJSRZ0pKZtduT11zzvf3NsKRdgmHrV9PSWAR07nlZYoOtMKcmyGrnV2/L@bWC@K2GzwJQ2NM52tfnBTqlThBx2jkNu/mUEVLbdHevTyIIcnQ21dnr00qHsEYekJ/mYg@fcWtPn3rrOwer4ZORBxy@Zvv0XHBOuZ@z0vP1mQsqXKcw3gCdy7hrdVKLeS8UfD7NeWOd79XwiU/oRTpANawV1Gq0noAmKs1hlVl6zUs6rV2IzM89L2sgINCP08yPtZRqWG9ZH@K3GtZtFvgvXUPy6jEtoDUi8QM6Pf211lQN61HrdmtW1bCutW7yrZa4fPTNtIZWDetsS/miLZSD7nlb01tArjViQg/pV9f6IbEqZ5c/j3XIalir3E@znrl1xrWwGDoF/rV2up9ufXUDA/KvhnVawvHpeVrvFR@IMrMFdtWv9pNc@v0l158n2fZnJf3@tuTjX@vhuwXxixU3TajYrL2DQpM@TzK@9oW4FtUzWYfKQ2/ddgE8Ttpf2LSyHfaXPwja7/qbZYuD4NLyr7atEtE3uudjywW51nz3a@umxs32DmLNz/w220RbPF/XPACymzYQSb37G9sKIgPJqA3STiPGAaIxBJujUQW55Z6X7bhdGt8xg8C2rYcHYz0fyaR7vrYQgVbIZpQ7Sr/qzXZlNfbHPGDbEwqCY@6Bbvt0k49m9oHYsHizdBZsBUd1zbLlWw3bwsqNcM/b9nI9sS3oDWuJxlBB7Y8K08QGjy1xZLFJL@Hs0ezg5NV8jWgyG6euv@m2@vEGhFRz2DMgdk33PO092GPZn7BhsdHzQFczTZsQEk@C0SZSuPZUIOrku0BvkA6wZ/wbG@eFxkfQRF3z2itCqof8JHsG8buxZjXy2HGai7ID5W@phj0w@8tdgh0j3@yea/bNr85IP8nt3iT56V74YHX39dhHtNEC9YQrfqTSMu1Z2gJn6Zpu71M1Qmi6hjWZzXk8PxoIjdhaITZdy54uMZW6521vGDkAngtkpdkkbkhOd6JL1QjR6W4tVKftIzt97Z0T@alJJbo9eNWwTw@Hu1dUTYbX2A7il93qdQhnhammt/2HG5ep3n3Hx7jhUtX4kJ@tEYNPVWNIjEKjesJBsMm20shDiqi5OK99npvA/vNRtJqkddhTuskd8TXT3tSN8HM/66TnbR9sNeyV3QTo/DzXnluxvpoS47F3F6yYZQucHHrT2@wTphePxn3tNy5D057kTSq5xhAugx8iWfc87ZHeIMs0F3fZaw3vhmXmjT1ITNty9V57v6thfziKtVksnvjM6zwJz8Xz2q/Oi5sJoywpyfnzfFwZz7B/Hl@12TSeaR9@NcK38cTPfzCgxEgBIGOF8sOcHc9xvODgq3TP1zGFo5wI8X40xx2IuYcZJOdgNT7ukO74xSHo5V8NxzgOKBsT7k7HQQ6Mn7o7aZ/mqt@OnoiU1z0fR1iOWGN0zXUU5ihTZZmAxKPxNsduDnB8jRjqj8bw7Y74iOfXdCTDUaEDIFtzUddKSwFEIL3lfFnYh5Cmv9k71xzHpPgn/SRudWSHienkcWzrcHM9D9wnesL@9rCdvI6RHeXW6JrhONoBJGTGlMTaquHo2zFCRQ1H6E4ZPqZ5ASfhno/jekBTPRc6QUSl8jgaeL744AG35W9exxChXfG8j@44YzXC@EKer@5VosXrB@yjnod4VcjpQ/sytqOc1XDcs7arI6ElPBwbPSPcQ4dMW41PySyv@dkcYy1x5KiraJjVM25ZM8D0EwqY0cMBM@5HAvOxwKwWGpjlKPDBjeVfbUeKxezsnq@jyYgIk8EAMdLzrMcxaJJA/MyY63oLET3pmu5YdjUc3RZZtElmhiPgR@aWrlmOksM/Y2KYFcTvgepJI6/ET11zHX9HDZfMVIqFeiZM5G@a4/jYkKaj3q9j/SU739BVd@MBSos3QuBIaOlX0ygCUVq752WkQal3xh4coQn0q2N8wkGwuudrDAOsKqbbVjqkCXKMfBBLtilyXqMjADK7lASJjZqdGkDZ72VVWIpWw7iLw0D7mmVsxiF1yf0Ev1ENIzpg3em@@zXqg1NCPodzg/hlkOWXOLJBdM1rPAkwaukA4vJWzwQQND4k2mrEdBboV8vYlXPD5XbkOdM3x4iXI8CMfnWNirkfTkaEP/6mGUtzn2Z0DQNoUpoaVLPUPN2YnKvMO10zjNu5COzTwjge6nGjfS6Ktchxnm1EkNLgRZ/DLLnnaxyRhueYYchYo9LzjD4Sibl6BjIr1h7xOOiabhTTrRuZ6OdD/GLAmAqoLaOhiGeYLKjkotmDWjBU1TCqqo5M46wuaZB6npIEpiR6wzl4SXXTW7xvD4vRe0Nr1Gd4jsZHfDR2mJCmsWEXga8xJKFZo0qQwT1vY8zQtM23BIBeswPYVPP1UcRWw@i1K7izSJJeI9ywZa@p3vtH9t6Ni7vCyuqaaexcNYymEyG8e15G3JUpbAzeBQerNxXsTP0E8cvCkoy6YJ40YrWIJceqYQSgOOZN29SNErwYrCZuGkYScrJIZt6PG1MhX3@zjEisC4xRvOKrbKGtd8/XyMZqGOsIjl1S/c5mPGQ1LPlrMxkziRqs06GMAuMqr@CmLUz46nlOozHJyh4myV9GbJKV61ooSHX3fIzzvHjYNRcwD2h2oHJ7PnL9FLAxgvSCUfY1r1GmpegZd4oDxD2vYWzqXdNo1UuAZpmsyohW8fWHuN@oVyLhOt8B7OrEx5S4prAKh@sF1WmSq2aErViuNIbKoPpKAKhn5Szqm2HsbimXRvNWw/je@7HT1bFoDHA1Tq45xgmTUZF@giW@aJzLHFrGG9/zPQ86lp4QTUg9C7G7TLDl9zrD2OYLrtJcXME/l0ac8cHVaDqubdR0CUjjqO8J4vcCZjAl12P0NfnQ16Rc33zd6KJkqHpO2U6@ZmTea7Fu9xOuYbw@3eRf3/oBn6DnAXKrJ7zBmV9p7/rmGovOojE8HapPI9ZphVKmJLVx7bQMdW840s1I8OgYal@hhjCKzZmiCmX0pczCk63WiLqkFMPzkcsAg0i5huf2FHAgsdm/hZ7L/bX2lX1oEQFQks2vNERvX7GIvlM@ogUIXK3pnAJaTjOAvMyZB7QsmlxgIvc4Tlmg5SyG9ghkckNzZv6J5w1pdrWaMyKa0Bsm7oIR1rxqSPXnp3hFONKGxS@LxDkYtG5Iv1Dd09/@qMHQMXLfM0Ig9l5nfdDaoRnryQ1p4EZCRgZZrN@354ih5TyTxiL6yNiGs1Fo3dCfAf0LH9tqIUnryWypVo4@2Nqc/0Jrh3CtX2fJKFk4cw6lc75r/SNva864geFtfRRvycuhdT8iuOHsnWrNN3RxYzrHx1xwucd2JhCtE@q5cZwvhOukhaBuJKsI1rgRGrvZnHtEa4fsbr7OUKpW/yjxZnceEyZmD3HeHM52qtZcodf74al5lFTp7/b8rotqJU66r78bshpUoNyXehN@FmJ4fj4Ca37m9X7vsaLywWf65H3X2BkDEjw9Lmt9BHzEHDx@2BahvNs347yiirqASu5xb@YIb7Dnbbc3c7nbzfzuj8BG4fl8FxW5WmNmveBWS3/zW1dKJfV3u2X97X2yJmsrZJ1@qjutnfV8npE1ftqTdX/a/oj53m9/QFESar6@s49OTAro@p7stzNDavNoMPzdfrJXocPyXJ7Ts6e/TEaJ1ex9oum@ruR/ZAQQ@fD9BYBM60a@gIn3s0BP6ee7McFcsCala1aKa8DZG7nG4blCIPhG/t2vSEeJWGd@wir4hrSvlmFL6ZuWYh8qhhOuwfeGuA/tzBx8z0jREDaX5bgWvin2QOzlu5XiI3L157fnDYHfkxxYOAtTxEQ39rO0mNJNlXj8zCTzhdTwPSnH0/oMkR@WrZn8OBVM5dfmV5anxcRvcmqYzQ8AWSgRz5vyPO18BXrgSjGXIj4b0yu@jzOLkSN2PbhAUNgT3xSLIX5xc92wG4OWc5lhWVxfxbrljGdaN3XryJcLP@NJ8RoVH8o9rt0rEDw6x5pWiuA0sdObkzGuGlrO127w0JmMBto5s@PAMmfKGhU28j3Q3z1HfTtDnJZdSE2Vfjy/XzEAWs42Jztt5DpR9ZsNsqVIkIomhQ8yri1azm@HLDLFhqgCZLacNgJobvCrmS8HOrW8b0n5mTJMcbm5IFPucVP8CFUg5QDRHTzOZEJ57OdXRAkes5QUnHEFVmuYD4DFlGJM7WMNoLWyDoQr8nUnRZ2aYtJhsgyFDuZcuCPX8xWHAjbi54OfOQWk3o@HcvWvyFQNY9gqV1yn1ZoznJZrfftjrRvmy7Vn9hHRVI8zbvv1U6TK99hx6UL@9IRrk9PDc7nfHkbOD/hMa4e3ExKwXDdb2D13XM0ugJV77BTzqtYJUygTGLLO@4ZPdKcmGAwa6/n4Ot8QkUJCFcbOd4Wu9PSPwfSMJ6SmUsjD7DlCfUr6iMf@c82jV45wpp7TQqNKBpTnkqHy/N4f/tX73FCy3rbC0noTMoBd1bwhtPZX7GuYXQSh4vCDxMsOq@gyLYmLguUeCWW0prCvr7umOKFl1hNcLtHhoElK3VLSkkyfKTiTOUgTYnHBMfNuoiSZihOqXLNzErYxYScqgDk8n/3Rej7HzC5CzM5cd83/QhjflDAuZham0@YwEkhhc8k0@IWsb7zQTPqZW0JSCFbz0tAyVY3YUc0o/ELWZpLPFo4bWqa9qdY1E474VZ@QpT7my4FRdX6Uqq9ZdZoofEy8KhJc/3aYjqf9MPTQ2t93a3zX7fb9dp@vv/Nzj/t@9703zwI3mp@vJ7ToAm9fqbeddyMlOeyto2UMlFCr/vr8xkoKvL9LyLNBJpZxJo1w/RSPyz3uzhyRh@Z5G61lLkcLm/L7hWI1a1kH5OzkuhFG5XfMnjU0Pk5lSltlrY0dVuVSNt6sydruWafjfmtXDHr6DpS533e2cCtDAzNTtzXMVLQcuoagNvzK75ymtKIVhuV3BnANy1U4ll8Qlymid8KyDEmL97TOAt9DCS7@roVpuQ5sh@chvQ3XMujYrwjfCNuy6lL5WeSc82@XKcBcrC/3OIYN0ArnMqqAZd0rZTM8upGJAMctJ6HUtex8JZXNrtsNZ3AhwPDrTtOc0Qr7MiloPcS8O/zLLOLM@T5hYH73NcyiAcryufAqtaR9RQZ9jxPIBty94WGulqncsA/DxAydSN4Danu/21mhhYM2xOcb7hCfeSpgmHvcUMwpB9FjiuPX44xbtocZOGctSXRhZb6BuFRrfLzMdPf8FEf0PXB95bv9cTNTwyi/PR878we9aSLlMLsvIifkwi0sfTiBPwrij8uvWqH365iu5vh9Aglqok80y@@zovvUiIY9sBP8PCEwDscg6l@KMraPiVCcGCbp1WnmUo9vKAyhOra@1n8KNOL8Pfluzu@6FYZE1flKfx@PIvGi7743bIvVCgFjhyfPz/z@1FZ@3zA39jfQLhTV8DuW1Arlo4pRhmd5hhhS6XAeUxVx82/3x@L8nm8@3vvxOEOTEkrm52Ny7i2Elf03Luf6Scica1TC5twDhavW/OFznveH0PmH0XmHSLMjF/x8/YRuU0U0w@ociF6jEll4nUcLdSfKeJidR4DetD5uZ9RijymJfx7nEeigC3R@zNGhFO3kcXnexg3xaLU@juf5FUmFrDcszzOQRlofz7NSitpX/NP3IEbp@875cT3PFdpUWJZsX/YPalmtE77Vrg1vkuonrKwkR1v@qbCo77He0Ll2eK08pisQUGIN4YHta8Z2JpXC9jTkBZbPfe1wykJWYDnef5hniUxY3ncqZvg6cE3@rXhb1N8OIBzS7HDdlogK/W21wogLgtfnkQqihm97h0q3g0Px@@4Twl1imfZb4M3PWJ0nTL2QVvi87EhWj3NJVp@rKrbqe5RkPSnAOsMNXCdj6IJ1RobF@9PhOkdevruhHu5Qz3zc3iEoViHXsHu/oTHuBJbC7x3oM9zf4T/uuK98jzvDklwTHuJkdAf7pUjIt56jIrG5RyDZTSluZtZGLxohEQ97swj3QiPew/GsKhEm7n5GmKDHE6i45ZvZs5/9fN/tn@vO/H57v/7wkKdo7fPdtwXC7iT3FbbyUFuruG34ykcIsAdmZVjNV2iyq5VxGR@0HobzjJ@S2k0BjvpvDnD4R00C/n7zMZCipgF/38zbeAP5Rw5nfkuF@4rvovLku/URhsOOlt@ej1b8/WEaf@9HPl7HVfjISeH188FaNMO0/hGZi0/H342P7lyUL/7t/EjR@w9POlhTjx8uAI8pS9bjTBa3xx6eBd9DHNf@rv2Qtb8//O39N0r3H5b38UP8Pj8u@LE@enhVpXB/@yORx7DOfe9HNe/ETbc@Qvr5w1E/34@2fvaPyX72j9x@jo/vngBg6OTXx4o/10eUP3fkKTt6/1YEOZzyScGhFfnMEWCZDX7Fcnx8QPQmMGS@G6H5ryfJuaCE6vT3nR9AF3ym1JGSc4bMaZ89A9o/PzPctiGvbzm3RBzwUdznfBPZvcdlf9UNYHz32ThUkcjXrZRFgHzX5@r4Uqmakp09R/umxMIAFea5PC2FGMYPJ7VqDua7nnN/nKR4yVFk/WCcldIPQMitRwz46vws5Cn7@c5NGQkVnf6Y@FNsQgnJft/7piRFLZzoOdX6ClaX3ml9aIAc9ZjeFb0JhT@Fr@@nXw2ljPm7Gz0Me7SFzP@Jvjaf0Alg3kavI3n4u65H/6OEqftTsWwz3RNMMPE/7n0z/z875UBIC7beOZ@kEAKIi3465QPXdXihUn77TQESFeJObYGeMiXAolKGuyW1kSyb6M/K7M09dvTsSeFpU/pTOvr5KhN4fudPRRUoQ0@@e6PfE5z3ehG7gvt7A2ynmkHsBeS01x9ZmrYrlIPiZ34/@4MY/01xgyd2yoRzLiUQWuyZ2d/sj1ppsXsoz@Z9hFJl@2iKhvGnOLnv0XcK3EyBqn3dSRmcWYeo7bKf1Fn46GK/lXRJSZ1qxc6bo6fwjgqfpyLDTHkekMq2G@dISi9FGWJfkmOT9xg3duh0UrtrNsReBeZs@aei6r7HTKoxrdi/Ez7WFF@fsZNLovSv9MOOPT3BC6b4w4ndPWdSoF2wPfUfWkojIU57qkS8KaA0V4@9X6f1@xV5H/ELgMryOVN6W/wHQnj6mddXxWkK4uzvbvwR9aAp/zRJs/G47KSMKzvP/o25e0pJkWBqPwj0Nz5XVWje94BD1HO0d/wqPJ3PaRRp@19I7M@cnyd@mjrXUwhLTLT@Lbgn93e@ClrzJMWeahfxD1EaMCU@xJPh/gKUpxV/0wSZnOIXT/xS8yb1nxIZ8V9NarZ6/Kj27jHVpvVvZ/xhQlP4HnfFbyZwi@dNCQP@7U2psvVTvWyJjcnftfjrRKTmUhOE2lx94qNKoBX/31JBJl@34idEU/YzE2hNvQtKDLsEBurGSCUPg@ibCpK7dkZ7vxIg@D9cYQPrxUU3rI@45sf7lQFJmTha56cQSPynEImmFEi78bOu95tzKmCtfNdWyoHAJZ4qIqG8AJ6cdbVkVPq7GT@wEib9fKX/eZ0SaHi/giPxK683VBw4uON/Xr31lAbpKcdH66Y4SO/xZ5MEmfIgfcbvXRpV9iBZj96XC3ZEz1s/8aMvtD7P78etjR/jSZkQgGC@boS6hHIn8d/XwR1ZskS14@@mAfdUQ0k8YI3tIocEUSKvSjAYdE8r8QWSI26Ko7TEIaC5/CmhknhFHX0uukgrcQ3ogS1jSdTIfKg4rr87iZOQgGiZvSBY8vyuT7aXkpa4y1qhoCGlKfGZJZs4pVpyfpQwMxCfqi2J9yzSAv18aycutD5qHEJFiR/VZS5uSX2XxJmqZUA@Sy7nIOPos1EJg6kIE8oeLJzEt7B1QnCHudpHT3Hfl1YJJIX1zQu37AA74YIXbRkw25NKKwMb9XXaEt70UkdqXxgSNEQoOwRpFxU3bKsUEn8MxDmyEN82v1LpytvGhx6pcQ@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@FX43d6j6D74hXuKub44yiFcukaBvUsjAxuXDW@mmoBq/4T4Sypqh/3J2Pal0NDunyO/qyoC9BZmF0eYH@BIX6FIaqcJp/al4@KDICP7K3jFUgIsXpvQHKlkwMEBPoylUtisy9VruC3pB@yPd/@41UAc3e94QGxeztrEzQG4Uxjx2U9YpVkpBAL8zkQlcCnXuBv/quFaFM61UFIIqkl3j/JLTaz5w3nwEg14d4nVlYIgMFwMAN4p9vLib064EFz6nhgnHwuqwnf9fhi4A40S6258pEUSmhDzPlkERzqZ40nEP/dTAn86lxBMDjS6eIdSLGHXKckKMcnclifxEFN0USGSjIkcbTvXpiPr834OkHpr3KhE/WL7AQh9AIs5lZTBUpLTV8v90aED0sRTSKmnkqfzI0uWrdBTxsGlpKCQ7bBx25I7iyJ53Ocjy/MwzfDUYrWjmhCKdtmSid8WrHab8YBdAGCUSbDxgEwj4Y4T0ER1Akr39sXFaoTh6BrjK@ZHLLi0Iih14@nAAQWmrPcYb7Bjy@38FewE7000Wf4tw1NLSpBec53MMcAJQeSSLIZXU0ERj/EmpI34XxwLqXJBTldJZql0J7kMHfsrXsRXcDOpzClBpoIxz0@OJdAMHmlTacnHHJwQteUgepKoQn8wSNgkoJQiFVTOmenMJD8yOhiKq6bsnXhirvjmUUxTGFUG9kA7TEyWoloub/GVsaUE2xwnpZM3uWy1TyN6hWfA/OpfgQchV1XZLyNd23uwRVcA1/gOcaGj6dtLQhM@k0k2j96CGG0N7vuJhodKSHcsp4LBbA9Z14MP1TnJom14In6FPKMM2sfhwHl4xIt9nSZUD60MhOMckYaQKclHMMClEUpzEEMgUsCEJ7iGFpHMcLFRRhfghCPNVE17cAf/FnWornAOzCeOaIQt@Nr2pBzIUk1vsQu4TgSn9jzPT6k5zOnt8szJViC5WEvZ1T6OyZFTUbMUCBQ7eB1dsv6pIw6DwDOlxS3waDgQiaHW4qphdq2Po/pjDyHa4EtL4m8qXn5Ff2D3Zne@H1biqBrjhOfeE4PWQt7PMSz@FWk8hN0JeNcEcYzMm1qdB@owRGR4jURzy7hfvxNRARhlknOOcXG/GA8nlcrxDWcHkPpDJtbzU8cRhmXYSL@lSJrqfkjOisUILAXjY4Vz9oL6fJ28t87Ftw1MYaVEkFSwmupUZ4OSvJYZbuxUUhLEuG5gxZwsVhVQMetNDSJl7eAon18FXtVMAcRvHlCId2tKE4hnGZMJz5JbroS0YG9k1T9RtAV0xs63F/fCycfrpCwF9ENUAp2pKwyHm5OQkxBRI89uGh9BEEbPaD8EPaCsoDr7nNgP7nM9YIqPkbxQn0FIOrpYzzxZdSlxwwRh/wZZR5kvdO1DKWbX3GuqoVq6XerByFe8IQH1bu5yzsJ/EkQesCuUl7tTzJlCHVTvnc5BncKzL9K4nfVIauStTRLsLnQ9talKRfpKmAPXEM39GwIcEm0XDMBm5RgutMI@2ynW@qKN9s/jJoCa9Foz93e0hj1VE11KNGozmUknoBrcdpCvOd6H3Tqg9L/GjV7SfuD4m189b4SDKtyYIgXstriYQiF@YNEQk45rFykECPOrywshRcivmb/5ULv4MlyvC96GOogIF11bfy@CqNaC6eM71GlHMNN4f6iRg@7sZG9hwNCKKAFmDp8Hj8T4ch2JoJR0BazWUoZ1idkGxcDgwAdUB6T/lrYPIN9BSbrUUt7g97@q1mV5URD6nLlTY2mQGDBTAOZQ9BxN6Au11jDDc/955ckxhvGdfF8lR5UYYdftxAxRYkExtXiTSH8E4wM6JGLvodwUkBSzu4@ugMZHFkfeB/wEMR9Kxi/wPchPZz1u1ZL/CQKC9YB/dIcenaw4LIs3GwArvE7HxC9R2bAfOMRT7elRiPQhFVMrHu8i8L8djFIHGw9K8onqO8TD8w5nh1Fhtt6YkH4KjBB6IkkuZLSSouQbbJPSiPOH2GlKtQGa7lKuTfgjd98rF62L3q0H/Yxw0gjQ@mr9ns@LzPtA7wx0yolmC5TII6O8uTQRiSEjRBdH2MYaiu5AYO2301T2c4TbtKua2U4qAHsbFwzqnCmfOsbHB1Im9gsze4qSgbKpxbJhdgvv3gYH2XdAfZzZJVNQGMyGLfiK4iQuT3UgNR0Q/rpMB6AFaYzTRdOobYZ8SEoKtjxVb1TawHJ0qxb3O61wwNpdMo@QuQKzSymQS3iCD4JV2g1uHZduq0VUB@VxacIUx32OGDbjgGDL9i99rAaLJOwRvkzqzKJ/fC4GqI9Rf85rPgU8EewA02CTJrVNme9CqCKEWTCGfvdSjbnWgs1ZZGjUqSIHiosrYjXd08IYVQopdX6xZUxv@lC6FroI1wHDdsSI2aFGva9in0/qxzTJwzqua9xv8lhqPUxFpG29XZFcr49IEy7aUtngb79fGiFV2b76i5gJ5MScJF3CBMRqfIxoolYGjF/9w65Ef41TnqWPxNqhE1VxHK3EJOweHJ6ERRKHhHmtk/rjsiil4CgL6/Pxl8lH0g62het6ADt5IZyJQbQVKH4dJHaKOmGiL9WiZBNww5NoohQ75cWbIISJ7VNz4XLKhzMbU9/nTy1FnOqD88XF7hb510xPSjaK44zwRLePBysTzSYVZa@OmH6C7ZusHmkM4eAufYBs5icVSEj4BuosR5ScVGspmDR/m72Bn/02A2fVP6p0gJsvcCoyyj6J1TEezk9Bt6ESE4AGgnVlY@A08nkDvFY0Sjg5n99qAj7PDyuAvKeioXTJuVcBCvZr@KWw3eWSuak0QSKocuJc@lGVgUkZa848XQK6d@geY5zXZmSaPuK0hyMLDLQL0A3JE@z5xCzwjNYGYqpdjI9DSYLq9lCUna6U6hmyFJxyr9gAQ8GJEFiUgltm7mFHUojWmBSVB8VNQTLYilDAdr0faJksAVAAcFQqdxk4sDahzVehw@5ZKXv84vSH1fXLTxBA0qUMk5A3oKY8UOMEH0j1pPmDAe2yAO9IcJQE1kOuf4oZQmXytLAtviIL2X2nHPBWPZjnp8YSTkNSXOdPHWzOy9rIbyolY4yg0E8xIn1JaxhhM3H9WkYTpNRPZmS9zuFg6x/NG8TbKLwhlhcHLO5G52jiM8fd8ybvF/@ZRniHaxNI2N2pL9gFaGALJW9XLCSLnA3F0aZmZivD0wZmKZ3o3ft1mg@c2LrVY0WJ6zflHfdJyLWuV45MN84PPw/lhnqI7Ul4KetWAdwntJ646wjtproL9cAILAYkB3FZbZCpjHMRCCGvVUPGjDcw@ZZs4/iVpsyJBzVWbCri39DLEomfAVCQbikLI3Waasuj2UUZxv4RoGInBwDIivwicb7iIiUy6oCmVYutytDBFQOpONhyNwUwD5g1lYN2iVTcRrCBrx6bB5oTzqIvY@tVQTCqWjh4i/LyCl4XhREucHCir/fJC@1lF0DMpUUHJXHB@L6Jsk6xBN4W6IN4wZ337NoRe@GcIKTaXY9DfkdnipJKxLrdYQIhf@WAF0x5R0UXXi3Vrww4yLjayi3xIiCFOA9XigJrB0owpJIDBx8@/fd82Tuit39UhSprcSp7rYf0E8lx8XX1qDdDaMGNTmgFZCvzTjUeHfOgHN3AB23U1ma3IS9mS0H7V/naYVupJcXWLtlk9wtv3Wr5ARE2tR/1LEwO5jOS46puh7ntqn54uzF1UmAT0CHybPZUGZ5kTIo3IClxlH8cQqS5wDrAWhR7Ix6VWLTkw7ApPMXVCZLms7ZL25Pr3ilVeLYvPh7zQZIrBJIJ@g7z2CP6YO3@KqkLY1gPfGKHQGlMEDIE7@LMVozLdtJV3oh80l9oXFxO/MyVDQ6KhYDgVkMuFX9mM5JcWccqAtWTFfFCf7W3Dfof2tSc@dBi1EGLOLWJgE6ESH@2h2vL14pDMxUFiYST/fMGN0QGdW087LJrUk9ot9ERHWQV1JzSCeNNgiNndB26T2qXk4NIwdONSyKEAmcqRruD/JJL@JXmPsLV1X9TXNqFc5B97djwxYnM9g9NP@7gZr9VeDDw0ANf/0oLk8s0VV1pfk8AqavoZExsxJ96kgTm2HL5fZSynA@4Ke9ZH8HCLtt7YlqHD73uQF3Sn9wW6qRT6MBIL3IOcEui3yX9az6qC9MMNaUcMcvuNa3NlBklvdGmbx3XFGK@4ckD3ECU/6OXf3Wk60Cwlw3PLfvjp0CwYCl1gFyfwkRR4NfZezm3gdORzHss2US@CEnJ869KGNg9hB9TcZyRrSUwuyHYr6IJ0DZ8GTAUPcF6OnCweAjQc1mHHxIe7xJScmeQ8EYPkdVZ3qkiJiw1YTSsVX1wlpyVwtwbZbrm@ulOAiG/T8k9@OtdiZNx6OJNtecPEDUkHz0IPHlVWW8pb76w3zlGz8fTcKiIiYa5XRa3M5EzUFiQRfaJp1plE6AdtFX76E2GyAOTVlJqKRDma45hJB3HBF888YHgcbzbzHqKTOD@AYYbzMP7qOb0DkfyRAxRfuXD5pZxJMqy7oRJpAg@wH0tPgDtIUDe9ZN4rozAJvJ4k85BmTc0yHKGdkXoob1wDUGOOYhVt41aXI2Lp0opAIgcQLd3nQw6dC4Zjguyh5ba8biF4A0JQSa@Q8yqFrMbOqUDiCy@QqjJgEoSNHHc/yhCKH@GHBWy8Z@xU0RsQ9YD@Gx8JUagrsPaepKjs4YU4lguy4RmYANc6x2oy6FY2kdmwPDVMLYf/BmIXJ2zZo9UOj4eu2VKRDgUKFp75aYK5YLwAlm90J@is93nK6dMrNlJWFahIOuCbfB9g2oS4rv0k@GI/tbJA7lO4tUEgTltRzKzKZVLdu4Su4qjgHUcADr@ClALUdEwaFzRFQjMJavBLhr0L4JnhOqz6YARkHOyjR@qEVHiG1xIj4tJacW9I8XKawlfldMwUykTKSfRE4Doa0af2kSuSFHPtYcyTU2KLzlI1KiFK2SxGQGMfelvNSF18XoTIn/JocFMBQcUxycBI2MJ4d6Fwl@Fso05Ij8DnUYjBDWDlOPUoST0qErcYZwSM2QZuv2nThxOcfQTsx1Aajl0OH5UykM8Ni2CUrEFklwdnCAQA9Wv5jUYc2IH1Jr/QqZYA8CcUrBaHjIwXS6froOM0CG8M4F5H0GmwioGsAkMz2uqfJwAQhJ9PFsE8wE5rJFSsrg9CXd8lBlSWuE2OaGEOTiIWDOumvsIRnPCEDUEPD8/@VUqcvjAx@MIGf5TzAbqC7liFsUfYLoLc86UfS74uHY6uEe8s@aMvHi8AVaQwiCfgBI7UH9M839wUkuTtheR@cV4eFLQGkZ0FrvjsTpGUByWRXX84vv8lrQN8B1YygjrO8rPg/3ZbV2xQVQrOZBrYpZEvSEx/vILARQQ07Vmv0j@BtbysUdxeMPZtR3/ZcsvcTflvAfLB9Vd8kyuCpYy6ckIXypc3ORgTbVajIj3o3OmutRLJGebyuclUFC74J6fcoNby00qPnnZKv1poaFsZU5ll2ITnw1MfClNW9uUmfn4oKBXBfFIXp8ZRnGdbKGSPtjaIFQyk2S6uySzkOifW5NsIOwAh1IIGm94U7/w2cEJz3AfYwDkPgXMNLbhq8ydaludmxJKW5hQ6iycMAWQyPACmtX5QB7GVSEEZwsLX6MKhx@zMOKX/MbHwYKj2NyYKfVe2s8Rebs5ah8Vdt8KMV6vsUtZTGwtI5prLiBLvmFlx@YCK/t88CjMw8mR6uh8E7803lsrFkt5dTjf7DQAoUSySMsBiE@35HQdBDtJE9RBJRzwwROJv@BZDUffgNYUz95K3gNvAD5gxTkPTgxPB84FV1F9Cdff9rEDyA1at/st2o@7E9RFKhRRM808zNZ@Dv5/oBL3J39faOfHgm5rzkLcDZdfqTxT/JeOvuE0c3Uy0xRcUIfibHdZ5UVSN5URXWaQ/VYLDR7PEeYvornskECPqZEwxB@XCjQUPHtYVopHviqliJeum/bmKAoid5@L0XKO0eNnjB/2GXaTSzbD9EvQPg6GF4jAhRjRDogHIN5gb5kAE5wkRKC1r8z3h86DXE7@zSRBAyzAGxa3LupwyMaMaiFhFfd34HuP6A/FxGS2v6niqzvFMUVcN8XXfVvCARMABqjc6fpfJUbrcJrJ46yVNa/y15K0RXzwGV8s5EXJAx02PhrIUn9VyEq/viCF0W@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@ZCTT7BZnbxO8onwkFP3xTgnif31EeJdgldgLF2SRBxKiC/CMm9OeQE/32bpUkIdYHD97KdcNDkucsiE@wP9ArXy/YEfTBI0ycXWAlBlTORNKi@iHSgSfsebFF9Sxi8WjzN@ALuD27surgLBE@F9jDjnNit8T6gi1OlNWgOpw913KIkqfIR5dcXpCHi2SfV5FSpWmY8fXA@eRMLLX6n5Erp4n@5OoV6z4B@z/y0cQI8SwcPLL1CpMvt0YmCLAdqIewE3Ae5gXOOvzzj2B6ASW9o8mdzyjzmCCToQzerro0p6qDaG/m3NcuGEQWCGvBKRD6zJtS0euBZQnk0DXY/CvcFC2vTrGKhy3gl1xmFHpOLLU9oktg0yYUNvii7C2kcbl60oBsP9pATvqyp5QM4fu2Mc@UViJIaAEU9qQCqw4WFAaxvbeViL1QQWN45BkTuBxDzXlPiwL1FnqF9vALIniDWnbMlVotm3eZEmKtP5EViRCUOhlnDiLTxDhHnGlwP9EnYk6b0H@TzJt60V5g0G@HYOGV4WT0LCETL@jRirtuCUE0ibRr4AzHyiUa69smG6RfFSjWEy@O9K@hHAaSy0PlMHjC1G1OKNNS/qtEeeTc/oqzplmEMtHP0gGeuymRA37K6wAZJ9vsPsigJCWp@zHvCLAPR841jENoIddH70g5u8BPioDVas/QMd2k66uKITxO5aUtUk8wlGPU9yqQVgxUWXYVfiF7SQSRylnkhXJbavgoFSdx7bRoO1ijv7p9JJ6RyKbX4PTEER4JfmzIXT61EM5hjVjz8MZN75jQhJtYdIzmrxSLwUjMDnZjHdylaEln0mM5fkqFdhUFfhe6kn3LHGrApSCgLX4ElG/BYjHLgLVxTBOnlUPeMkTbSulcM51Z6mXKVENe3GJFS6OW6HKTGnjCeykg1NokQstcyVaOG687UqsXGTcImeWFoVJmVy8M7rmOQ1ZfVLtEwcP6Ygxd@DOjGNtSPLsAbkATwTZ64o0Us6f0SH5OiTimzzgbJFaBC1mHJ2o@UekeXscD51wFml1GXQSlN9FHNInvsD1PeZKf0Ce6HGs4UbE18/fP/XPPPVMWiZowRtaY8woomkQrIeoFwntCXZBioY03KtYMDx2bASUlEFwVjvA19N8hRIvlRulxPpcGvjQScbREfBoUT7VpjgDRhFpaOOCV8xDq4M9DcUh6RMI71u2EJU9qiUpPO5vYDDQFQ1Q5rcceI9IN2dkDRVbl4c6tZY5Yl7cZOmMAYpd0lQZT0DNms/jj@22A18TNowNZ4BF5mvEi5mcIWl/xlfB0EmA@h8JqmiKd0kosoyHNGkpIbhlbxUC0xiDylIPvsdcrs4oMTWlJRoQDqEjGbfXwhd3JIjtucQDnN1l7IBZIo3JhBtaLCWYODOMGA4gFLcEU4sYOwE4ZuT1CBBOhJXXwoMXBHEu5pJ@tHHiLA2cmmOIxd3uYiVtqOOX/xjyYXGrUtOHfGmL6kFXeLTI0T6gib@5BwAcYdPqURbAheoFcAm1o/23eXswHiPm4bnDAkE0TfuwJN6e1KcCuzax2MwyCBCtjtQAdEeGInbMgid7AIs89SBAOWi3e38k4UfQRUhk935UK1@U6HXxJxXadh48E2shD8Tt7ETcTEZB@RuEdLYLuD2x2cc1Mbg1Bgpm06MAQYi4kF2n6hKKwjKGw@QwpWXnFvrfke0wBgnrhvHQUVMAfCR8jY41Zi@lkrYZBFKqD7DxVOwoDCSTqrhkhP0AAb1iOEJwLVZv/MOrgWgIBehnLBNL8GRwN09hm0TGJ@4Qa3vEXJETI8dhQiICKlVYSEXpRqA1dRSJ4RBkY4ZVheVLeaFfshTYEnE0J8fXdSZIkuNlj9VifBZ2@HhBfSIVRaK5BdPg@rlzIQ@X9FCxUHqbGlC8XuZc/dFogKe/I1MibqpynUPKFE7a6lQhh28tY6Z7RWQHzNLQhjuUp2/D7UHlpNrehPc7s1HsB0kcnTxHdu5bPqIvT3v9WsSZO8HagYGU1uv5jm1x9lq4A0gIguRFsj5KTCqyx7h@hUJh5mrO3LUFTJd5Ae/nfyKSVLdeFKWakS6HIdcPpbfqV@85c567T3kUqD7x3z2rzxmwNlDcHnxjNYJPKOfvKEvdaU@1RzeGdwpE1yywWFXAfIB4oeGyXFxJdG4AlPNDgTvoVGp52BKz9sStb1dSQvoyXIKNLkj2GemNCAmjapAKqSJy4TtJMHEqk43Zv8@I5V2H8nTENOvJRy22AG8acTmj0YejDVRaVFmqLwutgU6cQ8oqClV8P0g@JwBvPr40n1eIagVqo9GveWhPJxjO8EP4kFdxRCc566iTWR12g@C2Of5T3j12WQl75tYEp2BpjoVoNockmHt4XJw4qu8shMdMvwc4hogee9jip1XPjAwNK7UCE5n4Rp2sZShJM0rY50os9JzFDNYzl9p8qO27bAytT@Vv4Q994SnE0zBcsqIQum8IYpuYiZMApgBFyJWkV98R18FATAsbNqPFPt1OSNKhB/XjBZIkD1hyxRkk45Eo@0HYS58tP1jw0SXUg6EA@0l5l6YPoUXVHUbuEAhBQntYDwQb0JgR1j4Hd59IqLY0uRix4HfKR@BoLMlhL/4VdjSs3yIOgBZeU0R9KoCL2TuWucEm1EUb1xh4lJ9VAzF2jDfsGc74GgOMcR/N7qjtgAik3pDxEQILCDuRiCZBKFxnFGfBtbtoSpGnTCxfq2UfxYYmWmgSMEwIEAMxSO/g8KEpdu6kBromurY5J1TSQQ8FD9VTe2NF/pmYPAcsT5qXABAMSvKX35TKxIc4lCIUQKKhB5cBbbGSZzbchAul50Tm013iU4yRzGjMUHQrxblAgU2dUVsqP0pvc45TM7HVpFQ44ZBRBIagNyvU13uQhrwlfuGAZGsbGUjHSwG7BSOh5mKqwTBoUJBad2qfUTyuUthXwMyBIUXCBRvTnNpxAEFBUBP9AtcY/CXwsrpmkTQaJKhgunXthPltxzMLj7OOY18ORtjEGeFYuVfwZWOmKDAiCxi6sxeK4z4Zo@ShslOIQmV6BLs2Y6oQpikQRjIZ3KgUIdvqoUzpFeuem7VVfoVdI8rZi5AFbC/AvPGyjxDhDBOkupae2S@HxW0J6BFZO1JmisuCcijdCaLU@m5IYDb7F0M2EscjBkhVvRsU0kpckZhNfJAwOQoP46CaNJ07hH3mHB@6NZbGdWr5QS1zwwYs2h1OdQfci70RtBjgpUiXiVgF3XTcRvYC4dRCNkPBV1AgeOjxs@8w2EGJ8Z5VX@RCMsRl8UBvyi7E9S0kcJbVCA48Zk1p@Z2oc4IwxKtJkMK7xc6pYxK2CPvUCkrARc7CqESAcNQepRjh1REUxTKDW/VR7gA0zmuU0UOplAEX1k3gVNwFaH6gS0BKAJs1zF7Jg2DHPzGJcSqArvXbP4Dnnuhb6TQwvxKZgzGvEKyJCY4FYY8wyXektCswTTGymTLgJICFMdkGAzBbR7VwyIkDk4ISi2WYE9xXnJK8V9RaVC@ZbK/ZgJWhIWVGq/k5yEcIWgLHVoCg13VrmNyDj67Jl4CFSwk3N9coQpLUumTX6luQcEXljWjTW60XEFvSCU1MC9udqy0KY7xqeCP1MsDBL12Fdijp1@7McaPq4VDnSQNnJRCrhKfSUIRFqUcISJaQaXCCUoClStVboWwBuF5MLGTySXn5klVGVKfqRsFglfeb9Ja2wx5cG1T7k8yzXStU6AoLelAVIIkm0J8A/jkmHX0rhQEGlSGYt8MpfLC9CJfTbz7lCYQ@F5gSaXJveLDkBaHSQRnk3DpdQ6DUAHKbFoY8DsP@4@YZed/S2t3fMVgNntRUb@jLcf6PymNt2HwZZWJ@hBQZsNPABlyKqRKb4JHRSKlFjw8dckAAaKBJ2kQadehCBZ0RL2Th4rjkdTbsk45ZeH0/XimyB5HEKAGvmLsxUkYdsxaGUdJ1kpqPfozWtpHUkool/UMkAEpC2SKZAzn5uCclrF2nX4x0NJQzh2aGpAzsHoR3jwVSj5pT8tZKZgGvSmex1IbSu0X@boPbdJKu/iCJBG68HV6bKXCP1h5okjgmq3UZZdj7FyshAwxwSi/r7Y9kkt8GazfRdRT1CoQMWzFASRGHtloHbwgutlRHKSnAmltBFyxHLcECVnIomU3npSYFBQOypXhCBV9mTVik1nhVCGDtAkWK73ebnPwio8AWfVK8H@uK67YE6CCGMnIsCaejR4MDf0OVgYtu85hYuKizoO0gsDiR1BJvQw4z4dOKtAVdbv9HVSCNRLywnnECG@pleuGII1YCpiLi453xKCMbyL@fnZCs0VDtLWeXMQuzYynh4wINHWs@Q5soGMiPK6ZhqVORKBjq2NZTqUm4yHVn5tcW4gEao8T8RBX5EomHKo9vnz5sTi9ycE60w7pjROgicsVzAIJnUslWEywi5eG8oJbBS0770gtqverJkMMiPMJSEkTvPSiAnaXEJoSP@CVxZmOegL66aRaL5E1cjCmuBwB9JLN/5qirqt4RM0jXJ2CvjrNqck4VbEgPHP4ggapg2y5bpSxEzJASREdQNVqSs8lYOEDFBktRwf6D2J5AoRv7SvMVNNL/jZu5GnyixsoBHKNzJGFyjWVQSt@mXAtMfBHPBmkW8Bt2lwA23VGONT4L1Yj8Wv0FQIt5u9ZHnuCRBMUO9zG6yNrFeej1EblAKlMj6IEjpdRQLdjoqDONyFn0EpnTv1Xj1WDX9Yh@11kRsNeFFLtQdOABhkk9CEpiQpcOQaIaJKJS8QYY/lChC@KlVCZP13GwGMOJ2C7aPqpaIlCtuV7KLku9UGpyZzBxwYP/lDy@BFcBACuzswnE8Wewt2NfnkIbIgCKpXNIY1lE73g@chOJ8EWk8TuIpYN7ICUsQAOMkWP1nrcT9BAsGDRWqRPqijpGg5rQ20kPRnvD1TlGJ0PZ6kIUDYgafxd4pwhUxFajXsMWKFiovb7EtM2ACQCzOcjj6QgM9kjHCEYJJBlycgX3AKNa8GwBY4fjxbhgKso2BdrRcrUu9S5jeTvgk/fmcgmZD2MKVWOuioioTgk@QhifDQODD2Q1TiSBeWfH4h3IZWZALLriHwRWdxBDWB1E2Ii9CkH21EBV@2N0ojxMLMOqC5zjZRcAVDgDmQ8IPdF8wHFwaHQTf@MyQAgYYMOBAhErOaQTT5VJQKSEXxDojsU84@sEdD6WJwO@pFEAAubeKiA7MnNzw57pmJcXccpUmRDNI/bFQiT6BBwOBCRQqYRZqdMh5JxUA0xgunq6ggUnh3gooAtmhMBOJFoIKhZTTgscMp20diSSqVVSMq7oRw@s1WDfMN7txTXOVQhmK@Y5PsrLP/VcGwl34L6EqAV2iOCdJwacCaxSUkGogCLeFeuzV3C1PAeU0CtGwUxEH5b3lC5pAbJtbB1drAbXSFRsiKXaIBqOSCzNwVvSOQQk5OqrQDZR8OHXbR2yKPAqooDcJQsitFMcd2Pq1yLsoFI/tmAsogJopkBSgUXA2mXyAs4R7YIsqjaIhZHMBkJZ6GlcR6/z4dE0@QQD77gHZhI6kDhL9DqucqGAfrhFDkxHFGa5mBadZkzr/4VOK@hmYDVhGOcrbNkET1KdYNHiLS/V9uljmwWJ9oLPDiDmI7Y1y5xRSqQkc4K7OBSLv2AGUPQcRbgyzTiFeJeoJEAcgW2Fgc0WwdAr@gQyCQBFIxJdYG6C82JL7J@uuX70gwO/Q8rgkMVMBwwYEJBaK4qtKMK6BxAnaG5RMuQO0dVNeBHBH/5coi@As@xPbvJU@ySoCwrciQwthek/yEaWpKVqMZW5hAOQRltAEVRADDJLoybDyhLcMJkVQlyVjvq9RGL66ELbqFo6BI4BgcMFhI7Z6EuXBKZEFwEIF8VlATSgNmKNKcAIZEhDt2NQwC4/u4OIghiuHdq16K4EUkopXJfJdOQyohrnTwiVEhSzDe8m@8V20YT8y2PxSlB0qUweXBjkj5fuwX7t0Qq7NMw@xDiWmTNP1KiIREEv7EVR7iCRFJPDDp8vExdrGtNmhRubmg6yQ/EAdGUvipcpBIXSMwn2ELY/REZKYiqrWOK1CH0yQdAl0AW@G4Us5tNiwoqRN4eewZQ1AUfjlsJiJTL@BzK1uFDupTBoDAW/Dhd5dBRjvmVNhR@OQCdgI7lt2VNgV0jPQLKBOx1RVDn/eosKHgktR1ri8Enu0L6HaVowJuLE09h8YuqL30bPleqnSFEagyBpGi/4wkTxHNS7LaraB6cqagrVyRC8D02THTVogDkBSMBGoC4D@wSPxQjJcWARGJWGhoWihjBBRJRXGMeIpuj1AscO0vQN8I4GLsEb9nDl6RmfNzUo4JESloKIGNKlqLUIoGo9UY881HODXYemvSkaAQ1jUTZgXmOsQnWEiDkNK9L6Wq4vQA2wCSKd/RxxUSuVr4PcaljOq79flEaIG@b2CJx40cgdjyeqGfsZ3nqeQR18hCG78DegK2zrgVrPol5YKvPowT5oVfBc4hkRl3i@FEVToQwHn80g6PYBitviWyBFDNVrwcuN4CoUvK4Cbh3xMVa92NA7d3HKQLDyEWpUalDHomt0nW8bH61VSz8moAUeCb@go4mN16lpuD@RiSiKpeUQeFl3T7KAJsQvUKNv/WeZLA1xzgfJMIDo8iDq04CCPgV@UWv/BIgZsCST2UKkmy4l9JtRtgK8OURY1XSEEon8GzAuNjCMG0CZEX22Yh9NdDQU6KAHIF6pqo2kZ5Izj18HkvhJM4FvHLkJ3cSOhDfyBsYD7dqmYj5EB/Vq3xZAKIiCx1Llv/ocmpP@fQkjTHA0EITa6TALYYFWiwFN6DagMHY8SqkLDwEcOaQlLXRAfETTfCy3hJ4wlQOG7CB0bj45aY0b8B7tYlgN6TqIDgqHO4KSOKLRBGkGAyQRBG5PnBhCojc5fCnBvZYoq0Eb0VNDeXhOeJOtXtla@HfG9IVCCegJHYxmYlDFxMHkqKLziSSMjjo8M6IvQaDjhXDpBEEOko8XSIC4WyRsrsl2o@tYbEEKfleZQ5R7NHbhKbEbYdpCcUQLnrVe2THPByzKAFOwoIAYWivMYoUtaR8nqrUDxR2sv6xsY74X8RABwAem0RVtMTmNYXgRU2dCrUIXHqmcNVXdWVK@cVmgUMXHyET@ShhTfwE6N6dSx8z0OlkrQMByAtRF5RpFYMlVex0rdHx6//6l7/9/X/69cff/5c//@mP//uf/vTnX//xP/zT73/3q/7zT7/@Rh9@/U@/mr74S77Qhz/8J//xb/7m16Mv@M8//v7Pf/nHP@aL3//xb/Xvf/l//vB3v68f/6/V49/@6edauv/Lzyf6/td/qVup0//511/@Tf3f@9/1k87/6Xd88bs/1w/@jz/8/e//3R//9F9@96e//Pkf/vJnevzDH2n8u7//D//wX3/9tz/8t///i/3h1z//Tlf91f/268/1y1@//7v/8E//8Pu//V9@/av/@utff339@re//vxvfv2PpP8@v/7519//07/793/893/8q9/5p7lR@v/P/@3Xf65L/3Nd9zffrX/3u3/16y9//Lf/95/@/u9//8cazd//XfX5d3/44@9//flPv/7p97//uvgf6rr/vrd62n/4xz/Ub/7qX/3XP/zzX//6q1///C//8v8B)

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), ~22-36 ms on TIO

```ruby
def newtonRoot (base, root)
    s = base + 1
    k1 = root - 1
    u = base
    if (base == 0)
        print "0, "
        return
    end
    while (u < s) do
        s = u
        u = ((u * k1) + base / (u ** k1)) / root
    end
    print "#{s}, "
end

t = Time.now

inputs.each{|i| newtonRoot(i, 2)}

puts "\n\n> time elasped: #{ (Time.now - t) * 1000 } ms."
```

A  remix of [Newton's formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30869049/12101554) in Ruby. I posted this as I think Ruby is very fast.

Comment: Can you please provide the TIO link for your second solution?

Comment: Maybe you could move your new solution to the top, remove the old TIO link and use the characters to paste the new TIO link? Usually when people improve their solution, they unshift their new solution to the top.

Comment: @Samathingamajig - Okay, done.

Comment: I have now added larger test cases

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), < 60 ms on TIO

```javascript
function iroot(input) {
  let bit = 1n << BigInt(input.toString(2).length - 1 >> 1);
  let root = 0n;
  while (bit) {
    let diff = (root + root + bit) * bit;
    if (input >= diff) {
      input -= diff;
      root += bit;
    }
    bit /= 2n;
  }
  return root;
}

console.time("sqrt");
let roots = inputs.map(iroot);
console.timeEnd("sqrt");

for (let root of roots) {
  console.log(root);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tb1LrzZJcqS3568oaNUjaaiMjDs4nIUALbTWUtBixGlyWuBUU91FaSHMb6f8cTfLUwSaFV@efPMSGRe/mJn/X//p//lPf/2Hv/zpX37797/@@T//8d/@4c@//vW3X/7067/8629//eXvf/nff3l@/R9/afG/Ef@7tFf8v3fG/@u0BscWfzyc1Z48/832GHl@/urmz/J378z24Xh/R14p75C/HSPbh@Pz5Zy5OX/lb1e2dx7fec7J82/@9q56hrxoe/IOreXtWt27vfkgrddTjXrEWc@76uFXvcnOt2pn1PPn275PvUGrXngf/vb2hzPf8bR8u7zKu@pfu/526sybv@t1ld7ymtEF2RM979dH3r3Xs/SdT9ZPPme/@dTjyXcY9Uaj5/uNkW87Vr772NWj1S3zyT6arTq1V6@O7MpZ/Tp3/evm39aTZ8a1Wn7dvMqaec218w7r5P32M@uD5FV2zyfbM59z73zqffMdTg2N8@b7nVFjZuW7n5M9catf4vz818g@uyt78J5H46s@0vPq3@Opj73y7Pjo@ePW6lqtvb3@Peo7tlWftZ36yq9HbK8x8M4aEu@uEfJeDRiNnz6mBlCNrn5rsI22NObrevF@9e9zaoi17Nk2e3Z0U7@3eerfS39fvc5f@v2qT9i2rr9H3W/r/vvW8xw9XwzX@ree/z71PlfvdzXIb71/9GL2x/tU/7zProHePNJ7DfVW/ftywRz61f@vh/tb3@ftrf7eh@bGrt8PXW/0uv6oLx9jv@4/a1zE2lDXmzVq3hiD@fdVY@qN187fa8S9e9Zqsms8vtEPNeFqtMYqU9e7NZbfO7N/47Nmf8dU3DUl63v059a/W82SePs8v781h2Ky1sR8a4b13moF6zX/ej/5PF2zM4bLrX/X3O2z11Semtmrxl9Mfs37U8vA1qqwVy0SR2tGLHf171pRYvg9WhoeraG1ij5D/z7599FqrWKY1uJR14vRVMv4W@vc6G/eP47m88RqrFW51sgYJfn8Y9YKOuauxWhpNVqrlqNdq@/YUwtSrc2xrtf1Tq3b477Zv@PWmj6fVguRvsdsT/27aS@IgVs7Q@0TcbSWuF57yOwn7zdH7S@xyuXzzFnPF6Pl1rJX@9KMeZbn79qzYq@p650n33/G58y/x7DP8@/M/oqzaj96ZvYnnzFXzjafWjqf7P@l@bG6/t3196Hzh34/db2p66@6H92Z5@96nqXni6@Tz8twyb/fep94u1qCH63IT71/vF6t1636Z7/VX1v9t3v1Z6zg2b97VH/vWf2/tV7FqK9/L@3Bu77f3vU9t77vPvW9Y3nK@52nxsN5anwc7cen1fg5b42n89b4Or3G29H4i/2i9o1Z4/PMGq/x@tlfZ1f/xbKX/XlOjfdzavyfW/Phan7cp@bLbTV/bqv5xDKRm4/26Nj2a2saNR/vqPl5Z83Xq/l7V83nu2t@313z/Z6a/7Hc1PVurQ/xq1ow2tOazJW2P/NFe1yvRScatQrF2lrLUjRqnWqPN5KYMDqyrs7ZU786r66j1bA9t5ZHtsm6e/xN5lKrFTUe6/UWWmtua70W4dhMa1WORi3TGFl15bZqIY/G1U67l7be07UXX2/Ot3YHPkJt32FZ1X7@Nm343mHYoXWkX50ztOm/s@s6S1d@V@1jsY9r44/Hqud5j7d@74X90ebI5jWqoe0T46z2@88A6Npx@7AJMLUnx5SqXu3etWP5rp7vR/t6v9roY6LV9xpa6sKEkG0wXp0Ti1j9Kga5zInPvpg2OKYtkKXnGVs2yrBREEOt3oJRU2bIIztnNr37tCUUO3H1T6xE1WNxavVhrKJd1ov6eS7ZWyycdc6RRRbP9dislmH96JtGP9U5sbs/MnvK6ItvpCvHhlj3YgW8MonqeWKu1RMuGZXR0Dhct4zOhmFaBlIro7Rtj@fdy2iNhsb8HltW1dS82DJ6Wyxw1fP7lFEcDc2vfctojpGqL3ja0JFX8/T0MrobvdJkoNWVz9R8P6uM9rDZtCaEPSyrTstGzJgy@qNxZdi1I8vu3TLtum27UYtTY7Oqc9YrN2aX0xHbqPr5nnJKWixNZbI9j5yWsA3LqHts5T1dTk4sRDpnygl6lpyiR0txNOw0nSPj8pZTFUOtlnMcqbpyzOEy@GJelcXHoC@Tc5bTFiNERl981LL6ouuPzdKy@@I1yvCLm8kybbU1xecvj/ENozS/Tix95U/GZesLvmFn6sieOucM/erWFom7V1fGgasjb/mxb6wS9Txh/9UTdhke7Lf1FljEdc4pD/llTWjyIOvKo9V2/4adVj1Gf5fBPB5Z0NMmdXylOrLLqHhHbLf1q/t8Tqns6uYjr86ZXb@aQ9eZvnJM87rX3Lp72EWy16@ecPmZ4/vbZNd7ra43jcWr3n25N2LIV/8wl2XYqw/XVa9u9/Nu6vmYi/UtdtfXiaWuvpcNlNgE9U331lfeR999X42E47FxmkbL6Ro/MU/lSEyNseNRd7bGIe5qnXM1Vu@j0Xs9nu@rEX67xnyYDtWHd2peXM@UezR3wkwos/55an71p9WM656DsVktHRlb50w5A89ygMHuwnMVZMCqKIemKdAQ22e5HM3Bhli9yilhEa9zltwWzKO6jlak2IxrjYqFW67P@9Y6FrNBztGrtS6cCrtPu8mfOnKwol/K4/pcsNh8deSVkxarTv0qPntdp2t97n1POWJnyxO7tar30Z7PF5Mz1ru8sVG7Q7hntV/EZl47CPGXujKuSR4Ji716LLbc6sPYIqtXp3arHjtj9XxsVvUt2BDrV6d2ve59MIb3qyNv7ZUYmfUr3MC8ztIO29euPRcTsO4e30Q@4lM7NVEihYt67eY95kW9156148cnKRugb1kFfd@yE8K3LMshFqSyJcJaKeuCwFNdGT@ojqyySWLvLCuln1t2S5hl@oK3HR3pOueOsn8wnuo6VzZSfC7d696yo@KO9Twx8svWiiVP7iVhijqi9xpsVvWrU@9OeKx8zKb@Cee3bL/B5lJu8Cj7MKx9OcJhDZRnHPuxXOVbdibmWDnTtkVHrN06MpvO0Xcfse7Iw5aVGyt32b2ja/xgxMvLHjXGCOLVlbvG4cCRrXNujdXBylShPo3nET9T8G/UmB/44fmroXlBXLCuHIt6udyzlV@Ai/eWEz/KdxhTqyjTQ0c0T4lj1K/C46nrLPkpY2m@jzXLlwlT1OHIXf4O06uuHIZZvcVuCmfGoK033Vp/iF7WlfeuNWrsU35X7Gy1jjFPqlePXLVYXst3G0fr4Yglob5O/PpxQLSufLWuMsvrnBh99St8owpta30esW8o2H1rDZ9PKz80OrXWeWKsCrbO2gtmrMYVW3i0X8znlrc7m9zf6K/yh2fTvjMxsvNXrL0O29aVm/avuP6rKMirsEl82oqT2JKZsX3qyFHo5L2KnXTtp0SCFT0ZDp9MxU@69uUZ62o94VBIYY6mGMrQ/h5LjaIoMTjq3YfjKEN2QtgUiqSE4VF9GDfrFZuRvRGjr6IhMz7gU@fcipfMJbtlOqLCQqsj0@fI/gmnRNfZCtPM3XSvLTtq4iQNRXzqCbefecseS2Mnzzmv3pQvuSoupN44S/1zjnrsXPXhlX1IVL2ujL1QR6a@xZWdOWOx2YosKdXxvE1HZK@usDIqMB8LZIXmH42NWLJqtIQVVuNnhVt7KiQ1aowt288rNthbR26NzBVDv@JIr@xwYv915XfWCF8x1ioW9cqeX9GXFa3qCicuwnB1RH5BTNKaXwS2H6cT6spD/sUa/VVUbByFxVbN5TVkycTKWfM915g8JzqjnmfK31lT60YY8bWSrDC16r2W/CYMz3r3pRDtWrPWqDAca9VaYUa9irrtL@lRV97y4/jq9S32rhUylrpaM5f9wRU7rY50JVbOrLV3HfmV5FHqymFD1r1ipay7X/mn685a52NR1jNj41ScT34uAb9Ktzy9dhA84IrFPfKXiclmj@3wv0aFA9/am8LErn6OiVL71w6v@Klzbu1xsZjWrre9D278kzoyr85RHCBGbO2nuyuVEN1Uey4hsro7gyV/FUbJUfhRzzwUl9g4PhWRHLXjb1IHeR3HN3asyxXlnK0shx0rWsU5p@Ik5KTqyjFjK1QZ86pil0vxlh1jVNHNL9y5u44obrMxuiri@eo6WzbS3or/hOdRdhTTrJ4nXL16wiNLJlySssd2LCD1XudMJcwUjyJzVldmJCicWrbfvopr7XAZKgL6qJ9jwpQNGfOuvgXLWEVBn1Pf6ziPFo7H0ZFe9upps777abts2uN4Xfy47N7odyXu3qFE3qu4H/k9JfquEn9hzyumq/jhiYW/or5d4znmR9nquF8VKB5v2fMHW90pQ8WCFc88MQorBxxbY36dE/tWfq9jS@bEQq8jt@bpiSWyfrUUXyULWVfGd6wjp3yZsxWnjfla/s7ZWjcOI72OKNh7cDDzV9l3SmzWlY8Cxufs8r/iNWsdO7eVj3YcdA63svy4mK61HsaWUr5ePKcC1/YHSfDpyOo6R8HvS3B5Kcpd4efWy/e8TQH0i7NVEfBb6zzp17ryqyD8JSma5zCDK0x@yxfGwFegvJe/fMNfyh4Lr6B86hi8tTeR0a0rk26qI6N88zuUUCDAnt/rOgV0w6bRESUl8CHqV/ipTUlixeGV2LhsKnlOrPj1PLEc1xM6ORKracUlYjLV/h4LeFP8XgkW8s51ZUZ/HRkVA7lHSZpYjCtOEnu4@pnYZx1RoueysI3KADw/qWyF45/3OzYeJbTjQyulzbJbof2m60frrVs2AgRDmYRVDxYtpa8yTe6E@StYBn5AhQ7DeBU848lQiJIOijmm06VjSqeRiehKV4STuL4UvO4xlJYjjj6csljTOYsznbRwxDQsmuVjY@u8MOT026k0Yab3dY/1GuZB0kzJf6UbSX4I7/FsQz4eNmgdU9oyWlvYj4cUVTN0QPc4Sn9GawoH8hBFEsTgXvX9ff097mj6Rne9@m731IRs@Vmdb1E6g47xsbWfLwnzKAvzKCwbi4OzJQTrdUzp4WhdhXgbcZhmyIPu8SrNHK2tcHEiGuq3YXU5sTOc64nvq/RPbI7KCJGhULpHae@EU@geRKF07CrYnVkFgW@6QuLNK3K09vYxpeFJGym8HhaBIu4E/J1UOs5XYcworfQ6Y7WnAvpE63WP2DL1brGhLeeflBxoZzpvdZxCYJNT/91XiYZ2h3NXsXo4eeXsVUyt1@mr7vwVRlelmZ7tDNYHWokZ6BwWQBElupazWDyMsEqGr7zElo1fciaLGGf99r3OZfUfIMswlKUvg1m64SDkW6pf3uGM1hv@vzBSw7CSGF5KK@EPrA8ao3tMw1PemKH13TL@W78NL2ArHedvHrNc6a7wS31ebKn67TZcBtiN7hFemO57mhJshN30fPEF9cznfNCuR8m62J0@@M5USu@92/1yfxJ/hgFhCVSfdny@ytA9R0nE/sGJeutKNbLd1XcL@0YJSdyg@r79S1t2ovE6tpvPE7iJqykFSpDTGcalRGnvAkg1xpeeL76bnnk46RpzTOO5syTWeYQCnJ9UAhfUie4R3WcgU9M86nhESmQK7JUwJ6cym@Zl312J5b4FGGtEFev79i8b1sME9DGBzhoD0YnQR@sGECrd4wq4Fq2ttDhhQeU142spsfl4vYqlaSq1iXNT57GeDWdUBUVscg2jdbROhu9SDmS0BMJrpG26krDOkI0cHNUSkC9as1zWaG2t48OObbQEBiRfe3RebG/6bYxSXW96/yBcq/viV15ndvV8y6BE5okBZkv7Fnlove/@gI3ht6hf9nJfhavhxLDBkQOgRf0WpMIHWdM9wpRU3jmMZ6Wi79Q@Pe5pArM5ZhGt/vjY1L4/n30NgntkHwCHU7qZyIyO7QqcNLqlno8IVz1zDGe9x2Ry17GYwMpng1uq3/YpOweone4R76OcNh9YSe0puwmMkNLa0/ZVPPtUYpuDyn7vqdQ2ofxmGJ/uEdaIj33nhXuu3@7venv6Hvu7L/k6Zc@/5wvvRs98vve4j9/tfu97p/vgul9AJymL/rj/MnhUefTH/byw55rhh0qlk@7XMX@3RZq3fvv6@y5HGhPxoWPxR8MYPV4Wi0UztFH3YDWrY8Pjb4U5pOcbHqfEenSP6fG8mKB13vS4X@uD8H7zY8X/CSWwPI/WNpx3bc@3tbcRB9vzksCNcAnH83eF4/d8kEzd4wrmGy2vBytch/rtfrxu7Mc2HEGZrmNHa07sClqHYvpqbdrfehWPrDVsv17XYuPUWrdfr3/R8R@@weskkRYhHLrX093v/oGS6h5DEGGQEFqfY5hqzSZCWd93fzbcnl7v8YJ13vK@sNcyauLbPzY5@zq2vc@EGWgExvZ@RHpK9zjet/bZRnNc728bH7QZAqt7XMGLG/Fj4bdjiFc/x8akfZX8rxEb3n9Jxtd3O8379GmGHZ9vPz9kznXM@37Y@bIFTrd9gOeve3TbEWcYhpy5CgFDlmwQoLuGhhiOfKbtl0N8un67bOecZRsuZoyBwOvIRjrbdtPZhiefz746MdqFSDm2w84xTPkc22vnfuiWa7sOf17nXdt/FyRxM@RYQJTHsOX72J687dXz3Wa7837wZfLfArqQRa7zXtux8ckNY/7s3RtTRmiXbrv4DsGZo2X7OUx5I16G7WyWzvpud9oeZ3t7Pqi07rEEb46W7XvSYY8xNfID7rYNFxNG/gIpHz3LsV9xj@DOCcPWPaKL9G7Xfsq9gj1HS/7My9IufM0jvwfEjuDP4e2XfxStLgg0H0bwnWYYdFyk/K2XfFrhJJ5Xflm4M/rm0ZL/9qbnX@d1@Xmx4gkWnfBx3WPsrftO@Y3REjwa96jrmef1eyz5oWBdal2LlvxV4ES1/iU0XffYgksXxqjOA/ldvz3ykwEeGYt05U9HqxvndJeBTlfw6ffzz18CEj4mP/4Nd1top9bk77@4pCaFKC6AmyesBx64IE/vMeapf6CnPj7U0/5gT49xT6Mb@DQ@5NO4hj7FMiTs05wGP03BrBOur3uw7eqY4ioks4SNYQOp79s@BE0stwLV4DvrvKN4zstioutdA3Ri6gmzE9Oif0AsIXsYbFN8GeN/iKWJEtSaUELxcgIOAfB6m2kGgnGF5XF0THGuaAmWjZssqNLbjV7KJH0dG4JnkyMR7CnRUh@FQfeY/Tu2fN68/u16fb313WMd35dNo87bw8@3t5/5fO9xut/tLL/vue6D@7pf7tdX9xhM9jTjy55hyBnT4qNefMA0Y9WaQqXRuvqW7Bn1ffuHewtrTeMAj1TndQVnoyV4d9I6dI/RNdbiNI2/PgXzjpbCwUTNjYCbChrHiiy4d4Uo6rfraC4AkNM9tmDf0VKYmo@qudWPgtmEN/Q9wqvUvIy/mZ51FRh/8SWfZjqKoHZEbHRMQfYYLoKDEynVuhF@o/F2rwL20RIsPP6rsH4C9YTd616vRhc8PFpKEcRAfLXWjaFEQrS8Jsa6oHVyzKm1c0wlJWIbEVY8aTS6B3nWOraV4IiW8OIvSIr6vsP@ebSULImWMOMJ2NJvo/90vev9I/NswhMqPROtqb1nPkrivNPY8Rfv7urYEYUnPnPtb9ESfjzpPwIo9mYqUFdy6cWTG8YoHkEShylFBI4/4KJoR9AoBG8Mf/r5qEW6xxKWPANZOi98J/12K4HGNPE9ttJsLwAJYyGVjMsgmJ7ZKbsXpoje7Sqxh7OwhYh8lP6L1jEmsilJ@K4mbPmLDyZYJFjZjxIlyOUrfPkbI7zssGiNss2ipeQl2CR98/C3jo9tnzeVCI1W9/WcLn0X6NI6tpRUfdO3qt8upV4B3Ps9thK00bp@36M0brSW@gUql@5xhTl/wbwswUCv@jnmtkhp@/H32I/Sy7HsvvpuuykJHS1hz98vVR2teXxMCe24rPDnAEpFVAv/yPcYSo6/iRUR3lQpdPDBGqd4RbrHFA79JehS77vX1LhPZ0fQVM@PvacJbGHCHeFVBQCIlvDoSW/TPe6reYnL9AFbNX9jjSq/LFpe28FI61gTLv0lKF6/JbsrVOwrfzBawqZHS1AI8Jpah04XYOIF1qB7DMEqojW1rsUyXf4qCCStf8cQDQK4WidjVSv/900kfP12Ce7xhu/0GH8rUMhLorW@2zmCjkRraR0/9s@jZbx6ZlIF1X20L9xHYJVofUjcJkhLtLrxuk3Al9icjVu/hscQajb2twtEEy1j18OUr7jFe4diGeDIK74BJFj75Z2C7URraF8lu6l7LGPY7xIEKFpH@zRpzC1Asb95eB2PjuGw1nlHoKNoGct@DU0iKC47InyNig@BQhZN@3kEc@rADIQtbgJDRUuY9vhUgkyBpy47JymWhi4L1x4twa@idcpuIspa8bBoTeOXh6BcHaKBUM5TgK9oCd@e/oruEcPAx67P292/3Wt@EGnf43Tf92w/y338fGEy6Jmv3yNJW4WUfgR9yzcTVroJINfBYonq3QSjI1@uPm2vwHaAZKvvk3aqe8RSPHRMwL2eYecrqPYjoqpzqdESCLATWjR9VVDBMgSbKa26xxb@vRPa0bPEyNHzHYETo7X8HkcQxp42f513BXTsuKTVL6/hkB1nrfovNrCaRwkZr37GsRAL/lUsPLPOTceMh8dAfQQuX0LEv463dwwsHxPkM0zbR6h4TAVdbxoXT@Jb911TyPjYkES@TaJBM83XhN8rdHwseyLx5jIlFLtgraR2jJC/Ar92UPyiBz/ThOHn/I5CLDB7M06@N8Fte4dUUr99Bcrtv8PKd0F3o7U/tLwAvh33UtczDLhnXqiOTYGFo2XMPOlfPfNSrqj3LeBxB1Ze70u@p/ogQePN1Gfd4xg7D@5tCZa/hJ6Pl619tQMcEDL/EWw6Hr4JQT@awNXRMob@g2BHa70@JqB2T4u7ftsF58YR8j2GQN9ERYWlx/@W7kJspvXMbGC6xzKefizBzHtOvPrtFhgdP8kMgyPIerSmUPXR9WU39XGNqx8f/J3cyTDPQCB5Iv/1LWczlH5aMiBaBtyHk@DzXsPyZ/@u1w3en90Y@1giBPEn9lbPFxuOiABhNb/mM5guEN9U7xsLokgFcwlrnzR23WO7/whCiDBxhLePlmkM8/p7pAGgY8f8h@ejRDz@vqv9ECe6uRTN9ArYRvrtaxLGMvaemJWoGqt7/GHx1/PFCqtxuj7ax5oez2G4iRySwdX67TKFZH3zY20TTQCQVp@S7pa0yfF8g6ute1xh8aNlakvMbc3f/ZgAs23DRcs0md28HuxmMg0fYTTLBlg5xOtLWLki5uCj1vPtYfrOHl6v9jDJZ09h86NlKtCeXv@QJNA9lvD5YeWYVrS319OwfEQ@2sboR8sUJbaZ@m77msi0r3D6KXcg4snj9f40k6IABDxirIg61c@3f0SHX4kmvMLr99NFw4qW9yOkFHSPIcw@Jl/FI0hZa387U8SvfpZsuGiJHhYt75dpqdZvt7D7KdOgexzvv@eIkMYyuc2hEW2NtLhZNI/IbdEShh@m4BCRptk@QAJCVJpXOP5oiU5HGET2xu0i3fVrLH/HDrw6ZvsFPNQwWUd2zjXNrxMMODomMmC/W5h@cksVD@v3s68AzDUdE66/A5CTcMWVvTY@PNxIFJyOico4QLw9YgWJ8DiAzYkX9IoWGS3Zk5CG6vn4Uz1zymJYIEP26SBeIwrRFM6foFAT0Wg95h4tkTqjJax/bFuifkZrWcbo6HswtSVn9BzRSGOtkj1ODrS@L6aSeDfYkz4m@34UeKtawv2nnIdITq/8Bdz@Gn@jdWH/AUDUOB3N/scAdnB1TPh/LO8a94MEdfVL0rTrHkscAGCSW1SqLf9okLwTmepYVqQd0YEHuCrzqUQaHu2KCzA@ajFEV3F0YjHbJl6JDxAt0ZQHcWBJl7wiMw@2wXoWAo/1fG@Xf5kSJ7rHEC8A3lata9GSvxoGxWNlJXMDBoGL6r@0CcXwEmEbiIiYT69p3QAlxY8CAV/fLbFHxfx6RBEf3Wv7wLHQsSaewIBwWb/FMK7rAXEQSayLKzCI0daz9K74wehDBPfBHy0SJRo8lDHxyWLb3aKYrW7WmSn1A2i2uGlbxPuRi3H99oieH62P53ZF4o@WuAMjJ2sR0h7FX1JSxlJf4g@M0SQbwG4k/h2dX9cb5hDAeCs7IlqKDw0y@fV8oIklW2M5A9Dj4gWOJdEDwopiDxJnE6nO8atBrNSaWuITDNAxItZdxcNSCkf3uOIU4LcekesexddG2HBdZLr28eua5B/SQtd5r0QiRqJZmmV2RN8biv@B1hNRklBBPV9YbqJKxob9msMn8YpoiWMQG4okLqKl@GRK@OgeRzyDgS1Xfcp7DzMARZpc5hrQpaJNEsOu77aaBDqiJb5B5q9EFnwVjw3jWmIf0RLnIFqSBMGt9j2GhENAEmv8EZ9cohoqXpzSQ7rHEvcgFlNJlRQTsX57JGgyCKHoHleyJ9FSPJv8kMiUsRxpvm1LqAC10rzcTUIrxKE1f/crOZYYVl7bd5doS7TERSBAL1ol1peuN02s3FN8BGBxzcpuygcwhEWu3OYkROuYXnle8yvPNsHyNjMsLVyTUgHVf3H/j2R5P5ZlN83S@Q9YNyZavstMy95MtezKp6TUk@4xxFGIlgR5BpBA/XZKtCdu7/3jLAn7jLOV74mWxH8G2AU9swWCoqX80SAWWu97rvgKTFoJVQFnEKuzSYyInKr2y9skWDTuq/xWSlSJNNpfy1b1beGqoXxZtCSOND7uQrQkoBQt5d8gsl39dom/kPJXusdWPg943dGzHHEYBixBPbPzg9GS6NNMwFExTR8JQ82nKd@Y0lqiqL7iMkBfFQ2S2Jy4rV0iVGRTxJ@MRUOUymcoHzpj6ot4ydL@NMt26R5r@9huPm8v//Y8vt4x@zM@ge97h5/lWoAL47@euT1@D6Jw9W4JFq/zXuWTZ3st9tXMaZhAZUW47cpPzzYsGgYcUpzbT1isTeW7IZKJtNnWshzZ/gTKHHudMKp07IjTMFFy0W@v8vFJ5617xKgX1/d9JJgGx1eMYBL39cxQOMTufSW8Ftuh8ALRkjhbtMRpSJk03WMIfzDfKZE3iDXiM@MhVt@/S7Hw@W6JxQG4rLk6SSbUt3yP8BHZU7rHFadhppJFEYkf4S2iJfG62DJkw02Eluq@aefUea9E8MIDE6ch5d1MVRYeJFoS04v/iNMwCWtUv3TjS2JMSZRvstaK1bwl3Dczs/xJx@keR5yGiZsl0vRdFs58JBI4h224SZBJx5rwNIRaal@YmSdulqUTMboLnzMZfhKtG@I0TPj7ol3P17zrKfFDaNZTzOslgcQZW9M193qafH3EaZjEW6tPM4FVv70SY5zDnIZYrSTYGC3hm@ZsEnWcIHTr@07v55PUjo51iUOyfCz9dkhAMlrL95gSmYyWOA1k0Jro4Ut4rpTq0z22OA3RkqBlmDnChxG3KztnQvHTPa6EMVGqKhuJQFbZTenVVt8vC2zGhxR@LVoS4ZxYKPUtgTZKL9W5VMJhXcfm4/OmBD8nuExdb8lOnBCLdd8t4VC4Tn6@I3HRaMmGm@TlJVh4hf@bzE@JFj7iNKR8ocjrTXhCQnNLFPdXnIbJsDcR3t9jD4mmJie@vhsI5vqWJAaeTxpR91jiNCDCsXTeFn5ywn7V9c7wPY40XmcCtuq8KxXY2D3EaUjZRQkwNuE7oyUl2bRsxcN/pTWLPoWZ@F1qtACONY/OkF7tTD2fT9JR91jiNEySh/XdzhaeNVpWxT3GTEx4nDp2hY@NlpV1WQjF73@svXsf4W3nbVLnjZY4DRjX5V@CjdF73C6F35nMyTpvSAOYoKnWP3ZL3WOK0xBjTjrCyHVoPQ0jqPzkCTRZ9zjSIo6W8MpwscrvjpY4DSlzKYGBR/jn@IsUj4EziOUPu7AI@8@7LY3ZpZq8Ur@wzhvSVY6W8Nkpoal7THEa1rOkzRwt4b1XOlR1PXMaCOtUfCNawo/HCJYCdLSmVREexUsWpMIhpYSn4ipoJkhhoYE8LGkEY6MQUpAEdeviNCwoKPrtEF4@pT91jylOAxGULjmGJfz9SsBgXW9PKzLEfJIkwxGefwGprT4AqCpVhuexLMMjfsBi5kuYoYnTEN3zVDwsHa@6xwu4rY51cRpSwkWCpWP@TrLU0g/fsfWdt77f7u96@7vH@e57vme53/NdP3P/3iMzYnWs@X17cx@A07mSmHBf9e7@I5lVfdqH@xmrYH1Sq7rH9DcCFVTfjfB@fUuWjfq@3TbcItKhY8djI7xajZd@PYbGN67G47E2mscfAeZ6PjBj9czkraRo0T2eCcDU@xISGZLC8FwY3/zAka/@S1ejzlueWyjqVN8Pcxpinfa8TDGcOu96/o7rOT2/eZ5GepPQRq0HK/d9aW5o3WA0W7K2a31ZaULVeUPrEBui1Tm8XkXrWJ9jaV1badzUb7fWvwXqSvc4WieT9FF9GkthracrF6xm2dy6B1O@vlFMx1qfw1bSmo0KSK3jsbpYrSOGydaxoT1gJSulfju1V6Qkr@6xtKcAiJIuOhwTqYhs7UdrmdMQLe1bkFKmFEmu9jcs79rzUu5XgiNNe2OSVyQG/GoPRT2v9tUwKLTXpmlR3whMcX23PbRPrz21d69vP4@W9ngeeei8LVtgoXyp653le1zZEZBmyrYgrFP2BnmBskFSptiCxbJV6IyyX6Ilm4Z8Ytk50ZLtE8Na9hBWe9lI60zZTdGSLZUSyLrHks0FWedIaOXINouW7LX1cRqiJbtuARyt8xBSOBJVlk2Y8sqSaXllO0ZL9uS6XTZmtGR3rmt@7Urhvzo2ZbNGS3bsSqGCZulm3WPLBl7wT6pPE0RYv72yn0nRSlvleWRnR0u2936a7PGd@3SzLLREYV7Z8vvpsu83OED9dsgPABDje0z5CynhVeojidiv3@7HKjP7E545j7VozrI8zW1WrLnyZ3YzpwFvekqwuskXAs1a/hFqNTXfUs667gF3vXRYWpe/hV5kzV8iD@WX7Y9/Drr46tiST0cqdem3W75fSmXrHkc@Iits07Nc@ZLRtfIvWWD1Hm@TH7pTkfRKNaf81Q1ou/rltV@LHFCtkxsob/UpW171M4C86nugnrrHkj@9wxg@Ut3Z8rsJT63nk/jWPa58dvBQ5cdneLJ@25v8/WjtT7NHcQHUe45Ue7riBxt@snR7HGcgyFn71k5gQZ23FKOIluIWSUjTPbbiG/EWinlsVMeqnxNB8kmTSxzoUQyFnUIC5Ej61bckp1Dfd9iG22QQdKwrdkNYx2LnQzGelD3XPaZiQXssxYc2Knb1fGjVTYkQWWodxIeEia5iUCy7FZfCQio7Z0/HrzaBqeq/REfXea9iX9DuKh62pzkNm5BDfSP86fpu4ZZXfC1airntj5eKTJWP7e7z9vVvz/D1rF2yoYbXfYnz17OsR3HCjYlcz7wcTwxrXDHGnVDOOq8rFhkti9KvIRtuY2bMT2qp@nQti9OvpRhoyszrHluxUphV@m4s31Juuhaq386lRsti9bs1y9W3T7D@VSw3Jewl4NQV842W4sDkgjQm48NpnG5zGlgWNJ6RilLZk6348yYaX/2yHafeKONX/yE8Un2KOn71Mwm26vtjzZ4Nu7a@EbLS9d3Oqzj6BmLzfNL7Et8fisFvCH06bypWv1mKdb11fI@tOH@0FPvfpKz1fFc5gpT1lyTVo1wCSFOta2hkVR/cpjwEV1Nf3Vf5in27chgb2ZTqZxSAfkoG6B5TOZENOLW@213KnSCBpXX82j8HQKL1/l7lYqKl/Ay@iZSjHudxYg@0vtTzKt9Dp0iFKnzY2o/O82lVPUP5IxImUrR6pvJM0bLu1eN81MFzLfUnsFTLUlzS0HqO8luHuLfucZUHO8lDKz2upnwZkBerdnk/j9an7dWVfzvkfPXboTzdAVSn0gtT@byDDns9CzoDqua0lQvMEg26x1HO8KQmXJ13lVs8SSVc0glTX71NeckDr6n6FPOv@vntymlm@QfJhg3lPg8Elfpu8YOyzYD2lL12Pm2RAwxAx/b2eUd5WP7r6zlfe9IRLm2yR3ndw6PU86FXVs/c3259sld54pOEyDpvKJ98AApK68x552gpF30KelYt5axPeJqSbQPWpHsc5buB1eu75Z5XMmiPcuXny58fgJ469irPjm6axsvoysdHywpu6FHUfWNZ0/gDiV3PR5rW5Zks4za2sAHREl4g1gVhCGLVEq7gDGsTHjQgqv9i5dQ8mk04hVgQhV3IUh51D4L/UnTrx5Juo1vTbdxP1O1TdVvNsm5L2IpDcFO/3cJgZJkQ3eMKq8HCJHE30Ib1fOsRzgNOnt6DYEu9W2pG1nlduJFoCUuSJUgkHzeEOTnp7NZ5S9gUxOUk9LbMaTiIRtY3SqWBOu8K/4I7U@t48tvqHqRDdawJT4Nnr3In@xXuJhb01yVRuvA54RQJs3Ny6azfTmF7snSK7rGEAQq7V7igkyCf@u0Rfuiw4OseVzgjpNBU6iVZ9pLDE0Ypy7JIEO8VlgkKh0q5wZSvbxmdXPGXcNq0tkdLeKnDB9F5S7iqAy1V1zP@KlrCZCG21/UsV9gtNrWKI51rTgMfo@JNJ/28Ou8VPgw6Sdk5WU6m7kHKq/oPCYjq09y36rdLuLRzrUV7Mrhax44wbSeRcfXbK@zb/fBwKfqnY024ufs0YenoZInNRddLf@7pwuHd5GjXeUN4vcuWcprL4LggjrB@F9@kRPCeLUxg6sCUVB4fVfe4whNm9x0pDgp3GBawsIhZYqfuAf6/9PpSFqnO68I23riphP4@TgO@ouQA2xJWkoycRANjoZaOYDPOMlrCXsb@LzzmhVxfzxeLj2QKX2swX0jQ9W7v261v@F5LHvZpFcTxCSOOba3EKVzpZWeqfkaSo/qe1JjusYVTxV2ROiMEpPqWYOTr@34y/9ESFvYm2aOEFF9hZgk4XBUq6l@poi687U3cf503hcuNlrC6WdJI91jC9N6@hfO94PmrDxK8Wtczp4GxWevkBQ5ZfRpzotbTaAlznOWSJPXYhU2@hBQk9jiEYWY7rHX8ftrjCaPQsSVMdJwknPRNBfDmUky6xxXGOlrCXUP9qb3nziZ8drS0R8VUFY4bB6L2snC2hPe@iZJvLvNU95hTWHHURoaKQC1hyhGNUA1D9h7d4wiPfkn91HdDo6e@Jeqzz1dCyuUrhXm/MDN03itsfJjAwssT5NI91hCu/q4prP0l87gkfSlMfpancqEqYfcBn5T9AhehbBoctStJTGvuX7DnEs5s4gykcmb1c5Jlv9JXdY8kwNexIV5C2ODiKkRL/IX76ezGBi@eQ7SOzzviQ0Bm8/XMm7iY5ksKneJX3PM9H@ZmPTOmYN0jyQhLCp563zPE67jgvaX4af5HOBPuP@LVEv3c4o7Eki0@yT3mNFwQRxL@fMRFQdjjSvrz@77XdjsqCRoHTFadNzxeYuBvXc@1Jgj6dcmNfuMP/FA9HzSCeuZrPs5NX6iOXfF2GHMi86CsLoYPTUvExVYiLhBNEYQa6R2p9zy5f7avmpm1TOd0ubFwwF2C7PFUbiQSXars@cTiACy5pNlzu8ucocyhK6ABquu29pVIa15ykESdXym13r7yan275Foz1SGaU3wtmiJxIaAqZhdNLY1Vl813OyKG0RRbrD2JGbuWW5W@0/O6CEs0mxhoLZFXkgdFvF9ar@w7z0/xNyu2Dm0LjC7x32heC4ziA/m6@5MixZryM5xh0dL3in1Hc1vetJun18B/WQgVXX/1Q/eWSFPcv8b4@0Rih1iCNK9lWEEZWyd2NQu2djMPo@mtGyFZcRRpbovA9is2Y6paeJRQ7sNHW/@EZZsYkijQrk@C1lxKmvcTqx1iXUZzvpa1HVP8zNKr9d22mJw0j6VyxxHnk@BYs6juMDsUddth@d3ZxCOluS3UO18xTqPZP0nf2cVNxeXvFv@dQyzWaM5lmeAf3bknmfo6uud3rk3LFNH9rnstPofh52egLpuejHS2npe8st5ivd@7LZvASMg/7oc1tnsHDQH12VqflDD5MfUv/prFevf1t1g21at@oe92r78mSQd9491ef/ndrsfD/gTpEhXjo3YpojmmxxnxVl93fmMydQt0dDeP372PR3VMLI/1z/WhuT0vzjM8W057PIdO25/E8PvNN0TDLDLct@fmsYuG9PDjeXymReqe7Ccd3Y9XAmQ19eXP6V41PiZ8ru9eYQCu6NzYmrwawSeygrEpFjSv1zPoQ3oy9Lv1vNcub9WUdHnJ5aJ0lF3wmsrOvyyN/Hr9vV@Ru1jspSyAYvJr@eEYx81FKpuL5mXhSispv9cSxFin0hF@hovwMWW1t@QkkkQwQGAfXS7qlwkoX@G8liJ@rL@AMLOLBOZD6MmaQx0tK2jqLSB7W7z5PS6j2fq0JDHBBmkSs2NJlLjNr5xmc0imZXxKusSATS0AfV6X1WznK6yJjJn0ownLSVT6faR8waql0FHV@bRe9OuijaTars8dCkfRlO4G2tLrq7G9pNBB87rSNtxpa1MfF5XMYqK@21XYDI1r6YPQdJHKlgWTpEbtUBxNaY40pHIlJocurtTuEMGV7FxWLNXdcHv0NfuW4glNhQxb1ujUePhKWdGUigq85OFzs7aUNLGbi3xmWVSrYju0SVMaLqhmu2goBTylfteGKRsNfVfp3yHm6n6IzWe64KpDsFV71Xe7LmqKYeMS55hD@haQWvWF5lckFdVUl0ufDhVHc0gTh3HooqvtU8@huTx2Ekaoc4@LuLaEd1jh25J4OM/W0F7PVxQWoJeelzocLh77frrcq39FZqOfreC9HHqP5pzW@l7rm29rXauCrz09N4Ec6FuQPFo/pWp1t@0UAcKQjzXJ2d305ffbrV7@UTtobuucoyzqc2ezIvp2KqPq4fpu20V/o3msss7XtrT5fa3Hvl1DGHGq9Xzq5q/l3FGrtL75uyz8fvqnBn/GY4n4dF2shT4sJg9pT1/oSw1hYA9r0Z/TLFAPi1Vfno7UeLg/@vb3uRa9v21ZCf86hYVyvbS6aO6vJPCQqhdrmNJiuZxta7IviYJV@WDfzam21hIpoXOvhMZoSn2MCJqtV1QSVS@AEKr2@TcxjFJxd0qwahRLmxxzUILl1C2Qijn5RkmbY89I7/zZnwj6c6S8ltj@6XOvNNrAyki4rQohWzW@KR0K3UG6bw0ZQdlRL1LbeovmFCsrvLTkaEpgLuXmVf3hRSlWkujN@nQ0JVoXzSslu9Stfyw//0jzDp36@QnVv1LHaynLJ0n7LEWgKwyJ67UfxT2a@zu6xnfubt8V9vmue37udt/vGe71kyHDquftTq1X3eivhPT2GyOTYXX80dw7KeBQ1@3z68n0dnTUEICGPqm/Bfzy9VOc2ne7218TurG@8WjNX340V8R4P6hCfmGPHZiUPne4KsY7ZvfoG19dDGrZeqSO7coYYUS9HtWxpnisj/vNgJT5raNwbNQPs7k@BiJtmllZZtsVAAz9oCyAa2S8c0r4kqarZLzTlBLUMF0n4wXh7fLdx5UykE3TqpHblO6W5EIdba6WEVaHYC@UHHC9DMD7XxHw4YoZWXlWT5bhWV1hSUi0Cob7bkfwHJqum4Fho5X2Tbvb1Qy8KkOX0VpNZQOt4G9uEqpy0AUjqqrkrnMwJaJK0xU04Bh3l0nYrqHBXPAo2cdVNN59BXdqYDK1Z71J4mtf6XPd7RhCRTEF19KIpgRk8cRdTQPZLr8b1ZP0xmdZlBZtLu3HBLG0S2d9dd/tWug2uenqdTIH@hYE87trNthSgDjtyhrXkLRojq@2Bpd9foq4625EOX10f/U1qC/qK5yvwsYHnWupcqV6CyxyLv7QrCZMFuErE/HpDkfTYsSdmIGqLjyG@LXUhFbdhWfZwos@t@pxBwJwXGrC@siYvy4j3z4l5RSVUrmE3HtVpv61EDOFKWSn9p@S8qQOjo/O@Z27rPicFX593U8bmiTn9wzXKtLRtLR0R75Xb/E2W@bxXytT99fQTix3a1jHcmlhawouuHoFFQbVv@T@1etZ9llX2F8ljvd83@29Xy0O9MlcUOP5qnH0Zqnu/rt6HPE7F@SIHnNFjm6obDTnT02OeX@KcvxU5diWFO8sQHrefiw@3vv9qcxhSG@jHrFrc4xmQXOcFlfnGKay0Pzqc@AyqNchfutbDEOPaX41Oij2oK8JEVffeFxLtEfzq9MxTV5rVExwpY5piDTNr1ZHMj1VYORTjQff53Idc371Ouay6DyaivLn@wfljuaxZn3PVUXFRx6r2yPWofWXUIfn23otjt9Ru1SvL0POyXNZW7@v6QgGTDTFNZDs0X7R17ZePwI92lv6j7I/mTHtQ50ScDoXzKKukNJpdd1tygulUVxXIFZGFxuIpisQwDDQvkni0O@W4SYd3a5qgFiO9mMy@IoxkTVyT57HlRIQeNI@31ni9S1iiZdNgHPr7xZLvOyHLMyibxwTa7tIy3JFh6z@6rsd135A82H63OsqEdTwGy7p8tWT6GmpudCLK0/E2ulyFCQXFRvshCd1tztdzSKGiEtcYA4p5ojAjGy5fr8KGf2aYtKSu6z6KRiAw0VkXHUjNYBdRqa7PkcWM1Ohlme4ksd4TIWpxVX1UZ79fEf3z7lnfle433XJuOhuVYhMtWpchiT1WZbr1rhgCQouy5VrhkubDLx417hZLoISTffZ@KhFFLxx/6YYiwq/4DGp8gv67Cr98n7fbbCYq/jL@/obj9cUKHYFj4cwXr3jDOw6H11fqRikVn2F8xWVeX8qzbz3Kz8TO6tr0qAQoedFhHC6Cs9X0iZl73R0fMVvUnJNV5hfmZz@UzsHcLv6l@CMep1xr2@BuIi@ECpDuluWLdHR9lPO5/2p8dN/V/jnpxrQ@CkRNL@6QWN9xYSyhJquu7@yQ0Q4/Az3K1BU1H41v1JG86e@0Xy/okezf5WQZv/KI83x1Uwiqe0CROurrjTXV3Jpbq/rrBla7VMTxFWITHmk6f2CzUm7CJAy7S3jo9q0hFT76HARqXgu71kp6@HrfvsbmCDterHpeS9EvEM75ECOWG9B3QAXPmreY1MQ5yuR5P04qyWpz/ZXVYuyQNrRR9b61LnLRbmodCCbYHxU15YqG/qa@7rQ1wAEqi9/mkuCjZ@6IlnH3Ee7bZhxTMnNyJ/snXGWC5LBjJFtNBDI1ZOhi6HnPddFzsb5Kp@Na@pwVhSQfYb8uKy2GHG25aJp6xWlQNl9A3C6ev0u24i4SLIcMQ783ZLpq6PXtidBgOYSUY/t1PlYJIfYgm1a5Cm@c7vt3wmJVAWlnq86HWuRnoEa7LKr57Nd3A7NCdng8zFlHFys7fWZCZU6l/iiKi2la65SVZ8fgJCE@heQo3wGyrjrW8TUtH@RchG@27YvMttxCcDZrv2WmTU66ro/FQTRTj8@@tofAs2icZZyQrrua@oOxbPsZ7FxaPxC3ZdPlmw@vcX7@W9gY66LaT329Sa6ti671ewXzv56vsU4tQ9JHWbNTWxI@ZszFaR13a/KY3hOLv04kwmic4@LRM7Y/uXz/kgvoHpr/zhWMxeejKZ96Tm6S1QSGHTdsTFdzBIqhXz0OSwRQVkw@/NwGP1u49r3n6W8osJhjhPAxtD6O@dXiRNxBK3VRKsVf5hI1@tbzOlYRSxg/StDth3XmOCJXYjsOAYypyU32vyJl5CIGz7aHFtB2EB71lzdcZgwOby/kVNSzAaopfbCMFgd30nAuN5ifdVSZ9IwdPQ6bhRP7mKrEw6j@mxbwiQp14pHzd1dwBUNAsWuEKKTTYD2gL8bMur6mns7JsbTytbA01D8DFkaj5LzONYWBopL0qaYv64AcFHXPV9F23ksCUNBNsf7KCHuAnUpIaXrmgpE03HECWXCBdoexxzntXQNpdwcn4ymC/cSo1Isc@aaoCtMxz0TpKS73eUYaeLL9I2TLqUrXBcYXj9Vh1eKK@poc5w2FVhV/IxEsSqifVJANB3/XVntVOcux4rxI/QWIAtcj@05KqlMOMYxaAaqegeFK/UZHCMXfiNkpWpw@IAqEVemlurVvV8RO5eBpnl@ytg5vo6MugvZtetY/Hq/UUIV2uWjbbmYHcViXAnPElBwJjwmV/rwOjqdO0iqvJ437F@NdTJb71c4zzmJ9VqqilSJ8xert@7Cdt1luWlel7br3XkRiO8ubtencyhhQHp2w3PXnF/IN@sb9@PczMLo1Xj46qMQdXpc5A58p84dlv6ihJ/zQ2F@eOVaKXuno1OUIor8Oe@0xlZJdHJ5XidjBRKtiKbzWbDFrov@Nee@EO7@KQ/oPFns1irZTtM5NYowaLWHyObvFguPdoYVq4L2Cyjm2kUWEokaD@vbccI2dQ5wLUu@wSV1vnBlVMIFCb2/xToqqhHFCZ2HXHC99bxrO2e5Pmk6EpnOb8apXTvv2s250GiKcsSI9d5NR2tHTx64KyBaQg9f0flY3EaL5xIm6ANQtqrEdEgUJ0Ew0pZdFeU8LgqUkqbA@Y9rCA7iAq9oouRnwsyKOSao3kjt/ZHMnKqkgvx87OiY7GIupTR4MyYTiQZWm/ka1bTuQTUQqQhRR/ZOrn7cXL7fRpKBMovr/RgnqeuaVFHJKICgBRlj5O8LXzc2GIERsYfhjTTH4GaS15lIUm6Lnr3ArR8X@qLSyM7J/7vikOi8jNfibS@KCjMLMR7N2bMbXw4eoyUANvqh99pLYZe4DyBWa/HHIDupyL5FzZyp4z9dxSDeZGbqaTax61MoNTyRnzBgLNqE9GZTMPulvmulipvJ6BcayDPEkAFzuTs2ylLibfHdsmDvl57j84LIUKccYG4zTRiVuRrQjbsyCekpEPWXDjkfd5TAtgh0yFdgXRheReB13d4fkVLe1LgBTCRQOhGLjaBNdzU1IkBffWG0mp/E/Us4YuZXTqaCS1Pic88kvqqsXPQC2efXWzuoczjOQG4fSTjBlhvQ81RZDp2qjMUaxxp3BozUvspXnXIm6Mt/6XvMHrrk/FRF3OgdPCYbUGGHYmDAhFRZkjx@jLHtcksxfMIgh7KleCO6uSM52aLM8lQEw83sZQMmLfgV@YRpcrOq3SPiDW4jrgYAMUtEs2LdT7TrJa4MTPZc12J8iM7D4pHJBFA@CQC9265/SBJQB0EF6HA9D7CC43pD9BWimgptMBIABfRvt3gRG@jIMopwszIXufuX/elZPgutJtV/YdM4IAG/qvEUL05c6afEQPAHFY@vXCzjDaZKTF6JvsM8pi7LEKwx87c9Y/3C5sOdYka9@ycoCsrvfjsRS/Fl3zdIBLYNBdCf/bhqB2OJ5JG6gLwWqYX4HMLGZw@G@71FTMslCN0ZVxVLZwCY5Ke@85I/enes1csF6FBoGlBJXJDwJe3gRDasmD3x0z4d90wm9/shVg/KhQzP8ckC5jpMhYLHg@SkOam0Jbn6/cR@MkXsBudGEQEidq6htWODZgxJZHZnUPiQ61bVTDQmyE1uhUNnwUfm/aJO0QsEyklB20UGBv4A35QUAP2XVNAmTCdO1ZuluWR7okQdo5mCoZ8vvxhKVeZLxVWRxu/UPpGfexb1q7nbp5xbHTctxE8MBJMJTIXK5E3C87A/2nSI8oLDpF6W/CUWSGjNbLiSqE2mRW9fFjb6HRnNMb6a24AYwmqjgIAjSkQEwXf2bpeWsiOZa1hfzV@qY/YUijJ4lmUGKuEVF22AvEO/zDSrNz8R9eDGa2gGu8ti23FZNCiwseKn/XlMteq4oo7@von7TA/AJXyzeOHzQ3oHpsSzbeqJak9FmigmKmqKteZhwhR5QELkL/UcgLBKu4SvzO/EGUBhsiVT0WGvm5WBsKmVDh8ZlRjYssYMUGu2iqAZnrcpazyHdgWAxHyCfb2gJ4AHB7R/db4Sp57Vtt3/sTYM5vYyRYNAL8kTHBiFoGgjzDWhLNYbgR@IHn@/peWhrucdS2xZqhAhm/kQB5feRIoEPV7UE/VJDeFPMYjt92RVkStCZDx/cqCOOG2NlSrWUZJCqoAVtkuqBLOGSLWLSNwik24R1dOzOHQXJIKSww8R/t9loeJ6hFXm4zQDKziQ@va4iBzaSmOkNo3KhGEuzPP8VHEm4rDRqBWmlvoLaM4w6lUc7lRdiK28Q5gw2JxIQFd0EfXFiXejb5gzIdHgVkUmkR8jMDpfZeFOlud9wAsYMh7byaaM/VeQkgopzOr3QwSdrJw@KUCkL4b5BJXxiF/zZuEeip0YmxGfjo1qwjE0eTrGzRyf8l8K8/M5rl6QfBBSaRYbwVO6XyqQLTFrXw@xjyAywkF9fkquU1YC4fNvyCIYsB9oqXaVQWbhSS1L4l9A268Yz@tcMhbAbpbrVqZhGAPB1Yyp7hKDkcSEq38muyBuI38CNYEswCddt@hZykRT7cWv1lsW3IMTJG1xygXE9zZuhCGPDgojc6li50LOmUny2DlIsgNBEAXeLyq7vJuLkCHDNynyd7SAILBashEmX8UXYQaOTxsPH260HzE6UIqIjX7ZiIecSD6q6@/CjooD4JeVtI7HnwxOF1Hk0@H/G8hKWVv8g/jm03WsQQGjSnxcVzAj/Bspca0EPWPoKHMZAwtkESvqSjMBEN6kbOCeYvzPZL4sBDlEG4dffmNaGZWPIl3MxLDYHEeEuDSzuNBrOTfEDhYlC6QANaosH7NTYT2@zUVLw6HNBH2mBa4aSh2zZRPdl0Rg1lSHV3kMKSNIivqp8sV46YPiSlcg7wtBEZ3e6RA36KmTJROl2QWDI5UJXWTlINCUsnCqn5kZZHTmVdeSlQjS3/xdULunCpOq0KLxE/sdycMr1/ZlQYuxoqI8HbHSk5BwB86ouoixL6WOhE9ipFHdVrp0D2Ga8RHDSZrFkg3sU7I2RCp4PewSQXEfIEpUXdIa/gDZH5RsVmKIRBfBEGWgwp2ciO2cuV3uc0Aomi4VGO4P9nD7yeFH71NG6EusIPZA0RykForVGUsRk3U714y5DbCvOQ4HSRx8G1gnr6IPFVHBWqk0zuiZr/qkWqGWoU1j/yd2kAWwjSVZtHAUHPr8yRmDWEKufLuEDPxfnKPXE4bYQ2zHzn9jS@IAYT@49uiTufYH3npNEKK4gGu3sXodvgwA5cd2@kgBuXeI5trwE162yeViciQfYQJb7j5XZihKW3ppqVpHCt7FiSFF9PQHJFiXYdQ3o@SqBL0e7EYSicNciptj/XxxfV6OyhRACUWZXcCcngxFNNW9hHE2LIp0EkccXdOVK45pevDvWOEkgt6zPu82WYiVgbgUlqY0Djse1Ec3AE5A4RpX1wVCFuNpo5tqDdwN5rhvI2QxF2JhwmRRhY8EYmXuS8VSD7Lng1IDqrYGkiZN2qlSwNTpZYUx340oBoURs56U1mbAR7gDMnuoSxJLKOiMSu2vJIKvhLV8cMQwtQh4qTRxDLTYmk/V8i7Tjw0kJbUdhWG294/0Gv2HDMawMvaiMBSQ1K80R8xQrLHzSjuHeAwzRtU8oG/uqjdUE/WmBNlCNPy7ZdZTbs2AswW7K7aujCipNjlu4D3NqohhOG@klocUUtGmeEErOApLieSk2G1Lpt83c@SPywe2XGDDUIjPcU2OiwEzE@Agt/RmeY71KWWjZB/GJJVs7keTpsLwV7ocPwe23THpHKE6hu0j9B7VzJC/7B/iSqa2kyVMFRa/bR3xLJaYQ9ZiB4cYMjktJ6eRK@3wDFXqLsytZIZ@CZjwZ2EG4h@pDBsIqRdpM/t3O0EGb@ELpBZC7u@jZMUqB2D3OLGcVmeqlUhFis/eZ36k@tixwhGwYGM61pQnvTHYxVTQeaFywYdzkfOU/ySP1BX@wpPGzFJm9b25kfVjJOxkhKXR4tohYZCgDfG4cBzyGhATMlpXsby1Mjs4f/dlB9mO24Rcz7tg/hsS/YIbhO36LX4d/@f81CIeWdgLZIoh5kwlgmra1gC4p@Af8eLnd8Wwn@dHuCXD0akardrJbyaQmOpWSSRokYGq69Je0N@Tvasq6RQ5e2GxNjHvVxJYOkLMjknELOYDflqiD7sjTAVVUR65KBHJcEKJQHNMOgaCqk2z@@WSd7sVOk9PdYppWS1CmW@K7VpDm0VkUb14SSqOqXxG5sPKOse@Qr9tSMmUVQUv/X5kAlhBAEvQkS7BB1D5OXnlqCcW8h5p7MbiSd4FSfePmZTQ4qribe7wQDr6ILlm@CwFNucPpLqng3uHE@Rw9w@qKy7ijbzV0yx0/KZc1O4pxlnalEjkPT9lOAm6Qu9n76n177BFxyKQADlllxbOyExpvo9Di285DQ6JoTaB/f2QvOPdDrto/2RPKQWCee7aOan8TsRW1HNyFITCXishEHDMft9WxQbzeLcLaPeEyjDtrGCQMlQL8lalRGd@s53cdXnRYRvjLuxXNEFqcuQdH5lu/GRT5Xwfp9zjJ0mn64K8EgOjzmR3AR9YceHKZxr/sQg3YU5S/K7FR7VZMsdGhiLNGVNqpnhHSdSxFWTpP6mlIfIfCyW7ftn2bLBoOdpPBCGBnjzAjWlsDqTxdJNcuzNWDMxOG@@4c4nV2ab1AJjKMJED2kScyYNX2lr2TSw7ndCFykW8uIF4ZK4Mf0BlvgzwmsHEUgaFSVa3B4e8FXvexwh9s8Is9cGUtseOehNOapOWmiTAq1/NrBft6Z54x1rDkYijlLkBcQjXp7DubQbRZHWSUoNQva29CNKQPe8qdJaxW9HeYSAyxLcFnqCzHfCyLmae@Z03B7VeHx1M2K6tOZ0HqJbga4IOFIwGKLdyTVIWCLYi7PSP4Ze1ep6sTuoxO5Mt263EzeJziQt221ojcbIbm1V20E7qb1YyV/qJqsiDOL/ghps5yoozJUZIhJLMggW2YtyxLsQip6AUndBilIK@l@gtRcBKy1KbMhtj3JUYg2pPk1jAb3OpefC2rI1TiWyMrRhrqchiCi71zUdCK2u3AMkFE/4I9psMxJXRHHn@M7WyAW99IYawRTNjIkomOYRL/Ev6yrAJQdghu6QCPKyklAURVul9ElYbz37sTlHggESyq89kEY7MRsrxu0kSy8D/h45IrUB@qUJOB@MmiRiyhi6VGmcTnyNlFrLsZzfF6UV9ce@KZfzomtviQLModneWaPk42GhsF89WD@6MXxMadslrUBAwAl/j1pCQiPmKv3mlpE0RD4xYpc2T7kGtqPGab41xEFt9SkOJu4xmM8JL/RNnOTMz79sQxQy4v@lzDGtG9t@ZUO0iwcuioMz/JUrP6uEiQwTbWwX4LEtEXgQSiasivpAdZ1bLnN@TILyewmGSwuOP3WSeOXbGSz8JeDYgwr33rE/AZo8d/thdr6uvxH1iELUfGluYF4AEu4CIEISI7mJ7mjg6n6zB14S93oCnHtLoKp6SnmFatnL0w1DoOysQW6Qs3mOgeijC0JvmRG44ikwSEmdG7S9An9im2KOuNn@yWmir7b1ERmI7RqAEp91JSvKGmXWpsmB4cWSQtchnf8cQidncnI7flKj6Hc2NqnH4gwcVLXUJRjnj9eOhEIFj2d3uNmL@IwVXtXpmgXdEyKzoG1PgED06S15VWGPYDg8hS4VjwaXAvSNNohLz9EtPxXKFTSEkoLnUjRzNQDWjUmAcggjg/TNLblUTKrtjBVeg7oErwj4maDjwtcpAuNB6SwIJYL/2SVCNlMg1PyzMZ8D/VwUDWDfZhzjyOCJE2Pbu0oit/BDBMeDpRr@8qFWx2KsEwmQ5o3jdB1oPZy/lMrtI2qxERFD31QoE0JQ16F0/khvJM25ZqEb6qEi@juz6Ci33hGWgMKRy1eypqJhv@e@EaxeP5zJFiOJAIum589TWdiFSL6RzqpteMg8btvInJU3wFU@xOdaAwN4BzOhYK0qYgH/JYQnxcTK9m5GdCthkfOMZ21VjN2Js4CDHV3INiVU8yMf0uzXSfrcLtkpAE1xIpWdfgFGHmrmf7AtdGl3bfnCQYNNzc5eIcuqSEOlc0v1Fd6azcWc0z1I1CRbxQEdRHGPyWpm9J5igmJgy6hB9RDz3fQ2XS85E2ElDQI6d@xtCaQYlkN9nix@Wmnhjc0I7YKXolRK4sduAxp8SH3oTYNNwzSo5i0IUy8AzFLnCKiTXCTzDUxUQCRyxLQxadFFyY9G/e1TyM8flK9oE@Q9WfcRZjyGEO2Noj4HPbym0xbxTYa14wj2S4a66O7msktRrFmdaTGIQih87Nr5UnL9ewyFeKHB44yDIHEQmnyfAKxL4FA265xoHyRNQ4ER9hoxN2vKuhk72GMTctQRhiiCHT99/6gWTgsBOkgoMks4jN@Ov/sFI0bHmlTezOxDslSIiO4bsfn500zPI3YSpOL8EOL4McDlphPUMKIIYHMeLNYCDiUbyR4k4ib@zJiX4OJBfr@rvEAFJHNqnxAiGA7DLysLnVWOa2BsVSyQ@lNY1elLHKl2H@BnDqkAXcCPQ9bM24Ei6xvlhUWax7AcZNeUzCUjj91CzUVVNKU2F0KplzmaGJZJrUesE6Fxi3pJDvmQXwNlAF6qISBKsMMZUReiQC0jbX2FYvj7eT/RJeU@UR2FuVI69dipMl1V7gLMQ@/xOaALOCMil4cIwmGIPTnaXw8iUAiDfTEIg9Qy@gYoCHxEZPAm5ejklC9EK0E@fXCBmA1KOW6l9VoyV8nw2NkCSoq1q0hcMihoTFrKgRnJZeKLHMqYuedGvhGt020uKbUt47SVPE7Pmnp@i1DtHZbkn6EdkEXqtO6megDWg4ropMYYKrCQHY4/EPRif6B/648BwYfpKZZtY0k5g24eNHGSupmnru@eSn1yNL0AMeQ8vRrktMAEbPfEv3XnIfPAVjuAfGY8GEje2wNd81ywseq4rUu7EL1PW6VgKBX7QC/i7NiAYTzdrLUmnIPFYWQb7E/FnVYcD/ShXczKjOiQ91@GonCzfIm136gMwQraEOBmJl7Lr@I@C78dHolTBdUEWHEnQ3s@HtMP7nWzjgmS0rP5AVFzGzUo@LQFLBU1AucHPat5viZbHDhAbzTYbaQBiZDAbIUtOjFi1tWAHkt7ERJeJRLwN4JDllAgYRII@hFcq8oJATNypfYInGVOOu/4O50HkGByOazlS37ZqIMgWO@RewM3cHxmShPQ/WjZ3fk4X3EAwNgywmfLNypgSZKyisZJgucBes0LLU1NmoTNBuWzVmWaaxnBEmXpY9ZE0PXPKeHoKLo0UHXWZPYrRPoy9Siq/WWGb4GaX3tjJlFRGSl8FcNFnap@QKojDlTa7YKLUAcfTW46xvABELrq8isI8QD8HE1KizWB2UbaOySgtWSwwFnwz4CaUJ3Agr3U@e5b8QGtS6CeY7qQajBl9UnU31fOkIjspR57aBJY2Ja@Nw3abczETTA5A8qmaq7E0xy44zfKO8Tdv8lHNtCS7@4wvMfVigQI8HJ8ocRjrWRa0rnABumOLP8eiOQyUJ/kUpn@nkMnJAov6LkACepI9qlQsAQpQYlLk7UhIL8x/VYHtFCQGEy569ECtANBZk5bimygFYImPEOSQKd/KvCnbl/I3PyQ25C0oSXXFxp8prUwM8gO3Ju6E1fmH9IcrA6r2/XS23kTMvMOByQudiqCW/K6YhIAuWCEMIXtI7A0j@pL7F7ZflxOMQs6Txd@mifcLIOMdLk2cqk0PtYEcJsraaIBCVAkkNlyMfrT6HNh7IMnxyrWNsLLNrHPvqk3EJQiNrPtTMfgmQshRIWAvRDyaVIFHGnsI4juRS@727GamHNG6@PTTnHMQyelDNxNRCHrGE86sP1EeDPSYQuBpl8EiJ8SXgPvrJyW/Q/nEV4GSmF6HPIV0m3sO685lPETeW9ndI6FmvgwOwG0G2VKSAwfYpRRa1ox/Psmz6E90WJ79I3YKDhApSoPCgL2mTOPUNRJOwgbSndDis@7n08cek8zF74OJMbLJIu4prgOBRf41sM5FEMb6b7gjCsLGqCT4MKXgS98AJwY5oYQmKprQQawLNzJIb1rNZhzzbibvkZCgHJ0Qc7mtrE8p9ZJkBPOrAmipY8dSSLLstY2RiOS3aY2KLQNMe/yyS4FzYEi@Gaey6hFWDrbv@wNBmRCy0XeoAZL10Vm2XFAb@yRhD4B2LNbQ00aDPPUohMeqTNTLwnvkVCDkqBxVS9gGGSNXM2lpuCA00HWfWKYTLSMF@VQKBundyhJ7EwmQRcN@AGHEYgEQvIbhx1pOiO6Krh/PmGVsjhRiF@GxJwUmXGcnMc9Jya1NCR8TLI9DLMRJCLaTiHi1ozKjQB0pvMAzZjLkkTY@iR/Sjn192nQPVVpxG2T@LkJTrMFWSGZHAR@nClgPojDY@yqYEM/EMwDLlWfb8cQz6lnARvZWEkYfD3BDOB2Q4S27jVHEXMGLKG849W53SXfXvtYJasANryhVZfVZdJzEIX4BK8blbAmzYFCOLebjYsiBHndcNWX1AAefqxI2qN1RILFfTRioRMAJXAXtJt3zm/gsSVmd/ZMThDhGQTjroS4iZ2TgxieY8JI6RlKjG8I/4dzHONS0BC4@R/qTWugSdQki4HdahTF1Z4bIap5lLIQYBylDFXbbKLVjD771LmROlsl8sADwPft0cVQmJtmj15GMFMB8Mkisz/1mMVfcu@aqOiBq48RpMAPy4yjDomOxrTyOIQTrVuwf4kQgkF/HZnH20KOenybthplDsQZBZmPOIWW5rTaRSSJyrs1E0dxSyBg@jyUXEmdNaNNfIzmWCAqbD071sZ7Va79KREl3e@TsDYY1iYOfMmlh@mSW@nt2ao@BCJbaO1KLTybGjrgshA@Bg57fycplaUSIj82RmZfaUAQqtQG08IapfjLNxodq@GZKW5WO45Rw4fAyZapS7onI6rG4xk5xT6A4KjqGm/VkBa1jynecnkF9l6ucGXomPa2AMJnvzSY/JK080x9EnUD4tnCdYIvP5B01ubcbxflhmjSWbJh6uM3mwZ63EstXxRtekpuphCata6JhmDRT6E7ov9FDD1grh8mzukgs@5/mLaIfaBHIA6KWIkZMDDibDdjkJ8XDtqX0Ooi/MDjdj2FTP5n3sUTGA0b9ma4eh4BtdnKztDJ5FqrwXFV0icuDrTop3FAGLqKVKZ5TOwmwzE4SshZKEO34z8B0ZPDGFGKkuPgaK228HGJdpurAk07GpKirZBBIWUCTqq0mNnwgwin5YsBSVrs8UhzHu7kZmXitcItyAgvhtcxR1mAMq@18QUKgU8gATpcB6MQ/HxgdYvRh7OKZfYTqNwOYL2Fnl76C4mqGOYMfOGP7CZsyMa/QiWW9TyTSYu@RrDElBgC2hnkqQCeSynSqSIFpMruoZKoZh2@MdVfmIdHdS/Vl0@Hg8JXpoTTpJU6XUncWQwDaRUpv9v1BJlJ1eNjFHokNXl218IBBE6Uy7wCNwZUMBzFs6CCwNXdYcBC2BsCLJh4oYnEnV76PK4ZGDbnJpqo4GIokzRvEs6MU0l1VcLPmcW77BBStfkDIHAYrOcGP@oU989kyqWSFB/F4nwHkSdwt1klnkLBtQNGsH6ehZ@iHuIXjVzyxFWdImXIfnlkTm@KZQCQ/TZQB/Y6NQwkjpFJBzNzmTumwawhJuGATeKhcG0TQWsRSsgK3WdexECAadocrXN7UXiB3Iu05YsME5sWkxyseSG56@ccNg60yPu8mphIbEzT7WrcnqpiJyjYzHwoY0OX3OkCWaecLXV6m6Um5erwsVcxlSyStA36tyExsoXxaYvwVZcL8Z6V@hoqm4RTi9aWUtGx4KqSYM5KREMLE8VPN/hggmY8kyebiCSshbSA9H5ERgEFMosqyRkkbswGMbQMNABFERdfhSD1LYNXzfupEhBIhz4isCE2Ot/sRekIClyjH/IT1zky9bbsoMws3P2sr@b9ArzEWreT/Em/JknrTaew3tfMUcJYOAviLvaT2/rJMg@X9nbYcZe5T8MLA2JyOK4taKXgeY56xsIwu5bPDtCT@XNv@Q2WfJS5abwnwfP1vUD/wm3pK8SuAX6I0e2tYxBWgst8PnA9kKmZsjII@rcgUV4ylHI1HaxDCE5mJl1b9RALrqfuj8gudtblKkasaIBHPjM2aRr4JLq0st63SWRkQq62hsozozrGKvYq/cjaElaPKL2/GGGFtWNj4EmmOjX/aUHqlcq1Kxfi373aXz4w85OKiVHqSUOCeWIyuUBBJOVM9x/hulDuxvFM8EN/7vM3Z@NuTuoNhX0GRlmEZZqdkT0AeYKxASZYYZIKOIWDJ8OrFVLmPKJGEvlijXbRlraQWpFiI5lnWwcGTMGkA7EHq8WRnUo6M@MXbjShrydJ9P9YJewxdMT6e3JuEgERo2AvYGeo97JnbqSjSdT0rDEnSIks/QrVWWIhdhXc5rj/D1IzdpKXCrSieWSMK9KQyZYxRAi/ip2e0e2LmWv8nlUcgzH4a4/NmyBDMlWpZg@5ahN5V6mwkbfpmlCKBBElpy6TNEsurZWi6bQEHKK6eLEBc1cfqzIBKVvGpCjvB@2KVO4nFxwEyMmV8Ed4kuvbV3QHrxHz/qji8VexwMfMK5zsSocokkgcORC63YNFLBilJYt/9kzvGvks2kLAVsWi@6DsnWLXq1yECjeiQNWEVh3mdsDxJ@9iuSUOCm/AB2gpOnXQKNLFsyrEjIP9m/llj4JD6Adn0SuaMmQj51lWQABRgyl5HDlNf@8maZbLeOcR07wD92S/ZXLpgPzFjWISpOUiGitQOa@cwSBigAYFGqs1RIWJkPcMOBqB@nzIfjEGYnyCcAbKwAAn6CemJ6sthhFc5V6BYcW2pM8@kz/Bk/BizEqdmnetOIqzG2Ik@AkbHh0rxgddlswHBjswP5xoHAY4giaIP0FN3RlZXFcVNba2ukuawuYkY4EFh6y1KHycIegkiPqECQbzIcl6oMSf5v169Z@aroabaqXh7EQmZDjogR4u2QrL4Do4OXhabznQte2AOSCxhUu@seIicRN06nchMJFHkmpwssa2mos8DWRpAx5g1BA8RqUZcWYUHUUGGt4Ur23ZpYOyM2j@1DmISsCqdjXNLlCaxEF/xs87CQkGvdPgnQAJZsIS4T9L7IWxBCiffRwEHpcRRecveGCzzcAex1a8UkVH/YjYRIeeFJ1YPGDCVDV9galD9hquA23xG6k2JXNhzQKJlAeA//TT4OirUzhIKIJg6Imz7KQH3XMtkbmY4XvklP8nnIWv3bOnhZVKTaq1woUBsJeeU2qplX92TsouJJMXu36mCsJo35womArpPkXXshgeuUb0Y@sUA7EgfJi5wvanB2BWhxLVFbIxqarAYCPgTsN9Wb0Qg57xZPprM1klNmwNUtjxocP4FZd@pEkSGhG8ovnxP7CL5c4AH8AmJBmLZlmuMeu8dWcMyAbIdizQ5thaXPklaZR3FVk28JGG7T16FshvEmjM1MxMm8tWHTYgSoTIMT8BFwISAkguKwTckzABs55IT3@iGXZWnGVRoSTxWWtaoecMQI0hRWXSIN8UIg8O7UtXI4pLIKDJemU3g6QBX8mWEeuFWT1a/BNsAgAw9QMalAnQJGyXpBYxvZGAewuR0ypB0fopbpDrBSHwqyJra9xJBeLMULp/qEMRsqTdSVZOBcLSqPIkPnBTl9qW0@e8iSEDPo12Q8a/X0r3ZRS8JC3zKmZUsZqbbyrA9MCdixgFKe/qtKM34iSlhJUBGIoCbmGlSYabY4QhnqCeFmLDcCBJDMFRh7Z3pwwHOAkT25GPDOntcsQ1RAso@giTP3AFs8jatFh@zmGeASzarqDv4o2ZiHPWp4QqleAiRSUYBxp1L8g3qOTKlRtLpEYPKkJTTJNTWSe5I4nCTX/qmBk5Zi/hr6MQljyL2ckBJoOslHQWI62F2kkfu/G/lkB5fSbXNTM3s68n5yMQ4Lqe70WVn5KVELJDfRsQDBXyXf0@bDG2lXHZiJiDIaY4TEByCZgOURG6owI2HTciMyLG1QnkPZ5o9Go32T98OgQeWCmzNN8XXCZVacjjGyknlgySQn/w7NuAnD02mnXEOLIUlGRgdFCNR0ojjpyd5i1M0sADxC5QEHAiuMKhZ7Hk0fAwYgEvUK7yT3jKXyvAbqciRBT2060Pb7qk0lmtGT0RmPXyKVjy4oCl2wkk75QNU67lzelKMUh8qWbGxLrDAlS4Ow3qRgE6RJWRVdqZQaql50nXsYE2x@E6mlLprpccUITrNbk2ClvGdFT6EVSbthyRLcsLYf1NYUcZ3ieYRIoKZ3RJ9nd6EMgwAXp8E6MWboae8bkp2HyNNUiIRpQMgB9jbVDjZxkRh08c@DnQhxUCRoyGl@wn5Uv@JGhkjdzhwMnHH/W1wCYslq0hQjN7eabCua91GclKgZy5m40k1fOIqTpAwR1p5VGS94/lT4KlJTPpA6MEtIPjQgXp03JJHlU@JKpBC6cQVcHhn6gEQI66/twzcsWhstjQqC6Ccu0wSxZEg7ZEhOrZ/WIhnKk6/iVm01MwGawItemXtMemdE22i3PDOKtmdV6UG5PsVViOfxr4GRKglWvliVnZV35u5SAGRz5IamDnA3s4V9J3MJRSimSK2gMaR23ilpNmzslF8ViSNE1BdzL5W/nLW1yP2SFBrwLBlPvYCtItNBDyONAqWW0vqOxke7b6s6RmewZZiFZ9wM1r7Kh3G50Y8gYD6LC2ba/wKCyD0p4UJN5OVnhJTlmfjK5wUvoElhCg0ye@RycEyCBc10QCkkXxIw4cElWS9Vn0IEm0TQgWy8@tTvU512zRGk@CWpesykaIU5CFrhDuEy9ASDIW5O204vPls8SXCP2VBSMGzocgP2hcApADzDHiuLKokTW4FLkgew20nY4/3fqmbknpKrl/x9HQ5nhJ9AwyON@HS11h4O@MjsRGkDZLUf7bwI@@K2C/SGixw5EZu7rePPxvzjbg/Zush/5OicY9DZISudnIryXymPiBVJRzqYiShYUolJWA8MwUYW3f4DOUWxjHmT5qpWeF8DSEL0D1LK5ygFcUocHkfNuISONpA8QnapdIUJF60ce4R3ojyyLkgrKyTALaMzP755HDPyeITpGegYQ6k9jLsULgYLLiFRB@cEiJyZEhu5hG/nDZLUbxSbPzsFT0R@nc6b4xiF91L0b@eRQKxPkyoo1YKhgveJeB9gufJKZkfHHyxiPM1YJeSNyRZuw3jwPknLUdeOYOEJ8vC16wJc5uoOgODGmm3cLTLABeCm3QMaukYUYBt2Ee6RPjxTACJbJCiYLrIaB2EG2ZWHkIviDhWCrGm9ld6PdBF8HQrdwqbBXXH1KsDs5m5DubeMzMv2HMjZpnZFBUhpAwkLeVJCH6QvmPdA99AVagkkWFq4n5zqZsbZ3InwLAmCqm@TYJ7WfQA5TO2CJ4Qbe6p8g01MAcl2hIFsqndHkMa4BqWzpt13VFpeLNGSH@TQXKzP3ZS1YHzJewZ5TMSm2wwKKcxc6GwUQ0sFZRuudjgAFCQpyJpLyzKYG3cGdStkNmAg47acAdL0zOxDC94pepXDAoW9k1pNlhFKemW9b6gh@A5oJQc8@XJ/HTWhGHLWdRJm1nCZNzk@4SPBVFtA64jh4pxB1YZ2BKyfqkYwm6zUziPomEpIwswRnk@zDz27/f5wIX5fcitX4AmfEsKHhKnyAF0k6QFBKeYnylpRqG0g@fW01F6878JvmzYM2B1KfTAHFrpbD1J3UQrDFrrm9Mm9nfGJzYPqlaDnFYKNl7yrxTnhNgNvCPO65RfeAkNILrP361djng5WFiA2onQTwF9JhBY71QegckEZBxn7cKaSBgvEdP46c5AXH7Dkf/DK2HrBdcIQJwsGLZv1nwjfZLbU6dvLolDFqGTVZdQYAVu@7LRvgmDZI72UjiqGAhV2FlRjEN8IY8ccsax2JK32UlnI0yZziDoYAwFPL2L5u8DmhboOMy/hArGtHprEybQ0RPVkunilegkwj64XMyehVVxIdixhJGWfbO8M2ARfGLWd8r7kgdjU94EHuB87F5JkYSM7u2q9dh6ZEbCFt03iVywc0kNQGnD8ESMYaP3G5eDm91SwZvnYuOATpyQSrR40ZyIGYNvHasr2vzIcpHVWwhNPGmAI0IKPGZnPuQmypWKmRQnIbjVU4expc1FWB5lYOithDla0rQT51oUGNQsyCGBVnhSDBmQ286dC@YaBugD1C5xK4SKMlc5W44r9FR5fZwiAGoX7gCRLOBqVSbuUMeVqNWl1hG1HFGxYokggpqV4m5OKmKCYHRBnGcomWEFuBCSDbIjRAIylTzvVxsns2Jp7@O00f2wdNIQpH4ZRIQUzEzowMVHSCMdWWlKeLKURC@C9clJT/Qt8bqT8vU9C8ii1owpc1PyC9HYhuOfBYXA2yHhgVmQkiEVsD/UBoeSAmmewYYFhqVGMgRm0yyvEGmpk9Qd4kcrIYkko3CdSWAzkS8sfkLv1EVECi6tFwDlFA/H/GUdoowpGdwn6Vy4ipjdkwo/VMpLMRz8fXxWQLJAV2dJKoUlR4gNHAg6xcRmnyoszNlJJiPDdkphb79ffgkA4iaBSub8SToD0VZMNyZ1phB4hrzKAzahg0CEvMDYTvj6UXoGx3@eFIoY@S4EK1mhMaLYh7K0NWsxmQishJMZGAbfSlUSyI0jhWXwrkEYz5HcHeJUqfgc96NHlXAg1IJuz8XKyaK/PBPzpec@s/kZzNyBRjWGFEhagg8dA2@8yWkiCM/KiDEdaw0GMWP3SbrhRE2amiI7XxTiZKv87cOy8CDP8xASzGUIhBt8tTeDHOCNYA7M5KxCfd0r2VrD6h3EDMkhJ/8MaxQAPmBqXGkEesEeswSWA/xmV6NjizFyEhc1s94fVFm0JhDDWZn4Yn8g8AfTvsP3YRln1UH8dGcJqhRBJfr1JsEbCG8KDY@VwYPRM6A@M2yYizLeGpapM6YUmMf5wLil@hHSNGioV2KN1RYhDuSpIPptTEJCTxN0c00LYmzsqIm2KPw0Ub@ZNjmAyZhIqJtSRhdMGuH@zKgS8MQqpKAXiNDUhH6Qyk0Uec@MwyUAslLPFuga1YyS8SlwwWB1peuJHo40G8hoYDL21CBMhW6cILTBLgZUSgsiK0mYJ0Wh8PwYNHw2klInudArJXPYZNL43bnEn/KfU48rxSWyXC/mPkZcglkJB@KFIudFbiDLGTNrHjZczAGR@FD9GDnh6EfqOFPV9c267djwCFvghJ1UUEopSVgNeCtZcjGl9mYirDFaZ@Z7EuV7ZuLhb5YAC1sYZwZJbkKPfMonuY8pw4Ep3jn1KRHJ3GNjYwAAROIH2zpLqEM1PD2H6fj1l//j3/7xX3/9h9/@9Odff/nTX/7859/@8Kdf/@Vff/t3v/x/f/PLL//8x99@@T//9Nsvf/9L@/WX//Affvmf//RP/@uvOuNvf/vz//bbX/706z/94f13f/vPf/z1n377L7/8@1/aL//xP/7S/t3f6cdcMH79/MqB//e//Omf//jLH@KCdfU65T//6R//MU75Q576P/yi/@RJ/z3/@bs880//@Evd9pf/@Pf5E18i/pSH/30d/jsdrMv8/c8F/lv@f17mf/r7X958Hg795Y@//etffs3T/@5v/tvf/M0//PnXv/75n//4t7/96b/@8Q//3V//77/89t/Fy/hV/hoPmrf769/@1//0L3/I/oo///5H/8uv//nnd3/zj3/@yy9/@Driz/9YV6ln96/@@c//9Add6L/927/9/w) Can't remember the name of this method sorry, but it's very handy for square rooting floating-point numbers by shifting as the bit is always `1` thus reducing the complexity even further.

Comment: If you move the logging into the timing section, like [here](https://gist.github.com/Samathingamajig/2cdcf4d1ccbc576052c809194787875a) (copy the link and paste to get the tio) then you get the same timing range as mine. We are awaiting the OP's ruling on if timing should count for I/O, and I will change mine if the decision is to disregard I/O

Comment: @Samathingamajig And I will change mine if the decision is to include I/O, but you'll need to ping me since I'm not watching the question.

Comment: @Neil I/O no longer counts toward the time, sorry for the rule change

Comment: I have added larger test cases (sorry for the change halfway :/)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Well, I tried the largest test case, and it took 25s on TIO...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), unknown time

Finishes the first 7979 cases on my machine after 19.2 minutes. (Using `head -n 7979 input.txt | python3 sqrt.py`)

```python
from time import time

numbers = []
try:
  while True:
    numbers += [int(input())]
except:
  pass

t1 = time()

for i in range(len(numbers)):
  base = numbers[i]
  u, s = base, base + 1
  if u:
    while u < s:
      u, s = (u + base // u) // 2, u
  numbers[i] = u

t2 = time()
print(t2 - t1, "seconds")
```

Uses the same method as [Samathingamajig's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215079/70894).

Comment: @Samathingamajig, no, it's faster because it doesn't multiply by 1 and doesn't raise to the power 1, as in my other comment, also the most significant time is the sys time.

Comment: Wdym by "sys time" @NahuelFouilleul

Comment: Has anyone tested this to make sure that there's no problems with losing precision at the high numbers?

Comment: @Samathingamajig I don't think it would lose precision anywhere in the code; it's all arbitrary-precision integers from start to finish.

Comment: Update! OP had specified the I/O as optional in the time count.

Comment: Update: I have added larger test cases

Answer (score 2):

## Rust Babylonian + New data 33 ms

This uses the new, larger data set and a novel recursive version of
the Babylonian algorithm.

The algorithm refines the guess for the babylonian by calculating the square root of the top half of the number, which is much less expensive.

````
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use std::time::SystemTime;
use num_traits::{FromPrimitive, ToPrimitive};
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn recursive_babylonian_sqrt(a: &BigUint) -> BigUint {
    if a.bits() < 53 {
        //println!("a={} exact={}", a, BigUint::from_f64(a.to_f64().unwrap().sqrt()).unwrap());
        return BigUint::from_f64(a.to_f64().unwrap().sqrt()).unwrap();
    }

    let mut guess = recursive_babylonian_sqrt(&(a >> a.bits()/4*2)) << (a.bits()/4);
    //println!("a={} sqrt={} guess={}", a, a.sqrt(), guess);

    //let mut nits = 0;
    loop {
        let mut new = a / &guess;
        new += &guess;
        new >>= 1;
        //nits += 1;
        if new == guess {
            break;
        }
        guess = new;
    }
    //println!("{} nits", nits);
    guess
}

pub fn main() {
    let text = std::fs::read("numbers-updated.txt")
        .unwrap();

    let numbers : Vec<_> = text[0..text.len()-1]
        .split(|c| *c == b'\n')
        .map(|s| std::str::from_utf8(s).unwrap().parse::<BigUint>().unwrap() )
        .collect();
    
    let start = SystemTime::now();

    let result : Vec<_> = numbers
        .par_iter()
        .map(|s| recursive_babylonian_sqrt(s))
        .collect();

    // Print the time.
    println!("{}us", start.elapsed().unwrap().as_micros());

    numbers
        .iter()
        .zip(result.iter())
        .for_each(|(n, r)| assert_eq!(&n.sqrt(), r));
}
```
````

Comment: Rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=5c10d0e4272dfe67a2c3e2198a9dd3c5